# What is "docs-beta.stackexchange.com"?

Tags: support, documentation

I stumbled across the Stack Exchange [docs-beta.stackexchange.com](https://docs-beta.stackexchange.com) site by using [this link](https://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/do-we-need-custom-syntax-sugar-for-topic-page-links?noredirect=1) to a question "*Do we need custom syntax sugar for topic page links?*".

The interesting thing is, that on the top right corner there is the "*join this community*"-link but it doesn’t work and redirects to the main Stack Overflow page. On the right side is also a list of *similar questions* – but they link me to an "*Page Not Found*"-error page.

What's now the purpose of the *docs-beta* site and why I am not able to join and use it like any other Stack Exchange site?

Comment: While this is here, let's talk about the horrible rendering of that [logo](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/docs-beta/img/docs-beta-logo.svg?v=7e0959860d40), [2](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/docs-beta/img/docs-beta-logo.png?v=93beaee3deca). Looks like the logo is in beta too.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper: when I open http://stackoverflow.com/ and after that the posted [Question](https://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/do-we-need-custom-syntax-sugar-for-topic-page-links?noredirect=1) it’s actually a "documentaion BETA Beta" logo :)

Comment: Note that the related question links *do* work if you replace `?rq=1` by `?noredirect=1`.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Yes and vice versa I can't see the question if i remove `?noredirect=1` at the end of the link …

Comment: @elegent sadly, the `noredirect` doesn't work at the other pages.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com used to be the link to the *private* beta of Documentation. It had its *own* Q&A section (as not to clutter Meta Stack Overflow, which it did anyway during the last two weeks), which you have stumbled upon now.

It seems they have redirected the homepage (http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com) and documentation-specific pages (e.g. http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/documentation/c%23/topic-requests/666) back to the Stack Overflow homepage resp. the corresponding Documentation page, but did not do so for deeplinks to *questions*.

Comment: The questions are still viewable if you replace the `rq=1` query parameter with `noredirect=1`.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper yes, I put that as a comment to this question already :)

Comment: I didn't see the comment as my screen was scrolled halfway when I was testing it.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper no hard feelings