# Sunsetting Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

[image: Sunset in the west]

### We will stop accepting contributions to Documentation on August 8 2017

On behalf of everyone who worked on Documentation, I want to thank all 15,451 users who contributed. We particularly want to acknowledge the 294 people who tested the private beta and the 2,361 who pounded on the public beta in its first month. Your efforts taught us so much about how collaborative editing works and how it fails. We also appreciate the dozens of people we interviewed over the past year. These were eye-opening conversations and immeasurably useful for improving the product. (I also enjoyed being able to get to know some of you over a hangout.) Our top concern at this point is to **honor the trust you put in us**. We hope you will be willing to participate in future betas, but even if not, we remain in your debt for your efforts with this one.

While it might not seem obvious, we are deeply grateful for both the positive and negative feedback we’ve received on meta. Many people told us this project was too ambitious and that we hadn’t considered some of the deep challenges inherent in what we were attempting. You were, of course, correct. Most likely I wouldn’t be making this announcement if we’d aimed our sights a bit lower. On the other hand, we wouldn’t have learned nearly as much.

### Why was this decision made and why now?

We were really excited about this project and I'm disappointed that this is the choice we had to make, but it's the right decision and something that we always knew was a possible outcome. Last December I wrote a series of contingency plans in case we needed to shut Documentation down. Some of the options I considered made it into the plan described after the linebreak. But the entirety of one plan was “Just succeed instead.” That is no longer a possibility.

**We still think Stack Overflow Documentation is a good idea.** Kevin Montrose’s [initial research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) has mostly been proven correct. Not only did our own survey show that developers rely on [official documentation to learn](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#developer-profile-ways-developers-teach-themselves), GitHub's [Open Source Survey](http://opensourcesurvey.org/2017/#insights) showed "incomplete or confusing documentation" to be the top pain point. Unfortunately, we can't afford to work on the problem at the moment. While we have an [exceptional team of engineers](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Engineering), there just aren't enough of them to support all the projects Stack Overflow is working on.

In order to hire more people, we need to [make more money](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/15/how-we-make-money-at-stack-overflow-2016-edition/). That might mean helping more developers [find a great job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) or selling more ads or signing up more businesses to use [Enterprise](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise). In the future, it might mean selling [Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams) to new teams. The business pitch for Documentation was that it'd bring in new users who might be in the market for a job. If the feature were particularly successful, it would create new opportunities to sell advertisements. At the end of 2016, we established a metric to aim for: [substantially increase the number of Documentation users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339974/the-dawn-of-documentation-a-solstice-update).

By May, it was clear we [weren't on the right path](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation). **New users weren't coming to Documentation.** So we went back to the drawing board and started another round of user interviews [focused on Transact SQL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349409/what-t-sql-documentation-has-helped-you). We brought on a user experience researcher to help us interview technical writers. The results were encouraging in the sense that we know a lot more about what makes for great documentation and how we might support that effort. But it was also clear fixing Documentation would require a significantly larger team.

In addition, it’ll be a very long time before that work will pay off in terms of bringing new users to Stack Overflow. Our interviews showed even very experienced users of T-SQL felt inadequate to contribute documentation. Users with less Stack Overflow experience tended to be intimidated by the prospect of making even trivial edits. So the programmers most likely to become Documentation contributors were already heavily engaged in using Stack Overflow.

Finally, our research showed that while a lot of developers were dissatisfied, the current state of **programming documentation is not universally broken** the way Q&A was when Stack Overflow started. In particular, we heard over and over that Stack Overflow has become de facto documentation for many technologies. As many of you pointed out, Stack Overflow is already good enough at providing documentation of obscure features. Even when considering just [the company's mission](https://stackoverflow.com/company) of helping programmers “learn, share their knowledge and build their careers”, Documentation isn’t the most efficient use of resources.

Even though this outcome has been a disappointment, most of us agree it was the right decision. If so, I hope we'll be able to revisit documentation in the coming years. However, as the [ancient Hebrew proverb](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2813.htm) says, “Hope deferred makes the heart sick; but desire fulfilled is a tree of life.” This was a mature and responsible decision, but that doesn’t cure the heartsickness.

### Will anything come out of this experiment?

**Yes!** As Shog [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348143/1438), we've already learned quite a bit from doing things we couldn’t do otherwise. It's too soon to know exactly what we'll be able to port over to Q&A, but I'm excited about the possibilities of [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/), technology versions support, shared drafts, better collaborative editing and dated links to previous revisions. Before we leave Documentation, the team will compile what we learned so that we can draw from the knowledge in the future. And, as I will describe below, we’ll publish all of the content generated in Documentation.

More importantly, **we've changed our approach to product development across the company**. When we started Documentation, our discovery phase was largely done without interviewing typical users. Up to that point, most new features on Stack Exchange were developed with input from Meta or entirely internally. If a feature got used, we'd refine it or just declare victory. If a feature wasn't used, we typically removed it only if was actively causing harm. However, after our experience with the Documentation Beta, we've learned to focus more of our efforts on pre-development research.

For instance, the Documentation team already decided the outline of the feature before coming to meta with the initial announcement. By contrast, our newly formed Developer Affinity & Growth team [asked for help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354125/help-set-dag-product-development-priorities) setting priorities based on themes and user stories. Documentation’s private beta fleshed out most of the functionality. By contrast, the [new mentoring proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project) is a minimal viable product that is arguably too minimal. We’re certain to have failed projects in the future, but we’re working to fail a lot earlier in the process.

---

### How will the feature be phased out?

After August 8, 2017 at [1700 UTC](http://time.unitarium.com/utc/17), we’ll disable proposed changes and wait for pending changes to be reviewed. Once the review queue is cleared, it'll be removed from the review menu and [page](https://stackoverflow.com/review). We’re still working out the other details, which I will try to explain below. For some of this, we need your feedback in order to do right by the community. This probably won’t be the last time we discontinue a beta feature and now is a good time to set a healthy precedent.

### What happens to content?

As with all content contributed by the community, you own it and we merely have [a license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Since we want to make it as easy as possible for you to recover your work, we'll be listening for suggestions in the answers below. At a minimum, we'll provide a JSON archive similar to what we already [provide for live content](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). Let us know what you'd prefer.

### What happens to reputation?

Reputation earned on Documentation will be retained—probably in the form of a one-time grant shortly after Documentation ends. We have a [longstanding policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/) of preserving reputation even after worthwhile content is removed. While not all of the content in Documentation is exceptional, that's mostly [on us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation) and not on users, who acted in good faith. We looked to see how many people earned privileges on Stack Overflow without participating much or at all in Q&A. As it turns out, we mostly failed to attract new users to the site with Documentation, so revoking reputation would only affect a thousand or so users in terms of privileges compared to nearly 20k people who would lose reputation.

### What happens to badges?

We also have a [longstanding policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/23/generalist-badge-implemented/) against revoking badges. But we've never had a badge set for a discontinued beta feature either. While we could just [retire them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq), it seems confusing to show expired Documentation features on the [list of badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). In addition, we'd lose a lot of good names for potential future badges. As a compromise, anyone who earned a Documentation badge other than [Educated](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5870/educated) (for reading the tour) will be issued a newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge. Does this seem fair?

### What about links to Documentation?

Unfortunately, discontinuing Documentation will be breaking the internet just a bit. As of this writing, there are 3382 links from Q&A posts to an Example and 2199 links to some other Documentation page (usually an entire Topic). Ideally, we’d keep those links live, but because of the nature of the content, that would leave a lot of information that could easily become outdated without a mechanism to fix it. The next best thing would be a plan to automate the movement of content into the post itself. That *might* work for many examples, but probably not for entire topics.

One suggested approach: we  automatically generate suggested edits from the Community user and submit them incrementally as there is space in the queue. For links to non-Examples, we think it will be sufficient to remove the sentence with the link. Many of these sentences start with phrases such as “You could read more about X at [Docs link]”.

Links to specific examples seem more likely to be integral to posts, so the team is looking at ways to bring them into answers in a new section. Doing this via suggested edits will allow the community to reject or improve automated edits. (And authors can always [override the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/1438) if they prefer.) The key will be to find a workable template and make sure the suggested edits don’t waste too much community effort.

Until the suggested edit process is finished, Documentation pages will remain available on the site. After that, links will redirect to a landing page explaining what happened and where to get the data dump. There's not a whole lot more we can do for links external to the network, unfortunately. On the plus side, there probably aren’t that many anyway.

We’d like to hear what you think of this approach. It’s entirely possible there are better ideas we just haven’t considered. This plan is far from settled.

### What about all the questions on Meta?

I’m going to be going through the [~1,500 unaddressed meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=documentation+-%5Bstatus-*%5D+closed%3Ano) and either close or put a status tag on them. Our community produced many great conversations and suggestions, so I don’t plan to delete anything. I could probably slap [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) on everything, but I’d rather take the opportunity to make sure we have the feedback incorporated in our retrospective.

### What about . . . ?

The most important thing we're looking for in answers are feedback on the mechanics sunsetting, especially making the content available to contributors and repairing broken links. That said, if you have any additional questions or comments, feel free to post them as answers below. We also plan to write a retrospective on the blog and make this a topic of an [upcoming Town Hall Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298165/lets-do-regular-meta-se-town-hall-chats-next-event-july-26-2017). I’m planning a few posts for my personal blog as well. Documentation might be coming to an end, but we’re not close to done talking about it.

Comment: Amusing how this was announced at around the same time as [the blog post on Flash](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/08/01/flash-dead-technologies-might-next).

Comment: While we do preserve reputation we only do it when the content has been around for longer than 60 days and has a 3 score or more.  You do lose edit suggestion rep if the post is deleted.  Are you going to have the docs rep jive with that or is all rep being kept?

Comment: @NathanOliver We, in good faith, want to let users of Docs keep their earned rep. Few things about Docs makes it hard/unfair to do it any other way. With us not accepting any more contributions and sunsetting it, it does not give newer approved posts the 60 days window. We also do not have nearly enough activity on Docs to justify the votes criteria.

Comment: @VasudhaSwaminathan The whole point of the voting criteria was so that posts that were clearly extremely useful to lots of people would result in the author keeping the rep.  You're now arguing that there aren't lots of votes on most documentation, which means, *they weren't that useful* (especially given that they were apparently not useful enough, in aggregate, to keep the feature around).  That would indicate they don't *merit* keeping the rep.

Comment: @Servy: The argument here isn't that the content was useful, but that users acted in good faith. It's really the same concept as for Q&A posts deleted after they've been live several months. The difference is that the thing that changed was not community sentiment about the usefulness of the content, but the existence of the feature itself. (Also, not much point in arguing about reputation from examples without votes as they didn't earn much reputation at all. A rounding error in the grand scheme of things.)

Comment: Is it possible for us to add some items to the retrospective as well, or is that meant for mostly internal production?

Comment: @VasudhaSwaminathan I can get that.  I've never been a fan of docs rep from the beginning but you're right that it is unfair if it is all removed.

Comment: _"[...] a newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge. Does this seem fair?"_ - How about a gold badge for users who were awarded with all Documentation badges? :p

Comment: @Makoto: Yes! I'm not yet sure what form it will take, but I'd like to share as much of our research as possible. It'll be _especially_ valuable to get community input on that. (There's some privacy concerns with sharing _everything_. The interviews, in particular, were done with the expectation that they would not be broadly shared.)

Comment: @honk: As a holder of all Docs badges, I concur. ;-)

Comment: The silver badge sounds nice, but dang if it isn't replacing 3 silver badges and 8 bronze ones... as well as my first ever fully-achieved badge section. I like @honk's suggestion... a silver badge for those who participated and a gold badge for those who earned every single badge in the Docs section :-)

Comment: @Zanon: It does. We kinda have a backlog of items in the Community Bulletin at the moment, however. The plan is to feature it after the election is over and announced. We're going to also have a banner on Docs pages explaining the situation soon.

Comment: I know this really wouldn't be possible for many high-reputation users, but for the newer users here (like me) with 400 answers or less, we could probably do a quick sweep over our answers to manually remove any links to Documentation. I realize that many people probably couldn't do this, but since I don't have that many answers, I'll spend an afternoon or two going over my answers and removing any links to the Docs. I know my answers probably make up a tiny, _tiny_ portion of the total post with links to Documentation, but I'd like to do my part to help make the sun-setting easier ;-)

Comment: Ouch. This must have been difficult, but this is a courageous decision. My point for the retrospective: In the eagerness to encourage participation you've offered easy reputation, which tempted many users into editing and expanding popular 'examples' - this [led to some terrible results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348986/7586). Reputation should be more difficult to get.

Comment: Holy cow. Sorry the thing you were excited about didn't work out. But kudos for having perspective enough to let it go.

Comment: Ouch, but it is the right call. On to better, luckier initiatives!

Comment: Why not create a gold, silver and bronze documentation-beta badge, and award each of them once each for each documentation badge you had? So if you had 2 silver and 5 bronze doco badges, you'd get 2 documentation-beta-silver and 5 documentation-beta-bronze badges. Solves every problem?

Comment: @ChristianDean: One note of caution: removing the link will also remove reputation in the event of a recalculation. You can always do it after the 8th when Docs reputation is locked.

Comment: Personally I never liked the idea of documentation because it is impossible to write a real good one: Can a Qt documentation written here compete with that of Nokia? Never.

Comment: Regarding *"What happens to reputation?"* I lost already 2 times reputation somehow wired with the documentation what is about that? (all together about 1k I guess)

Comment: Sorry to hear that this is shutting down but I think it is the right call to make and an obvious one for some time. I was one of the enthusiasts that actually authored a few bits of documentation. From my point of view so documentation had the problem of being too sparsely populated because it was just too hard to edit and get past the multiple steps of approval and nit picking built into the editorial process. The result was tumbleweeds in most topics where edits went unreviewed for long periods of time. The feedback loop was broken and the resulting documentation just wasn't that good.

Comment: Can't say, that I am too sad to see it go. I'm more sad to see it being created in the first place. I would say, that research team didn't do job well enough. All of the developers I know, always use official documentation and why not? I for myself hadn't come with any relevant argument to why would one need yet another place for already existing documentation. Most of products I use are at GitHub and docs are as well. One can always make PR there to change doc., if it is not correct.

Comment: *“While we have an exceptional team of engineers, there just aren't enough of them to support all the projects”* – I don’t believe we can or *should* blame this on the developers. I believe they did a great job and don’t think just throwing more of them or “better” ones at Docs could have saved it. Docs’ original approach was already flawed, as the community attempted to point out repeatedly. This is not something that could be blamed on any of the developers working on it. – I’m sorry to see all the made effort into Docs go to waste, but I’m also glad that the *correct* decision was made now.

Comment: @rekire I can't parse your question, could you rephrase it?

Comment: @tripleee [Reputation lost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352605/995926) and [Reputation lost without any trace?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344513/995926) :)

Comment: How to export the documentations to my Dash application? It would be so helpful, I think.

Comment: What if we archived all the documentation on the Wayback Machine or similar and then replaced all links to documentation in Q&A with those?

Comment: This is just sad. I think Documentation was a good idea. I’m not sure what was initial idea, if it wasn’t big and inclusive knowledge base…anyway, it was a good try :) 
I hope SO team will come up with some new great ideas. RIP Documentation…

Comment: It took me a while into the post to realise that "sunsetting" is pointless business speak for "cancelling" or "shutting down completely". I would have guessed it meant the beta was ending and it was rolling out into production, or something.

Comment: May I say that the lack of visibility of documentation did help to it's lack of popularity.

Comment: @numbermaniac That sounds like an even worse idea than just leaving the site up as a static set of pages for the indeterminate future. Dismantling the site is supposed to counter against content rot; your proposal would basically cement it.

Comment: @rekire Thanks for the clarifying links. I guess your actual question *"what is [sic] about that?"* means either "can we assume there will be no more undocumented reputation recalculations because of Documentation?" which I think, based on this post, we can answer with "yes"; or "will Documentation rep recalcs finally be documented once the system is shut down?" to which I assume, and hope, even, that the answer is "no, that would be an absurd waste of resources."

Comment: @tripleee I understood it in that way that they want to prevent that anyone will loose reputation from this changes. However in my case I lost already reputation. I am wondering if I will ever get that reputation back. But I guess the answer will be no.

Comment: Or perhaps even "Do we want to perform another unpredictable but predictably upsetting recalculation to make up for the admittedly miserable experience of one user who gained, but then lost a shiny 20k because they knowingly participated in a beta for which reputation earnings were known to be in flux?" which I think can only be answered with "$deity, no!"

Comment: I always thought of SO as a community driven with the main aim of helping people. This decision is making me rethink that perspective. It looks like a business oriented decision. May be I dont have the far sight to understand the reason. This is sad but.

Comment: What if a new version or new feature comes out?

Comment: may be it is a correct decision to make, looking like the team has lost hope from the documentation.

Comment: Why not just make a "tombstone site" that has an obvious statement along the top why everything is in black and white, has a different layout and cannot be edited. This is in regards to saving you the effort of what to do with the old content. The community graveyard -- so to speak. Breathing life into the dead will just make Frankenstein roll in his grave.

Comment: it's not enough for you that you are out to destroy all this content so abruptly, you want to do it ***in no time*** as well? you could *at least* keep the inactive Doc site live, accessible, for a year or two. lots of older Q&A are fast becoming obsolete, will you go on a crusade to delete them all as fast as possible as well?

Comment: @tripleee i saw the comment but don't understand it to be honest. There are currently two featured meta SO posts so whats preventing a third one being added? Why does there even need to be a queue. There is a meta post about this right now already created which we are commenting on. So half of stack overflow users will only know about it several days/weeks after everyone else? If it can't get the attention it deserves then why post this now at all?

Comment: That said... Thank you

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328607/why-is-documentation-reputation-counted-as-the-main-reputation

Comment: I never saw any SO documentation links in my Google searches. Was that deliberate?

Comment: random question; about how big is the documentation?

Comment: @WillNess: The content will be available indefinitely in archive format. We aren't planning on destroying it. Until we fix links from Q&A, we won't be taking down the Documentation section either. It's possible someone else will host the content since its licensed CC BY-SA. If you'd like to suggest keeping the content on the site in some form, consider writing it up in an answer.

Comment: @Pod: To be honest, I didn't know until yesterday that ["application sunsetting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_retirement) was a thing. I mostly used the term because it fit so neatly with my earlier update: [The dawn of Documentation: a solstice update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339974/the-dawn-of-documentation-a-solstice-update). Also, I didn't want to reuse the [unshipping GIF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams) and bluefeet found that awesome sunset GIF instead. Sorry for the confusion. :-(

Comment: @poke: I agree. SImply throwing more developers at the problem would not have helped. Instead we threw more researchers at it. Our interviews with programmers who don't use Stack Overflow, technical writers and users heavily invested in Documentation helped us spec out a new design. Unfortunately, that new design _did_ need more developers, designers and researchers to implement. I plan to share more of our findings in the next few weeks.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy: Yes and no. We did expose the pages to the search bot, but we didn't do anything to encourage Google to surface those results. Q&A gets _tons_ of traffic via search because the information is generally useful. While there is a lot of useful Topics and Examples on Docs, we aren't nearly as confident about it. Fixing that took priority over getting Google traffic.

Comment: It should probably be removed from the navigation bar now.

Comment: Throwback to when the reputation system was broken. http://imgur.com/4XO31UY

Comment: @j08691:Yes that's on our list of things to do in the next few weeks.

Comment: Why isn't this post showing up in the sidebar (neither on main nor on meta) even though it's been tagged [meta-tag:featured] for five hours now? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Haris: It is a business decision, but also a community decision. It would have been quite easy to let the feature continue indefinitely and only fix bugs as they came up. (This was one of my contingency plans last December.) But that would not have been fair to the users working on it. Once we started asking the right questions, it was obvious many types of documentation could not be reasonably fit in our scheme. Rather than leaving people in limbo, we think it best to shut down the feature until the timing is right.

Comment: @Keiwan: The community bulletin board is full up. We've notified most Documentation users via email and there's a banner on Docs pages. I'm talking about unfeaturing one of the other posts, but we really want people to see them too.

Comment: @JonEricson one of the answers closely resembles my point (and has a ~ -10 score); I've commented there with the more detailed proposal: simply, automatically generated Community self-answered CW Q&A entries for each example/remarks on a topic; good ones will be further upvoted later; bad ones will get flagged for low quality and deleted, with time. a win-win.

Comment: @WillNess How can a QA entry exist without a Q? we certainly wouldn't want to suggest to the uninformed that that form of QA without a Q is valid.

Comment: @KevinB something general could be generated automatically from the tag / topic / example title, like "Haskell / Monad / How to ....". Users frequent in the corresponding tag would see these posts and naturally edit them. This means they shouldn't be generated all at once, but gradually.

Comment: I'm just going to add another statement that this ***should be featured*** (I understand why it is not technically). I only found out about this by accident and immediately thought *"Wow! After admitting it failed, the SO team is trying to hide it."* Considering the opinions of some on how SO employees responded to feedback to Docs - I do not think this is the message that you want to send. I will also add, after reading Shog's post on the reason for Docs that was not shared by employees from the start. That I have reshaped some of my opinions, but not all, about SO's attitude to feedback.

Comment: @JGreenwell: We did email all Documentation contributors who have set their email preferences to receive them. That's 12,699 people. Plus we have a rather visible banner on every Documentation page. We are not trying to hide anything.

Comment: @JonEricson I actually understand that there was an effort made but am saying that it was my initial thought (before reading the post and Shog's linked answer) due to it not being a featured post. It may also appear that way to those who at some point "threw up their hands" and gave up on Docs but were regular contributors or at least editors during the beginning phases. Which seems a bad impression to give to me, admittedly a person whose experience with Docs was part of the reason he took a break from SO for a while.

Comment: Problem with documentation is what I think that in google search I never saw any link that was pointing to documentation, so for new users it might be an unknown thing.

Comment: so sad, started contributing to documentation recently, but  this is a great step

Comment: I am not asking why you close it. But i dont think it is the right decision. I did not spent much time on dodumentation, but i think it was useful for other developers.

Comment: Well that was a waste of everyone's time and effort...Still it basically didn't work so I think this is the right thing to do. I'd stopped contributing ages ago as the interface had become too cumbersome to use.

Comment: I respect Stack Overflow a lot for this. Documentation was a well-meaning idea that always seemed slightly off to me because the goal of becoming a Stack Overflow-like presence for documentation would be in competition with, instead of a good complement to, a technology's official resources. In a world where companies, especially VC funded ones, are eager to move ahead with their own grand plans without considering whether they do any good or align with what their users want, this decision is a refreshing reminder that focus, listening and humility are good things.

Comment: Good bye to one of the most credible sources on the internet. Hope to see you again :)

Comment: How was docs rep relevant to SO Q&A in the first place? It's interesting that you're keeping it around...

Comment: I detest the "sunset" euphemism, which implies both foreknowledge of the event (the sun always sets) and that there's anything beautiful about it. No, a project had to be terminated, killed--it was not inevitable, and it's a brutal reality. Use an honest term. Say VOLDEMORT.

Comment: @AlexHall: I didn't know when writing this that "sunset" was a common euphemism. Instead, I liked the symmetry it had with the title of [another status post I wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339974/1438). As a big fan of the feature, I also hoped it would convey the idea that there might be a "new dawn". Obviously I can't know what the future will hold, but _many people_ in the company expect we'll get back to this idea when the time is right.

Comment: I hate to see this feature deprecated. In my focus (ASP.Net-MVC and WPF) they are extraordinarily useful. Specifically to new users that are trying to catch up. In language specific areas it is nice, but much more technical. For basic framework usage this has been a major help.

Comment: I'm passionate about documentation (small d). I didn't imagine that this Documentation project would fail. I didn't participate in the beta for lack of time to roll with the changes, not for lack of interest. I'm a prime target that was completely off the radar. My fault.While we have Q&A with answers to questions, someone needs to post a focused question, otherwise the answer may not be documented. The difference is re-active versus pro-active. The tech world lacks pro-active docs. We rely on re-active docs. That costs us time and money every day. That problem still needs to be fixed.

Comment: Why not just have an archived-documentation.stackoverflow.com and then re-direct all requests to the actual site to the archive link. You could have always have a warning banner that this is just for historical purposes and that there is a possibility that the content is no longer relevant.

Comment: PS: In retrospect may be having tags to the documentation would have helped. Most of the cases what people were willing to contribute and what was expected did not always match up.

Comment: @TonyG: That's useful feedback. Would you mind fleshing that out in an answer?

Comment: This is unfortunate... but at least something new will come :) Let me know if you need help testing whatever Documentation's sucessor is.

Comment: "We still think Stack Overflow Documentation is a good idea."  What can you say?  This is why the internet invented the terms OMG, LOL and particularly here ROFL.    "We still think Stack Overflow Documentation is a good idea."  OMG.  LOL.  ROFL.  ROFLMAO.  It's reached a point where you just *couldn't make this up*.

Comment: "Most likely I wouldn’t be making this announcement if we’d aimed our sights a bit lower." Very honest to write that. I makes one wonder how it would have looked like, the documentation light feature.

Comment: Why do you need to shut down documentation just because it isn't incredibly active?

Comment: @JohnMiliter: That's not entirely the reason. If the quality of Topics and Examples were generally better than elsewhere, we'd have certainly focused on growing the feature. Alternatively, if the problem really was that we needed more people looking at the content for it to improve, that would have been a reason to help it grow. But the path to encouraging quality contributions seems to be via an extensive redesign. So that's when we needed to count the cost. While there are plenty of great examples, there are too many subpar examples to keep the site live right now.

Comment: How about a new tag, something like feature-discontinued, feature-removed, beta-retired, etc.

Comment: @htm11h: I could add that, I suppose, but the purpose of the status tags is that they help us keep track of whether we've addressed features and bugs. I left _many_ of these meta questions unaddressed because we weren't ready to address them just yet. My goal in this will be to see if we can add the feedback to our retrospective.

Comment: @Jon Ericson, well that was kind of my point, rather than simply Status-Decline everything, a new tag or two, could filter more effectively, the content that is valuable and that which could just be "archived" or retired? If that makes sense and is practical.

Comment: Total cognitive dissonance here. You were told in detail why the project would fail, and it has turned  out exactly as predicted: low-grade contributions by juniors, and little or no engagement by seniors, the only people competent to write it. People get *paid* for this work. Why should they do it for nothing? And why exactly is 'developers rely on official documentation to learn' considered a *problem?* You'll learn nothing from this debacle by ignoring the evidence. It isn't just a matter of internal resourcing. It was misconceived from the start, as you were told repeatedly.

Comment: @EJP This has been discussed elsewhere extensively (veeeery extensively, and without a consensus), but regarding "THE" reason for failing that you pointed out: There are people who are competent at a topic, people who erroneously *think* that they are competent, and (independent of the first two) people who are good at writing docs for someone who is *not* already familiar with the topic. To put it that way: Even the most competent person can write horrible docs. (So the actual problem may have been: Not properly defining the scope, target audience and desired content of docs)

Comment: A disappointing outcome, and a pity, considering the work and efforts that have been invested there, by the team *and* the users. "Sunsetting" this indeed must have been a tough decision, but it's probably better to take a step back than considering it as "too big to fail". I hope that the fade-out works smoothly and in a way that is acceptable for everybody.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a separate community project? I really thought this would have been very useful because so many software companies have the worst documentation for their own systems and products.  Often, simple APIs are missing the most basic and important details because documentation is such an after thought.  It would have been useful because we would not only have a repository of useful, unopinionated documentation, it would be documentation that would be automatically versioned, updated and curated by a very competent world community.

Comment: Jon, would SO please work with the Internet Archive to make sure all the content is on archive.org *as individual pages* in the Wayback Machine (not just the bulk JSON archive) before the SO links go dead?  Thank you!

Comment: I am sad to see it go, but it is probably for the best till a better format can be created. There are too many cooks in the kitchen and they are all trying to be the head chef! I think it was a great start and can become something really great. There is a lot of helpful information that can be used if we know where to find it. Of course, that was part of the problem it was always the same users working on the same topics. I hope to see it again in the future I have enjoyed SO since I joined and I plan to stay and help the community and help any way that I can (which included helping with doc).

Comment: It's a shame this got canned. On numerous occasions I found myself referring people to the documentation. I think the examples often went into far more details on Angular2..4  than their basic documentation did.

Comment: I never once used Documentation. That says it all for me.

Comment: My initial thoughts are "burn it all". Experiment complete, I think we all learned something. Personally, I wrote what was IMHO a concise and clear entry, like I would if I was writing an SO answer. It then got tweaked and tweaked, about 10% of those tweaks could conceivably be improvements. What it left is something that I do not really like. All of this an aside from the bigger problem of, what actually, is the right structure for "All the Documentation"? How should it be organised. I think, simply, it can't, you may as well just put the effort in to improved searching of SO.

Comment: So this is your excuse for the pile of new advertising scripts you added in the last weeks?

Comment: @gbr: Hmmm? Maybe you could link/screenshot what you mean? I don't know of any advertising scripts and, to be honest, I'm not sure what you mean by "scripts" at all.

Comment: @pnuts: [This one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354693/remove-prompt-for-documentation) If there's something else, I might need to check with the ad team.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which was the reason you had chosen T-SQL as the focus group to diagnose Documentation and if you think that the input given by that particular group is relevant to supply the correct reasons for the lack of engagement on Documentation as a whole?

Comment: @JonEricson google-analytics.com, quantserve.com, scorecardresearch.com, adzerk.net, and on some sites doubleclick.net after you allow googletagservices.com. You notice them if you use NoScript, I'm pretty sure there were at most a couple of them until 10-15 days ago.

Comment: @gbr Yeah, the tag thing is new. (I'm not up on the details of that project, but it rings a bell.) The rest we've had for a long time now. Either way, none of that is related to Documentation.

Comment: For me, the documentation experiment failed because it was made to look as if it was an entirely independent, irrelevant, and separate offering to the rest of the site. My gut feeling is it would have been a lot more successful had it been integrated with the Q&A. i.e. enable a user to request (on the spot, via official means) that a question be addressed in more detail, addressing the larger point rather than just the highly specific point of the question. Very often this happens already via community wikis. I'm sure authors would be happier writing docs that links back to sample questions.

Comment: this decision makes me sad. i had high hopes for using it myself in future whenever i find a problem i cannot solve myself or want to learn a new twist for some new functionality in a certain language. really.. this makes me sad to see it go.

Comment: [And remember that I said this first *"It will drag down the reputation of the quality of SO, so suddenly and so quietly that it will be next to impossible to correct without removing the Documentation portion completely or make SO as relevant as MySpace is today"* – Jarrod Roberson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334638/documentation-is-on-its-way-to-becoming-the-next-w3schools)

Comment: People are *really* going to miss Documentation because it was *so* popular

Comment: @AdamLear I'm pretty sure more of them are new. Unrelated to Documentation indeed, anyway. (probably)

Comment: I think it's really a shame that they are shutting down Documentation. I liked it both as a way to learn about a technology and a way earn rep. I feel that Documentation here was actually more succinct, focused, and high quality than other places because it was crowd-sourced by a large group of people who are incentivized to provide good content through the point system. I think the decision to shutdown documentation was merely a decision by an ignorant executive wanted to lower costs and use misleading statistics to argue that the docs didn't contribute to "the bottom line". Sellouts. smh.

Comment: No regrets on my part. I tried to use Documentation and hated it. It tried to constrain my approach to explaining concepts far more than the worst technical editor I have ever had to work with. Writing within such constraints was simply no fun.

Comment: I agree to let it go, but I do think it'd be wise to keep a "no-edit" version of the existing site around for 2 years. At least ,that would jive well with the idea of "sunsetting" -  but if it just disappears into some downloadable .rar file users can download, *naaah* that is not sunsetting. Sunsetting means you keep it there, and it slowly goes away while we drink tea and watch it. Then a year later it changes color.  Then another year later it changes into a .downloadable .rar   . It would also honor all teh effort involved by users in it .

Comment: @Coffee: 2 years is a long sunset [even on Venus](http://www.planetsforkids.org/news/how-long-is-a-day-on-other-planets/)! Part of the problem here is that people won't do anything with their content if it's available on the site. But knowing that the content is going away might prompt people to post it somewhere. I've got a few topics I wrote that I plan to put on my blog. (It's not there yet because it's still available online. ;-)

Comment: With respect to making money, why not have an annual begathon like Wikipedia?  I give them $100 (the price of a subscription to Encyclopedia Britannica) every year because their site is so valuable to me.  I would do the same for SE.

Comment: Speaking of Wiki, why not just migrate the documentation to a Wiki?

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff. I appreciate the sentiment. While we do like getting money, that's secondary to building a business. Any donations we solicit would not be tax deductible in the US since we are a for-profit organization. If you'd like to help out, one of the more effective things you could do is [create a developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/join/).

Comment: @dgatwood: Once we have a data dump (coming soon!), it'll be relatively easy for anyone to move content to a wiki or other form. That way people can curate by picking out which topics they find useful and valuable rather than blindly copying the whole feature warts and all.

Comment: I think its a pity to bring down documentation. As a vba programmer I find the Excel-vba documentation for example, really great! Nothing similar out there on Google. There should be a way to keep documentation alive, because it is realy great!

Comment: @JonEricson Since this is being sunset, [can this feature request for anchor links in answers be reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts)? I mean *come on*, you tell us that we can now use documentation, which would have made that feature request *largely* unnecessary, and then you cancel documentation, which means we have no way to link to specific bits anymore. *At least* let us make **great** answers **amazing**.

Comment: @JonEricson I see your point about donations, but AFAIC it's a business expense, just like my expenses for technical books, software, electronics, etc.  I don't know exactly how to phrase it, but if you offered subscriptions or memberships or something, then I'd like to think that it would be a legitimate business expense for any professional.  I will look into the developer story thingie when I get a little free time :-/

Comment: `Our interviews showed even very experienced users of T-SQL felt inadequate to contribute documentation.` Aka the bit of the Dunning-Krueger curve that we usually neglect because there are far fewer competent people in general.

Comment: Why not leaving Documentation open to the contribution of just the best contributors?

Comment: @Revious: The trick is identifying those contributors. People have assumed the best people to write documentation are folks with the highest reputation or the best score in a particular tag. All things being equal, I tend to agree. But there are likely many people who would make great Docs contributors who are not interested in answering questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @WebsiteDev: The revised plan is in a [more recent update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355115/documentation-is-read-only-what-s-next). In essence, we'll replace most of the badges with a newly minted silver badge.

Comment: Breaking the links makes no sense imho, the content on SO or on wikipedia is not updated either in a formal manner.

Comment: @JonEricson you have stated in your post that "programming documentation is not universally broken", but have not developed much about it. Do you have any references for this that you could share with us?

Comment: @pasemes: Sure. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) is pretty well regarded. [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs) does interesting things with interactive code embedded in the docs. Someone recommended [the Vue.js docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/), which demos things in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/50wL7mdz/). For older docs, I still admire [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html) and [_Programming in Lua_](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html). I should say, there's a bit of hyperbole in the phrase you pulled out. I'd say almost all docs are "good enough—just".

Comment: Id like to add my two cents

Comment: The decision is saddening but understandable. I think the idea has potential and with improvement, it could come back stronger than ever. I wasn't very active on SO when documentation was active but, from what I've read and observed, a better peer review system would have helped ensure quality of documentation. I mean peer review as "review the code" opposed to the standard check for grammar and code formatting edits. From what I've observed, most edits across the site are for grammatical and formatting improvements.

Comment: SO is always being unfair to contributors. firstly taking content with a lot of moderation and also no certainty in getting help on our issues! This module got Shut after all efforts users gave in, and no returns to them! One Word.. UNFAIR

Comment: Sad to hear ! But, I really appreciate `DOCUMENTATION` project...

Comment: Ha! [I did try to tell you all it was a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331935/get-rid-of-documentation). I am just glad that I chose to completely ignore it and not invest any effort in. In fact it was only today I realised it didn't even exist any more. Just a thought, why not consider placing the "blame" on the people that came up with the idea (or at least the design of the idea) and perhaps next time they have an "idea" that you don't all jump straight on it...

Comment: Any plans on rising the documentation?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal: Not at the moment, but I'd love to try again at some point.

Answer (score 390):

Instead of having [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) do this why not organize [the community](https://stackoverflow.com/users) to edit the links?  We can treat it like a tag cleanup/burnination and get users with edit privileges to go through and edit them.  This way we don't fill up the review queue and we can handle the cases where it is not trivial to edit the link out.

Comment: This seems like a great idea. Would you suggest that a new review queue gets generated temporarily for this? Or would it piggy back off of something else?

Comment: I agree, there are a lot of answers where simply removing the link will very much deteriorate the answer. Just compile a huge-ass list with all links (grouped by topic and maybe even doc example), and let the community have a go at this first.

Comment: Base on number of views the answer with the link is getting

Comment: Agree with this Nathan, I'm sure we (as the community) could fairly quickly remove links that are not necessary and even re-point to more appropriate ones. There'll be a bunch of posts that are left at the end and we can decide what to do about them later. (e.g. adding some canonical QA on the main site)

Comment: @Frits We could handle it with a meta post showing the status that we can edit and if we need to a chat room.

Comment: This is a fantastic idea. Like @poke said, just make a huge list and then _release the hounds!_

Comment: Here's the start of a list...currently waiting for it to run without a limit. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/709302/882839/links-to-documentation

Comment: @Josiah [This](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fdocumentation) site search is unrestricted and has 4500 results.  Might not be all of them but it is a good place to start

Comment: For _all_ links from SO posts (main and meta) to any Doc entry, post a notice in the inbox of the SO post author. Let the owner of the link have first crack at fixing it. No review queue needed, no community effort involved, and the original author will know best how to "fix" the lost link.

Comment: The heading sounds like, accepting contributions will stop only on August 8th.

Answer (score 342):

A few of the documentation examples I wrote, I created because I previously had a hard time finding that particular information.

This is only a few examples that I'm talking about. Majority of my contributions were just part of testing out the site. I also am only referring to examples that I created and was the main contributor to.

Would there be anything wrong with turning these examples into self answered questions in the Q/A part of the site?

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! Having written my share of self-answered questions, my advice is to focus on the question and be sure there can be alternate answers.

Comment: @JonEricson Would it be correct to also include edits that others made to the examples?

Comment: The only real problem is with attribution. This is also a flaw with editing examples into posts. For the moment, go ahead and link back to the Example as it currently exists on Docs.

Comment: @JonEricson It seems silly, though, to include a link that very soon will not work.

Comment: you might find this guidance useful: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314272/839601)

Comment: @TotZam: I'm going to be talking with the team later today and the link situation is almost certainly going to be our main topic. We got a lot of useful feedback here that might change our plans. Keeping the link will be useful information no matter what happens.

Comment: Also [What subjects would be good for a self answered question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322248)

Comment: @JonEricson so even better, why not convert *all of documentation* into community-wiki  self-answered questions by Community? each example and remarks sections for teach topic automatically converted into their own Q&A entry with some auto-generated title. this will preserve the content a.o.t. destroying it (and letting users on data-dump content chase ***is*** just the same as destroying it).

Comment: (continuing) good entries will with time get up-voted more, bad ones will get downvoted, flagged into low-quality queue and deleted, with time.
 valuable content will be preserved, bad one deleted. a win-win.

Comment: @WillNess A lot (if not majority) of the current documentation already exists in QA. Just moving everything over will create *many* duplicate posts. I think the only way to do this is by users manually moving over the few item they feel don't yet exist. And this would be only after they do a thorough search to make sure the question really doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @WillNess The whole reason documentation is going away is because it's largely not full of useful information.  If most of what's there was actually good content, it wouldn't be being sunset right now in the first place.

Comment: @Servy what you're saying is, lot of it isn't that good, some is very good, and we will through away the good with the bad! and I'm saying, I don't think that's OK.

Comment: @WillNess I didn't say that at all.  I said we shouldn't copy over all of it, because the vast majority of it is bad.  Feel free to copy over the few bits that are actually useful.  And of course it's never *going away*.  The archive will always be available, if you later find out that there was something useful there that you want to re-host elsewhere.

Comment: @Servy I've just re-read your comment, and yes, you kinda did.

Comment: @WillNess Where did I say that people should be prohibited from asking questions using the content from Documentation (in the rare cases where they'd actually result in a good question)?

Comment: @Servy it will be available as a JSON/XML/whatevs ***data dump***. Not really that useful to me - and that's a colossal understatement. An answer here asking for a frozen Docs site is heavily downvoted right now. (? or was, when I last read it few minutes ago...)

Comment: @WillNess Yes, and if you end up missing some content from docs you can pull it out of the data dump and re-host it (in a Q/A, or elsewhere) to ensure it's not lost, so it's *highly* useful to you if you're trying to find one of the rare pages that actually had some useful information to re-host.  The answer asking for a frozen docs is highly downvoted because *it wouldn't be useful* because there's so much bad content there, and that's the same reason we wouldn't want to just copy all of the pages into QAs.

Comment: [here it is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354245/849891). yes, it has even more downvotes right now. -- **no**, it isn't useful to me. the only thing useful to me is what I can open in my browser right away, not a zillion zipped XML files. that is not helpful to me, **at all**. @Servy

Comment: @WillNess Yes, I'm aware of the answer, and as I said, it's correctly downvoted, because it's not a good idea.  As I've already told you, it's useful to you because if someone realizes there was some useful content in Docs that didn't get re-hosted, the archive is there for them to re-host it.  Your statement that the content is being permanently deleted is false.  Even if you don't end up finding one of the rare artifacts that's useful, others will, and will re-host them, *helping you*.  But creating thousands of bad questions, as you're proposing, would be *very* harmful to the site.

Comment: @Servy and I already told you that it is not useful to me, and not having an HTML accessible means heaving a content completely removed - for me. this is what I am telling to you.

Comment: @WillNess And I explained to you why that's wrong, and how it *is* useful *to you specifically*.  Repeating something that I've already demonstrated is false, without adding anything new is just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Servy something that I have right now, will be taken from me, made inaccessible to me, I will be put at the mercy of someone who might host it if they so choose, and you call it "proving me false". ridiculous, is what it is.

Comment: @WillNess Something that you have right now *that's not actually of value*, is going to be made *less* accessible, but is still accessible to you, and because of your unwillingness to access it, it's putting you at the mercy of someone choosing to determine that it's worthwhile enough to host in a way that you're willing to access (which is highly probable).  So yes, I call that proving you false.  If you don't want to be at the mercy of others, then *you don't have to be*, but even if you *choose* to be at the mercy of others, it's still helpful to you.

Comment: @Servy no, what ***I*** have right now, is of great value to ***me***. Next, if accessing something right now costs me 0 effort, and will cost 100,000 on ***my*** relative scale of cost of effort, why do you think you have any right to tell me this or that.  You don't know ***my*** relative effort scale. What's easy enough for you, might be very hard for me. But as I said, you don't want to hear me, and it's fine. just stop telling me I'm an idiot. it's like I have a ferrari, you take it away, give me a donkey instead, and laugh at me complaining, because you're a master donkey-rider. I'm not.

Comment: @WillNess Docs is flooded with plagiarized content, duplicated content, incorrect content, poorly written content, etc.  Most of what's there isn't even original content to begin with, and is *already* accessible elsewhere.  Of what's left, most is just worse versions of content already accessible elsewhere.  Again, this is why it's being removed in the first place, it's full of bad and duplicate content, not original quality content.  If you're actually using it (for some unknown reason) then you can just do a search and find the same content somewhere else.

Comment: The few pieces of good original content can also be moved elsewhere, and that's *very* likely to happen, so no, you're not losing a ferrari and getting a donkey, you're losing a donkey even though you've owned a ferrari this whole time, and you're complaining about *only* having a ferrari, instead of your donkey.

Comment: @Jon Ericson  
I added a self answered question on SO with the contents of documentation I had created and requested feedback. Within minutes it was down-voted, received several more down votes and close votes. Then it was moved to Meta, received morre downvotes on both the question and answers and eventually closed and locked by Cody Gray♦. See the question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354447/swift-language-pbkdf2-key-derivation?noredirect=1#comment500435_354447).

Comment: @zaph The morale of the story of course being that if you're going to post a new question on SO you need to ensure that your question is a quality question, that meets all of SO's standards for a good question, and that the answers also need to be good answers, per SO's standards for an answer.  Just copy-pasting over something from Documentation that wasn't written to be a good SO question or a good SO answer isn't going to go over well.

Comment: Wonderful idea. Is there a list of the gems of Documentation that aren't yet converted to self answered Q&A available?

Comment: @Trilarion Almost certainly not, for several reasons. Not least of which is which topics and examples would be worthy of 'gem' consideration.

Comment: @TylerH Okay, then maybe a more flexible approach where everyone decides for himself what a gem is and what not but notifies others one he has converted them to self answered Q&A, so we avoid duplicates. A simple meta Q&A should be okay. If I have time I will open one.

Comment: @Trilarion As I stated in my answer, my intention was to move examples that I created or was the main contributor to. I don't think everyone should just start moving over documentation. One of the biggest problems with documentation is that amount of plagiarisms, so you can't just copy examples that you don't know the source of. Also, majority of documentation already exists on QA, so that information for sure should not be moved over. If you personally feel that a few specific examples are missing from QA, then move those, but this shouldn't be a community migration project.

Comment: "I *told* you.  *What* did I tell you?  *Didn't I tell you?*  'cuz I told you!  Mmm-hmmm.  And when did I tell you?  [A long time ago.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304157/211160)  And what did I say would happen when I told you?  Exactly what just happened!" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrGYLNHfUwE :-P

Answer (score 121):

Regarding Documentation badges, I really hope that the Documentation Beta and the Documentation Pioneer badges can be retained and be separated from the "newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge".

Both badges are **awarded to recognise users' contributions in the different phases** of Docs, i.e.:

- [Documentation Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6157/documentation-beta)

  - For participating in the **Docs.SE private beta**
- [Documentation Pioneer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6158/documentation-pioneer)

  - For participating in the 1<sup>st</sup> month of the **Stack Overflow public beta**
  - awarded from July 21, 2016 till August 20, 2016

These 2 badges are also awarded on a **limited time basis** and they can't be obtained now. So, it wouldn't be really fair to those who had obtained them. These users were one of the first users to help to shape and test out Documentation and I think **retaining these badges will show some recognition to the early birds**.

In addition, both badges have names unique to Documentation, so they can't be reused in the future.

As for the newly "newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge", I think another badge, e.g. "Documentation" *(the name's just a suggestion)* can be introduced and it would recognise users who participated in the "graduated" version of Documentation.

> [image]
>
> - *a rough idea of how this'll look like*
> - *my other ideas for the name of the "newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge" are "**Documentation Tester**", "**Documentation User**" and "**Docs Contributor**", feel free to **suggest more in the comments** if you have any good ideas :)*

**In this way, there will be 3 badges, each awarded to users who participated in the different phases of Documentation, namely the private beta, the 1<sup>st</sup> month of the public beta and the graduated Docs (current phase).**

Comment: I completely agree.  I actually went out of my way to make contributions in the first month after the closed beta because of these badges

Comment: Documentation Pilgrim? Documentation Settler? Documentation Homesteader? lol

Comment: @jpmc26 On a similar Oregon trail-type of theme, *Documentation You Have Died Of Dysentery*, or *Dysinterest*, perhaps?

Comment: SE Staff seems to follow your suggestion: [Documentation is read-only. What’s next?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355115/documentation-is-read-only-what-s-next?cb=1)

Comment: @Ferrybig Yup, just saw it, thanks! I'm didn't expect my suggestion to be taken, but I'm really glad :)

Comment: What about badges for those that contributed on the review Queues for documentation?

Answer (score 80):

I'm not sure if automated suggested edits are a good idea, unless you're sure that most of these edits will be of good quality. Wouldn't want robo-reviewers to blindly approve these instead of improving them where necessary.

Comment: Might put the suggested edit queue back to 3 approves needed when this path is chosen ...

Comment: Also create some submitted-by-Community audits...

Comment: If enough of Community's automated suggested errors get rejected by reviewers, will Community be given an edit ban?

Answer (score 69):

## Suggestion: export the Documentation dataset to GitHub

I read some of the downvoted comments about snapshotting the content, and noted how unused Stack Exchange sites are completely shut down, not archived. I can definitely agree with the idea of exporting/archiving the Documentation data via Stack Exchange's periodic data dumps, but that kind of locks it away.

GitHub could provide the perfect environment to foster continued development. The most straightforward way I could see this working is to create a purpose-specific organization for the task, and then export all content in either ReStructuredText or Markdown format.

Exactly how to structure the export makes for a good question though. Careful use of directory structure is obvious. I'm wondering whether to lump everything into one gigantic repository, or break things up. It may actually be a good idea to fragment everything, because cloning tiny repositories imposes less cost than cloning a gigantic one.

Moving everything to GitHub leverages existing collective knowledge, momentum and infrastructure. IMO it's the best place to dump everything and provides the best chance that it will survive and continue to grow.

The thing is, the Documentation experiment produced a bunch of data that is current *right now*. This shutdown is going to put a pretty big dent in the maintenance momentum that has been created. It would be a good idea to export the data in a way that minimizes that dent as much as possible, to create the best chances that the documentation will continue to be updated.

One technical note. Because GitHub is based on Git, that provides the perfect solution to version management - you can simply transcode the Stack Exchange document history into the Git repository history, perhaps even using edit reasons as commit messages. GitHub have been working with Git for quite some time, too, so this should be quite easy.

Comment: I like some aspects of this idea, but I don't think it makes sense to dump all of Documentation on Github. It might make sense for some topics where the Documentation trove really adds significant value over existing documentation; but even then, Github is merely a back end, and you really need a proper front end web site, Anyway, that can happen as soon as someone steps up and volunteers to code and host the thing, and is independent of Stack Overflow, after they fulfill the promise to release the data dump.

Comment: @tripleee True, but having a versioned backend that people can easily fork could help everyone to work on it. Also, markdown shows on github as a website and getting an offline copy would be really easy with git pull. All in all this is not so daft. See my answer for a frontend idea, which doesn't exclude github as a backend at all. Submodules could be one way of letting people decide on which parts they would like to work/download/fork.

Comment: Do you want this as a read-only dump there, or for people to work on it? In the latter case you need at least some maintainer.

Comment: @tripleee: You're right, GitHub is just a backend. I was thinking that the export would live in one or more semantically presented repository(s), with (a) matching *.github.io repository(s) to allow for easy presentation of the data. GitHub has `allow-origin=*` on their raw links, so you could serve some JS to pull in and format the data that way. A fair bit of work, but the result would be a fully self-contained platform (view via Pages site, edit via Pull Request) with zero hosting costs.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: This is an excellent point. Perhaps Stack Overflow could invite all Documentation moderators to the new organization. That would be one way to semantically transfer the ownership. SO would need to get a GitHub account from each moderator though.

Comment: @nus: I just checked devdocs out right now and I REALLY like it, thanks for the TIL! I would completely agree that periodic dumps (even near-realtime dumps) should be pushed to here. In the (hopeful) case that this GitHub idea eventuates, I would recommend pestering the new GitHub maintainers so they integrate this into the workflow from the start - figuring out how to make this work would take some thought, considering that devdocs already pulls from other canonical sources for information that Documentation would be covering. (Naming is tricky too - "CSS - Documentation" wouldn't work, etc.)

Comment: Dare I suggest a front end, something like Read the Docs, displayed on GitHub pages? Moving to such a system from the current data may require quite some work and tooling but the exercism project provides a good example of how they have managed to do something similar with managing and building programming examples over different topics (languages)

Comment: Meh. Someone else can do this with whatever snapshot the SO team provides.

Comment: This would be helpful for moving the documentation to the actual products where it belongs.

Comment: This is a great idea! It would also keep content available, so any links to docs could just be redirected  to the respective *.github.io repository page...

Answer (score 53):

I am glad that you guys decided to take it out of Stack Overflow and was expecting this to [happen some day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328642/1542290).

> Just a suggestion here to Stack Exchange team, if we stick to the current way, I am sure that users will start losing interest soon.

The reason I was asking to remove the rep is to get users who truly want to maintain a set of documentation without expecting any rewards. That's when we start getting legitimate people who really care. Throwing free rep is like compromising quality for quantity.

---

**What I learnt from this?**

- Bad move to get new users, especially throwing free points, which leads to poor quality content and an overhead for high rep users to review
- Hardly any community feedback was considered.
- Not enough motivation or reason to edit docs.

---

I am happy that this is getting reverted. But I would like to appreciate the efforts put by the product managers, developers and users who were taking active part in the documentation and providing valuable feedback.

Answer (score 43):

Collaborate with the Wikibooks community.

It would be nice to make it easy to import the content of SO Documentation on Wikibooks. Many wikibooks are concerned with programming language and the licence are compatible.

Comment: Agreed, it would be great to import everything as one giant Wikibooks book (just many subpages). Assuming the content respected copyright (e.g. by including only CC-BY and CC-BY-SA text and images), that is. Then pages can be easily moved or split into other Wikibooks books (many are probably overlapping with existing ones).

Comment: I don't think SO docs would make an interesting book. It covers lots of a disperse set of languages/libraries and the content is unstructured.

Comment: It could be several Wikibooks, not just one.

Comment: of course, this should be included in relevant existing wikibooks such as R programming for example.

Answer (score 37):

The preservation of the reputation, as controversial as it may be, should be highly visible to us.  In the past, when reputation has changed with Documentation, it's happened "suddenly", and those kinds of surprises should keenly be avoided moving away from the platform.  This helps us Meta-hounds who *want* to explain what's going on, but can't due to a lack of information as to what actually happened.

Speaking of reputation, I didn't see this acutely clarified, but if someone has historical links to these pages, what's stopping them from upvoting them?  Will they be locked so that users don't gain rep from a now discontinued part of the site?

Comment: Considering much of the question is talking about dealing with the consequences of the fact that the documentation content *is being deleted and won't be hosted on the site anymore*, I'd say it rather effectively renders the second paragraph moot.  No, they're not being locked; they're being deleted (hard deleted, not soft deleted).

Comment: We'll be taking a snapshot of reputation shortly after we stop accepting contributions. The current plan is to award all Documentation reputation as a single grant. More details to come.

Comment: @Servy:  They had explicitly called out reputation as a thing they were going to address, and Jon's latest comment only reinforces that.  Better to know than to assume in some cases...

Comment: There's a specific section on what happens to the content, saying it's being deleted, there's a huge section on *dealing with the fact that incoming links will be dead* which wouldn't be a think if they weren't being deleted, and then also the reputation and badges sections both indicate that the content is being deleted.  It was already called out, there's no assumptions needed here, the question was explicit.

Comment: The preservation of the reputation should be a primary goal. Users spent a lot of time on writing and editing documentation and you have to preserve all the rep.

Comment: I think a pinned Meta post when it happens (plus good display on the reputation page) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 34):

**I wanted to like documentation and did not like it and am happy to see it sunset. I am hopeful that a different way of searching/finding information on using APIs may be in the future, a venture worthy of Stack Overflow and its amazing community.**

The fact that Documentation was shut down is a good sign to me for the long term health of the core Stack Overflow website/system, which I remain totally convinced of. It is a 100% fantastic thing that you tried, and if you "failed" (I don't think sunsetting this beta counts as failed), then it was worth the failure.

I think a discussion on why some users might not have wanted to use the Documentation feature as it stood, is worthwhile, and agree with the OP above who stated "we'll be talking about this for a while". I would like to suggest a blog post "post mortem" on this whole experience, with things you learned.

I would like to know "what we learned" with this whole thing.

Comment: I can learn a lot from here. Hope your successes... Thank you.

Answer (score 30):

### We told you so?

Looking back at the "answers" to [the original meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) is pretty revealing. Out of the top ten or so responses, there is a lot of hesitation, some outright hostility, and a little bit of guarded optimism with conditions attached.

Documentation always felt like something that SO really really wanted to do, and the community was lukewarm about at best.

I'm sorry so much effort has been spent on something that ultimately didn't deliver (haven't we all been there!) Better luck next time, I guess.

Comment: With hindsight it's of course easy to say "we told you so". ;)

Comment: I'd accept that criticism if the general response was positive, and I was drawing attention to a minority of naysayers. But the general response was negative, so ...

Comment: My initial response was negative too. But still the problem with hindsight is that you only pick the convenient cases. It's perfectly well possible for a majority of naysayer to condemn something and it nevertheless turning out to be a big success. Only if then you also post "Sorry, we were all wrong, please forgive us." only then "we told you so" posts in the opposite case make sense. Otherwise, with hindsight we are all so much wiser. We all know how it's guaranteed to not work now. Maybe it would have worked if approached only slightly differently and then your answer would be off again.

Comment: This reminds me of [Captain Hindsight](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Hindsight). Every (community) project always has a large group of skeptics.

Answer (score 25):

More notification is important, even if SO is better without documentation.

Despite warnings and meta discussion ever since I joined Stack Overflow that documentation was dying, dead, or diseased (seemed the end of documentation was always forecast, but yet it never happened), I created several examples in a very specific topic area to help address relatively common issues I was seeing in questions. I used these examples to help keep posts shorter, while still providing background information that was lacking elsewhere. Likewise, I have used, more than once, the example of another contributor.

These examples are rather verbose, but depending on the question, they may be fairly important or they may be supporting information. I could move all my examples to a third party site (skipping the contributions of others), but I feel a better solution may be to selectively include information from the examples in my answers. I feel that the answerer is generally the best suited for such a task.

Given that many users are cautious in editing others answers, the suggested approach:

> we automatically generate suggested edits from the Community user and
>   submit them incrementally as there is space in the queue.

may take some time to be completed. Also, it is likely that the ideal person (the answerer) to make many of those edits won't get much of a chance to make them once they hit the queues.

I'd appreciate a chance to edit documentation out of my answers before this automated process kicks in. Yes, I'm aware I could do this now, but I have limited time and connectivity for the next week (and what of the internet points if I remove documentation links prematurely?). Some examples, as another answer suggested, might better be reincarnated as self-answered questions, and it would be wise to give other answerers a chance to consider this too. Lastly, incorporating other contributors' examples into existing answers will require some thought so that the content is not merely plagiarized but still properly attributed of course.

There are also certainly some users with many more answers that reference documentation, or users that are unaware of this change (I accidentally stumbled into this question). And, no, I don't expect all answerers to actually make or want to make changes to their answers simply because of the demise of documentation.

Is it not possible to keep documentation around for two weeks to three weeks (possibly with diminished visibility and accessibility for documentation to allow it to start to dip below the horizon) to allow for proper notification, and to give answerers an opportunity to remove the documentation from their own answers while still having access to that documentation? At the moment, it appears that everything will be in motion within a week, *potentially*, with the documentation end date of August 8th.

With that timeline, I will likely just copy my examples, make a list of affected answers, and edit the answers simultaneously with those in the review queues trying to clean up for me. Others, if unaware of this question, decision and timeline, will have less time, or no time, if they wish to update their answers. They should at least have a chance and get proper notification (I realize the election reduced the number of featured meta links, but it would still be nice to be featured there).

Lastly, I'm sure someone can do it rather easily with a data explorer query, for those with an order of magnitude more answers than me, it could be advantageous to be able to find a user's answers that reference documentation easily.

Comment: Concerning the last point: site search with `url:stackoverflow.com/d` should do it. For example, you have [16 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A7106086+url%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fd) linking to Documentation.

Comment: We aren't going to remove the content immediately. It'll probably be several weeks before we finish with the Q&A links, so the content will be on the site for at least that long. It's also still up in the air _what_ we'll do. Our initial plan as presented in the question was crafted with significant time pressure. We certainly didn't decide (or even suspect) until recently that Documentation needed to end. Our final plan may very well look different. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Alex, Ah, wasn't thinking, thanks for the easy solution to that point.

Comment: @JonEricson, my misunderstanding, I was thinking suggested edits for documentation, not suggested edits for questions with links to documentation. In any event, ensuring sufficient notification to users, prior to a queued approach, is still my main point.

Comment: As for the notice, we recently added a banner on the site and we'll be emailing Documentation users (who have [elected to receive emails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature)) tomorrow. I believe this question will be featured tomorrow. (It has been a busy couple of weeks on Meta.SO!)

Comment: @JonEricson, just noticed the banner, though it is only on the documentation site (understandable given how few people use and/or contribute to documentation, spamming the main site might be unwanted; however, many of those contributors might not visit the documentation pages very often), but all those steps are steps in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah. The banner is intended to notify people who might be considering starting a draft or have some drafts in the works. The emails will notify many more people, I expect. But there will still be people on vacation or just not paying attention who will miss the notices. I can pull their drafts from the database if needed, but the content won't make the data dump.

Comment: Can't reach/please everyone, it would require unreasonable means. But a reasonable attempt to give folks a heads up with a bit of lead time is always appreciated.

Comment: An approximate timeline might help the discussion. For example, freeze Aug 8, next step (whatever it is) Sep 8?

Answer (score 21):

Sad to hear this, but I understand the decision.

For me documentation was not necessarily solely about documenting things that had little to no existing documentation but also about making existing documentation more helpful.

A prime example is the .NET languages documentation. Admirably MSDN has reams of documentation on this, including example code - but very few of the pages offer any information as to *why* a programmer might choose one method or class over another. So many SO questions that arise from this can be answered by "Read the source code" which, while it would provide an answer of sorts, it does not help someone that doesn't already know what they are doing or fully understand what they need (and thus would not really need to ask a question).

An example of the problem this solved can be seen in the following outline of a forum thread that was typical when I was learning VB.NET on the job:

> Me: I need my FooJubber to work asynchronously, how can I do this?
>
> A1: You need to use a TaskGlobberb, here's the MSDN link to that class.
>
> Me: OK, thanks. I've started adding it to my program but I'm not sure how to cover X case though. *explains more detail - maybe some code*
>
> A2: Hey, you shouldn't be using a TaskGlobber at all!
>
> A1: Do X case like this *some code*
>
> A2: You should use a ThreadFlibber really, here's the MSDN page, you will need to rewrite what you have so far to fit it.
>
> Me: Hey A2, why is a ThreadFlibberNub better than a TaskGlobber? What's the difference? That MSDN page doesn't really explain the pros/cons
>
> .... *rinse and repeat*

Of course this is not an SO type question, so I was excited to think that Documentation would make the whole process faster, less frustrating and most importantly, require less rewrites, by adding something more than the dry simple description on official documentation pages such as MSDN (and others).

That said, the result is not always what transpired on Documentation. Even so I am quite proud of my and others contribution to the project, some tags became quite helpful, even those with which I already had a lot of knowledge on.

WRT lessons learned I think you hit the nail on the head with "fail faster". Although it only gets minimal mention in the OP, the problem seems to be that it took until May (10 months in I think?) to see that the business case wasn't being filled. I'm unsure if this time-frame is typical for such projects, but it allowed a lot of effort and work by both contributors and staff to be invested in a product that is now being essentially thrown in the bin.

Comment: The question was already getting long, so I didn't go into all the twists and turns. We really didn't get clear metrics to aim for until the beginning of the year. At launch, the business goals were very broad and not explicitly measured. We felt the feature was too incomplete to start evaluating from a business standpoint until we had the discussion feature. I expect we'll be able to talk about this in more detail soon.

Comment: Thanks for the added info @JonEricson

Comment: "...but very few of the pages offer any information as to why a programmer might choose one method or class over another." I guess in the end it's always a matter of convention/good practice and design guidelines/philosophy. This is surely something good programming resources should contain.I fully agree there is a market for this but creating it is not a small effort. Maybe StackOverflow overengineered the feature, did not clearly communicate what they wanted, enforced the rules not enough and had not enough stamina to stay with it until it's really finished. The basic idea sounds still okay.

Answer (score 20):

I'd like to say a few things as one of the 294 privileged users who participated in the early stages of Docs.

First and foremost, I'd like to thank Kevin M. (whom as I recall got engaged during, and maybe thanks to, Documentation private beta) and Adam L. for the direct and verbose communication channel they've given us through chat. I can't stress enough how beneficial, welcoming[,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) and important it is for users who are closely involved to have the option for a direct daily free-form chat with the developers. Iv'e been in a similar situation as a contributing user where the chat facility with the developers was largely unused to detrimental effects.

You said you've learned a lot of lessons about the development process of new features, I hope this is one of the positive lessons. That, and also

> We’re certain to have failed projects in the future, but we’re working to fail a lot earlier in the process.

the re-discovery of the [fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) approach.

Secondly, my (lack of) thoughts about reputation and badges. Personally, I don't care much for badges and non-gold tags (of which I "proudly" have none). I can't imagine anyone, including myself, digging in my profile to see what activities I participated in and I can't display them anywhere for "bragging rights". As much as I'm proud of the private beta badge and would like to keep it... take them... take them all... I can live with... OK, maybe leave us this particular one?

I personally wouldn't care much for the reputation or other internet points, but many users spent a lot of time in Docs so I guess it's only fair if they retain their gains. As others suggested, it would be preferable if the reputation tab detailed the actions for reputation changes and not just a one-time event "this is for all you did in Docs".

Lastly, I'd like to share my personal experience with Docs. I was very excited for getting in the private beta and I wanted to start working on the Java topics. Fortunately to Java developers, and perhaps unfortunately for Docs, Java is already a very well documented language. Between the API, official tutorials and many long-standing bloggers (some of whom are SO users), example sites, and even my friend the dreaded JLS, there wasn't *much* to add. This already came up in the chat discussions and I wasn't the only user aware of this. Turns out Java wasn't the greatest target for Docs.

What eventually happened is a lot of duplication of material from outside sources, not to talk about a decent amount of plagiarism which was removed quickly, and a lot of trivial examples (convert `int` <-> `char` anyone?), all of which wasn't in the spirit of supplementing existing knowledge. The more "advanced" topics I created didn't seem to gain much traction, unlike the basic language topics which were very popular for some reason but also redundant. I quickly found myself flagging to remove content more than adding to it, which led me to stop (un)contributing.  Even as of 2 months ago, most of the content on Java is redundant and I have no qualms about seeing it disappear.

I am glad, however, that for those tags with poor documentation the SO Docs made a difference. GitHub's conclusion about "incomplete or confusing documentation" is no surprise in a programmer's world where new options arise so often. For developers to use a language or a library they must be shown how to as there's not time to figure so much yourself, and if they don't, their ship will sink. Docs might have been the tow boat, but maybe because of the timing or the platform itself, it didn't live up to its promise.

I can only hope that Kevin's next attempt will not cave in (I'll show myself out when I finish this sentence) and I'll be glad to be given an opportunity to pioneer the effort yet again.

Answer (score 20):

A huge part to why this failed was described in this post itself.

> "programming documentation is not universally broken"

We have documentation already for many technologies, (yes they can be pretty terrible or limited) but we have that starting point. So to the other issue was:

> "New users weren't coming to Documentation."

I would not think new users would come to community created docs that are incomplete. They will also not go searching for it on Stack Overflow first. They will find it from the docs page of that technology.

**What I would love to see happen:**

Documentation should not be community created but instead community **maintained**.

We need the *official* documentation on technologies to be in the same place as community edits, faqs, and tutorials. The tooling that was provided by Stack Overflow to create and maintain documentation was great for anyone to easily give back. We would need support from bigger open source projects to host **all** of their documentation on Stack Overflow. This will make us more focused as a community and keeping our documentation *DRY* just like our code should be.

Comment: Nice idea. SO team should keep this in mind. They have the Q&A system as enterprise product, so maybe they can make a hybrid Wiki/Q&A/Voting thing as Enterprise documentation product. Just extend the current thing.

Comment: Agree. No new users (beginners) will dive into documentation. The advanced ones look for this.

Answer (score 18):

I'm saddened by the news, I contributed quite a few bits and pieces over the months, and seeing it all go away isn't a good feeling.

I enjoyed Documentation, if I'm looking for a more complex answer, or a better explanation on a feature, Docs were my go to, I felt the system was abused a little bit. A lot of edits especially at the start due to the rep being so high. But you fixed that.

I would like to take this opportunity to thank for team for building Docs. Personally I loved it and wish it could stay, despite what your post depicts, I also felt it quite welcoming, when it first started is was like a huge blank book ready to get written.

Also thank you for all the contributors, whether you fixed a typo, added an example or simply reviewed changes, thank you too!

Answer (score 14):

#### What happens to reputation?

Would it make any sense that on days where a user gained 200 points including some from documentation and got some 'dropped rep' because of extra votes (the reputation cap), that the documentation reputation is replaced with the 'dropped rep' instead of a one-time boost.

It might distort how much effort some people put into Docs, but if Docs had been missing, those people would have got the reputation the other way.  Where their non-Docs rep excess doesn't compensate for their Docs-rep on a given day, then the Docs-rep compensation scheme would come into play.  (I know I've had a few days where I've had some Docs-rep and some surplus non-Docs-rep and the one could play off against the other.)

OTOH, this is more complicated.  And there's an element of 'simply aggregating Docs-rep into a one-off grant' better shows how much different people contributed to Docs.  But then people might seem to have earned less than the rep cap on days when they were capped because they had some rep from Docs.

I don't have strong views on this; I'm merely raising the possibility as something that should perhaps be considered before choosing the simpler scheme.

Comment: What you desire is probably already going to happen. If they are going to remove Docs rep, as they say they are, and instead apply a bulk rep grant, my expectation is that a complete recalc would automatically occur resulting in what you desire throughout the time when Docs rep was earned. Such action would cause any up-votes which did not previously provide you with reputation to be able to fill in the rep (up to the 200/day limit) on the days where Docs rep was no longer earned.

Comment: But if a user had a large Docs rep day with a small "normal" rep day and rep-capped, he may not rep-cap with the recalc and that could effect badges.

Comment: Bit of a miscommunication here - I talked about rep with the team. It should stay exactly as-is (not a one-time grant, that'd throw chronological math off in all sorts of ways). Just no links on the items after sunset. The plan is to basically freeze the rep currently there in a grandfather historical table that's used when re-calculating rep in the future. Luckily we now have a RepHistory table with every single rep entry in there, and we can save the Documentation types off (rather than deriving them them from the Docs tables during a recalc going forward).

Comment: @NickCraver What is "In all sorts of ways"? People would gain a bit extra rep if they overcapped due to docs, and maybe lose badge progress if they capped from docs a lot. Nothing substantial. Any reason why it'll not just be done as a block besides that?

Comment: @Magisch picture for example the 1 rep user, they got 500 from documentation, then they issued a bounty. They had the rep to do so, now what do we do if they didn't get that rep until after the bounty? They'd have been at -499, it'd make no sense. So we have to inject rep into the system as an offset grant to make that bounty make any sense. This was an issue back when rep wasn't realtime and skewed greatly between recalcs. In short: you can't just change a timeline, things literally don't add up :)

Comment: @NickCraver Won't the recalc then just still sum it all up. Like yes he would've been at -499 for a while but would the system care about that sides from a graph? They should still have their proper rep at the end, no?

Comment: @Magisch I don't think they would- If the grant is after the bounty, and you logically can't go below 1 rep, I would think that this would put that user up to 501 rep instead of the 1 they should be at.

Comment: @Magisch Kendra is correct, they'd have received a net 500 rep they otherwise wouldn't have. The timeline would be corrupted and we'd have injected rep maintain the integrity of the history, unfairly. The solution we're going with isn't complicated, and will have no side-effects like a grant does.

Comment: @NickCraver: Not making a 'one-time grant' and just leaving the doc-sourced reputation in place is certainly easier.  Would you have the link identifying it as 'reputation from docs' go somewhere to explain to the curious, or just have an anodyne "reputation from Documentation Beta" with no active link, or some sort of hybrid (active link to neutral explanation, but the link text is from the documentation topic, possibly prefixed with `Documentation` or something similar to classify it). But my concern is being taken care of (thank you).  As you're aware, rep is a touchy subject on SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Having a link to somewhere makes sense to me, how about pitching that as an idea in an answer here? That wouldn't be hard to do if we have a landing site.

Comment: Geez you have a lot of rep.

Answer (score 13):

I'm sorry to learn about your decision to stop the Documentation project, though I understand limited personnel resources and the need to focus on areas that will make money for your company.

I hope you will seriously consider tackling this project again in the future. The following points are nothing new but illustrate that there is still a void waiting to be filled:

- Official documentation pages, while helpful and not completely broken, are often very terse and difficult to understand. They frequently lack adequate examples and explanation. Where there are mistakes or when they become outdated, there is no easy way for the average user to get them updated.
- Random tutorials across the internet have tried to pick up the slack but are not systematic.
- Stack Overflow Q&A does serve as a form of documentation. However, in its current state it does not readily accept requests for very general explanations (howto tutorials) or very specific questions ("Can you show me an example of this obscure API?"). There is also not much linking related topics together besides the tags, so it is not practical to explore a topic by browsing through a hierarchy.

The sun sets, but it rises again the next morning.

Comment: Within the company I've heard a lot of estimates for when we might be able to get back to Documentation. All are at least a year (which is too optimistic in my view), but none are _never_. If someone else doesn't beat us to it, I'm confident we'll try again with what we learned this time around.

Comment: "*very specific questions ("Can you show me an example of this obscure API?")*" It should be noted that such questions are not forbidden because they're "specific". They're forbidden because they are very *general* and open-ended in their answers.

Comment: However there are several competitors to such a documentation hub, including Wikibooks as mentioned in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354416/1333493

Comment: An alternative phrasing of the API question is, "What's the purpose of this API function?", which is perfectly valid, and usually answered with an example.

Answer (score 12):

I personally was always torn between whether I should just blog something, or help out Documentation. I ended up posting some Examples on Docs. I'll probably just transfer the Examples to my blog. Would it be possible to get an email from SO with a list of all the Q&A posts that link to my Examples. That way I can just change the links to my blog instead?

Comment: I suppose that would be a possibility, but I'm not sure how many people would move content to their own blog.  You can find the links _you_ added to Q&A posts by searching [`user:me url:stackoverflow.com/documentation`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+url%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fdocumentation). Your contributions can be found [on your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation&sort=contributions) in case you want to search other people's posts.

Comment: @JonEricson Ahhh! That's a neat trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Most Community user mass-edits have been pretty straightforward tasks like link migration that don't need contextual awareness or the approval of a human to be done properly.

I don't think automating something on the order of what's being described in this post is a good idea considering the lack of uniformity in how the links are used. [In my experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299123/are-grammarbots-supported/299128#299128), these types of loosely-defined editing schema can get you into trouble, particularly where review queues are involved.

I don't have an alternative to offer outside of archiving the content with some kind of disclaimer that it may be outdated (which obviously comes with its own set of issues discussed in the post). However, I don't think this is the type of thing you want to automate given the wide variety of use cases for links to Documentation that you mention; perhaps a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)-style effort is in order?

Comment: "perhaps a burninate-request-style effort is in order?" -- like Nathan's suggestion in the top answer?

Comment: @Frank Yes, I hadn't read the other answers yet when I wrote this, but I agree with his suggestion. The main thing I wanted to stress here is *why* it's not a good idea for the Community user to perform these edits.

Answer (score 7):

A second 'answer' (suggestion) from me.  In a previous ['answer'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354251/15168) (question, suggestion) with the general topic 'What happens to reputation?', I asked about the 'block grant' system mooted in the main announcement ('question').  It seems that this [will be handled differently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation?page=1&tab=votes#comment500055_354251) from the way originally outlined, and my concerns are effectively dealt with.

In the comment chain after that answer, I [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation?page=1&tab=votes#comment500320_354251):

> Would you have the link identifying it as 'reputation from docs' go somewhere to explain to the curious, or just have an anodyne "reputation from Documentation Beta" with no active link, or some sort of hybrid (active link to neutral explanation, but the link text is from the documentation topic, possibly prefixed with Documentation or something similar to classify it).

[Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation?page=1&tab=votes#comment500321_354251):

> Having a link to somewhere makes sense to me; how about pitching that as an idea in an answer here? That wouldn't be hard to do if we have a landing site.

So, I'm pitching my suggestion as an answer for debate.

My general idea is that where an entry in the reputation pages currently shows something like:

[image]

(where you have to know that [Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/795) is (currently) a link to the C Documentation), it might show the text `Documentation: Hello World` instead — to identify the reputation as coming from Documentation — and the text might be a link to a general explanation of what Documentation was, noting that it is a withdrawn experiment, etc.

Comment: Or "retired documentation: [c] Hello World" -- with the tag as well as noting that it's an old Docs project (in case a later version also makes an appearance in the rep table).

Answer (score 6):

Another badge question: Will the *private* beta badge be merged with the others, too? I'm absolutely fine with the silver badge for documentation public beta, but I feel like the private one should be separated from this. 
I didn't really participate since the documentation went public because it was a huge mess at the beginning and I lost interest...

Answer (score 6):

Why not set up a bare-bones wiki as it was initial inspiration of documentation as said in *[The dawn of Documentation: a solstice update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339974/the-dawn-of-documentation-a-solstice-update)*?

After the why, I explain a simpler model that might have worked and why this modern one did not.

My experience comes from being an old contributor to Wikipedia.

I found the experience of a technical writer of other wiki documentation cited in comments irrelevant because if I understand well why the scope of such a wiki is different: It is usually a single project wiki, and it does not have the critical mass of contributors.

The second point is that it seems that instead of start of the simplest model which can work (a bare-bones wiki) and develop around it according to the needs which arised from here, you have developed an overengineered model in the hope it will fit. From my experience, the way that the documentation is single centered around example fit to some of the subjects, but not all.

The third point of failure comparing to Wikipedia is that by wanting the contribution systematically peer reviewed and moreover by several peers you lost immediate feedback for new users.

The fourth point is that you had absolutely wanted to set a reputation system which overconstrained your system. As much it reasonably works together with single contribution document authors such as Q&A it is hard to work with multiple authors. It leads you to have a confirmation system to be sure that people will not game the system. The motivation behind Wikipedia contributors is as long as I can analyze it is mainly to act for the general good.

Comment: One of the findings from our interviews with technical writers is that wikis are commonly suggested, but rarely useful. Not to say they _can't_ work for documentation, but rather that it's a long shot. One key would be to develop a comprehensive set of templates to cover all sorts of documentation. But that's exactly the challenge we face pressing forward with this pass at Documentation. It wouldn't save much, if any, effort.

Comment: I think a wiki is exactly the way to go. Yes, there are challenges, but the experiment you are now terminating points to even more severe challenges with solutions which look like wikis reimplemented poorly.

Comment: @tripleee It probably depends a bit on how one defines a wiki. It could be almost anything. Challenges were not only organization, also voting, solving edit conflicts and of course reputation. While gamification helps a bit it should never be the main driver.

Comment: @trilarion solving conflicts would be made via discussion as in wikipedia. There would no reputation neither voting

Comment: Voting on Q&A SO is very efficient to tell you which content is actually useful. The biggest difference between Wikipedia and Stackoverflow Q&A IMHO is that Wikipedia is collaborative editing and Q&A isn't. Not sure how Wikipedia copes with different opinions about topics, but SO Q&A handles that very efficiently. My main problem with Documentation was that a) the structure was totally inflexible and b) the reputation attracted lots and lots of crap. If without these two things, my motivation to make Documentation great would have been much higher.

Comment: Basically wikipedia copes with different opinion via discussion. It is far less efficient than voting for single author document as so qa. But for multi author document, the documentation model show that voting just don't work.

Comment: @trilarion moreover, they are rarely conflict on wikipedia on technical subject such as the ones which would be concerned by a language documentation site. On wikipedia the man conflict are political, religious, ...

Comment: I see. So the main competing concept to Q&A like SO is some kind of Wiki approach with collaborative editing and lots of discussions. It might be more work but the result might be a more coherent, authoritative form of knowledge. Maybe Q&A will become/remain the debugging helpdesk and the future of example based documentation will be based on a Wikipedia like framework.

Comment: The standard [definition of a wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki) will do. The crucial difference to tag descriptions on SO main is the ability to create and name new content pages freely, so you can restructure and refactor content organically. Still a lot of work, but in the words of Einstein, "the simplest thing that will work, *and no simpler".*

Comment: Except I don't think it will fly; you will get the poorer parts of wikipedia, lots of stale discussion beginnings, and still lots of plagiarism because if the parts you want to be there when you start to write something original are missing, that's the the quick and dirty fix.

Comment: the plagiarism is a very little problem in wikipedia, usually a simple google search get the plagiarist so quick. And about discussion, I would expect a very smaller amount because in technical things, the amount of subjectivity is usually a lot smaller than in wikipedia in general.

Comment: In Wikipedia, the motivation is seeing your work being actively used on a high-profile site - basically, vanity publishing. There also do exist medals awarded to distinguished contributors and privileges conferred upon those who showed they can be trusted with them. Remember, Wikipedia pioneered mainstream wiki use - before it demonstrated the viability of its model, few believed the general public can be trusted with directly editing a site's content.

Answer (score 6):

This is a minor issue but it is something to think about:

[Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) likes to randomly bump unanswered posts to get them more attention.  Normally this is not an issue but with docs being removed is Community still going to bump docs meta posts like it did to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348787/cannot-add-introduction-to-an-introductory-topic-in-docs)?  If it is can we tweak it to ignore the documentation tag as I can't see any benefit of it doing so.

Comment: Community only bumps posts which have an answer but the answer's score is 0 (more precisely: at least one answer scoring 0 and none with positive score). This isn't a common thing on Meta, where votes are in rich supply. Community _does not bump questions without an answer_.

Answer (score 5):

Why not make a community effort to port the content over to MDN? I've seen GitHub and the Wayback Machine mentioned in the comments, and while I agree with using either/or, porting to MDN would benefit both communities and the web in general.
I always felt that documentation was reaching too far here, and wondered why there wasn't a community push to create/edit more documentation on MDN. As fate would have it, I feel like this opportunity has presented itself again, and we should take advantage.

I'll be porting over the very limited additions that I made to Documentation, as well as certain technologies that I am interested in. Would love to see like minded individuals do the same.

Comment: Please keep us updated on your progress. For people who want to build off of Documentation content (and not just archive it), MDN and similar platforms seem like good destinations. As always, please observe the target community's guidelines. (For MDN, [Working in community](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Community/Working_in_community) seems like a good starting point.)

Comment: lol. i'm one of the contributors to that page. but i appreciate that, and hope others will find this comment and the link useful! what other similar platforms are you aware of?

Answer (score 4):

I am also sad to hear this. I think a collection of examples and tips on all these technologies is definitely a useful resource.

One way I would appreciate being able to still have access to the content is if it were included in [devdocs.io](https://devdocs.io/) and its offline [desktop application](https://github.com/egoist/devdocs-desktop).

I don't know how big the dataset is, but if it's reasonable that would be an awesome way to share it.

For developers like me who are offline most of the time, this allows us to have a ton of examples and tips for our favorite languages offline, completing the official documentation.

Comment: Is that just for API docs? As mentioned above, there is Kiwix (with ZIM) for offline consumption https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354412/1333493

Comment: @Nemo Thanks for the tip. I didn't know kiwix. It's quite amazing that one can have all of wikipedia and SO offline. Unfortunately I don't have the bandwidth to download that, and their desktop app is far not as pleasant as devdocs. I don't know if it's only for api docs, I think it's for docs that someone is willing to port over to the right format. Their is a [trello board](https://trello.com/c/PVnfdeaN/26-suggest-new-docs-here) with suggestions for new documentation sets.

Answer (score 4):

[Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) can be a great way to maintain data and will provide a solution to broken links originating out of the Stack Exchange network. I feel it to be easier to use than a data dump.

Comment: I found one problem with the Wayback Machine for Documentation: it strips off `%23` and anything following it in URLs. That makes it impossible to archive C# topics.

Comment: @JonEricson That's unfortunate. Thank you for taking time to go through the documentation.

Comment: @JonEricson can you show me an example URL that this occurs on please?

Comment: When I try to save https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/topics, it returns https://web.archive.org/web/20170908120532/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c . It seems something truncates the URL somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in my opinion is, there was no difference between Q&A and "Documention" except the running software.

What was "Documentation"? That was never been clearly defined.

From the latest meta update (I have read), it should have been a set of *examples* for real programming tasks. Voting is based on how much helpfull it is.

How does this differes from Q&A? What is Q&A? It is a set of *answers* for a real programming tasks. Voting is also based on how much helpfull it is.

So, where was the **difference?** I don't see any (Except rep farming was easier on Documentation and some badges).

So if you by chance want to start anytime a similar project, please answer this questions:

- How is it different to the current product?
- Why should people contribute?
- Why people want to use it?

I am still a fan of the idea, that documentation is written by programmers (that actualy need to use it) instead of other persons, that have no idea about the real world programmers need. Especialy if we have one quality standard, where I can say, go to Stackoverflow Documention, it is the best place to get some information. But that's all, what "Documentation" was not. In fact, I never get a result on google that has redirected to "Documentation".

I am not realy sure, what a perfect product would be, but please make sure it improves something. Maybe it is better to work on some top voted and ignored Feature-Requests. Especialy on Triage/H&I, since crap is flooding the Q&A product.

Comment: "*It is a set of answers for a real programming tasks.*" No, it's not. "tasks" are generally bigger things than the specific questions we allow on SO. "How do I load a shader in OpenGL" is too broad a question for SO, but it would be an adequate task for Docs.SO. [My post here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329183/734069) outlines what I would felt would work better for what they were trying to do.

Comment: Agree. But I think this is more a scope issue, than a software issue that the Q&A software can't handle. This could be a perfectly valid question, if we have a SE community that supports broad tutorial questions. I am in favor of improving one product then creating duplicate products. @NicolBolas

Comment: I disagree that the Q&A format really can allow such things to work. SO prioritizes new questions over old ones, by design. Such broad tutorial-like questions don't work well in that environment, since it's easy for such questions to get lost in the shuffle and never get answers. Such answers take much longer than answers to other questions. Also, remember that SO's current rules exist because we've tried being more loose in what we allow, and it just doesn't work.

Comment: Mh, I never has seen a question get losts on Stack Overflow, exception on a low traffic tag. Same problem in Documentation. The scope for Stack Overflow is perfectly fine for me. A bigger problem is to me, less people apply it correctly! But on the other hand, we even have very highliy opinion based communities like [hardwarerecs.SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). If we need tutorials, maye we can propose a site for it. Just saying, I see no difference. The more I think about it, *How do I load a shader in OpenGL*, sound even not to broad for SO. tbc.

Comment: Even how to check if a file exist is upovoted in any language I know of. As for your Meta Question, where the answer is basicly: Teach a poor man to fish, and he never asked for something to eat. That's classical documentation. SO Documentation should have been primarly example based, that is the opposite. That's where I feeling that there is no difference.

Comment: "So, where was the difference?" Oh, there was a difference. Q&A is much more localized while Documentation was supposed to contain larger examples for general topics. Something that would have been closed as too broad on the Q&A site. I agree that there was not enough guidance on that but in principle it was clear what was meant even though people didn't follow the idea.

Comment: I totally disagree. 'How do I load a shader in OpenGL?' is a great question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote off Documentation in my book as soon as I heard it bring forth loads upon loads of easy rep that carries on to SO, without even looking into anything else in detail.

(I did get the general picture - that it intended to contain docs and code examples and stuff or something, and that's it, what was the bigger idea, they couldn't express themselves, apparently. That was enough to convince me it wasn't worth the time.)

I've seen enough rep whoring on this site and its consequences (both direct inflow of junk stuff and indirect as poor contributors gain privileges and start to have an ever bigger negative impact on the content and community, without any incentive to improve whatsoever) to support anyone who condones (even more so, encourages) this kind of behavior. That was the biggest breach of trust from the site's management I've ever seen.

Since protesting was useless - the relevant posts' authors really sounded much excited and eager to get it going at any cost - I did the best I could do - protest silently.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest an extension to the JSON archive:

Downloadable mark up files of parts of the documentation.

A nice way of structuring those files would be:

- A tag is a file (the title would be like `<tagname> -- from Stack Overflow Documentation`)
- A topic is a chapter
- An example is a section

Possible mark up languages could be

- Markdown
- HTML
- reStructuredText
- LaTeX

Rendered output from those files would make it possible to have a nice eBook containing all the knowledge for, let's say Vim or JavaScript.

Comment: Everything on SO was already written in Markdown. I'm not really sure what you're suggesting here. Is it a reorganization/collation of the content somehow?

Comment: I think the JSON archive will be a good place to start. As @JoshCaswell mentioned, Markdown (technically CommonMark, in this case) is how we store posts. It's fairly easy to convert that to HTML and certainly possible to convert to LaTeX with existing libraries and tools. Making a book sounds like a fun project as long as you don't [botch it](http://jericson.github.io//2016/02/19/duckett_review.html). ;-)

Comment: If the goal is to have an ebook, then I suggest producing a ZIM (nicely packaged HTML) which can then be read with Kiwix: http://www.kiwix.org/

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing ... Markdown exported to JSON. Transforming to an XML or LaTeX form of your liking will not be entirely trivial, but in any event probably something you can (and likely should) do yourself if you have a clear use case in mind.

Comment: Well the idea was to create something that everybody could use easily without any big conversion effort. I know that converting JSON to markup is possible (and easy, this is actually a part of pandoc), but It would be easier to use if the content is already bundled. I proposed non-markdown formats, because they usually provide nicer layout and intra-link features.

Comment: @JoshCaswell reorganization/collation are the right words.

Answer (score -1):

I spotted this topic only today and only today I was actually using Documentation for the **first time**. Particularly reading "New C# 7.0" features. Documentation is **the best** page on the Internet to read about it: clearly to the point, with examples, up to date, covering nearly everything. Simply put: not a single guy (nor John Skeet, nor Chuck Norris) is capable to think, plan and publish it as good as an engaged community can.

How is Documentation different from Q&A? It's **categorized** and **filtered**. It is way better to learn by reading Documentation, than from dozens of tagged questions and answers. Q&A learning require more time, many questions are too specific to the OP's problem, many answers are too specific to the OP's problem, and the readers often have issues to apply the solution to their own case. Another possibilities to learn are reading books or follow a tutorial. I believe Documentation is a very good way to **learn something**.

What were the problems with documentation?

> New users weren't coming to Documentation

Because they want to ask the question and receive the answer, and I haven't seen many answers what were **using** documentation. The mechanism to link Q&A with documentation **is missing**, it is simpler to close the question as off-topic for asking off-site resource, than to go and search documentation and answer with the link to it.

Another problem is discovery. Google rather gives links to Stack Overflow, than to documentation. Documentation is a **black box** for the stranger. Its existence is well hidden. It is possible to use Stack Overflow without even knowing about it.

I haven't participated myself in Documentation, because I didn't feel its potential and haven't seen its connection to Q&A. I was waiting and waiting, but it just didn't happen. And now it's down...

So what now?

We can **move Documentation into Q&A**. Every topic is an answer and it simply needs correct tags and question "What is ...?" or similar. I believe this can be automated, reviewed once, done. The questions and answers will be updated later auto-magically with new answers and links to duplicated and related questions by community.

Comment: I was thinking about upvoting this until the last paragraph. You have some good points, but I don't agree with your conclusion.

Comment: I think a Q&A *style* layout to Documentation would've made sense. "What is StringBuilder?" or "How do I read from a text document in Java?" could've worked as a question body, followed by responses by the community just like any other question would. Voting would work in the same style and it would feel at home with the rest of the Stack Overflow/Exchange community.

Answer (score -2):

Oh that's so sad... I really liked the idea. Something that just popped into my head while I was reading this, is that I never viewed a question or answer that had any documentation link pasted in it, not even one. Maybe if you made it clear, obvious and easy to answer to questions with links to the docs, it would bring a lot of people to that part of the site, reading that, and probably improving/adding content while we're at it. I'm no guru on any subject, but if it was as simple as 'click and read', maybe it would attract me. Heck, I find myself wandering a lot on WorldBuilding.SE or any other SE site just because there are hotlinks right there besides the answers!

Maybe something like what you do with the questions titles, where you suggest titles that have already been asked before. If you suggested links to docs while people are writing answers, then probably that person would link to it, check it themselves and possibly even contribute.

Comment: The means to include a link to Documentation was right there in the editor toolbar, and all you *really* needed to do was paste in a link. The reason these links weren't included in very many answers is because the quality of Documentation was...sub-par, and experts didn't want to recommend it.

Comment: That might be the case. As I said, I'm no expert and don't usually answer questions (because I don't know the answer to them). I know that pasting a link is ez-pz, but what I think would make a lot of sense is to display a suggestion to the docs (both when asking and when answering). It's too late, though, for what it appears. Maybe if you later bring it back, you could make a few changes and perhaps this suggestion could be studied aswell.

Answer (score -3):

Despite the fact that most software tries to provide some documentation, it is often not very good, hence the need for services like Stack Overflow to fill in the many gaps with user contributions.

But starting a pure community-supported documentation effort modeled on the Q and A framework of Stack Overflow is not necessarily the right approach for several reasons people are now aware of.  Wikis are another approach, but they also fall short of the goal for other reasons.

However, have you considered expanding Stack Overflow to turn the Q and A format into something even more useful, which might eventually turn out to be a step in the direction of better documentation?  What I am suggesting is organizing the questions and answers already created, essentially improving the searchability and browsability of the ever growing and useful resource that is now organized as merely lists of questions.

We need more than just a simple set of tags associated with each question, useful as that is.  For example, simplify the searching and browsing on multiple tags, or create higher level 'topics' which are defined by a set of tags.  And we need more than just a simple unstructured list of possibly related questions; we need a verified list of related questions, grouped in various ways that will actually have a chance of being useful.

It would be useful to have something like the FAQs that are the supposedly frequent questions but more often the likely questions that may not even be asked.  Moreover, FAQs are often organized by topic and sub topic, and readable from top to bottom almost like a tutorial.

My suggestion is to leverage the community in greatly improving what you already have in a way that incrementally grows it out of its current niche, which has been proven to work, into neighboring niches.  Rather than starting something new, which has many risks associated with it, even though it might be closely related, it is far safer and more effective to grow what is already known to work.  The main question is what path for that migration is actually going to work, and that might be difficult to determine without experimentation.

Comment: Not very useful yet.  You disagree with improving Stack Overflow at all?  You disagree that the improvements I hinted at might be a step in the direction of better documentation?  You disagree that the Documentation project should have been cancelled (which I am not suggesting)?  What?

Comment: Everything. all of it. and none of it

Comment: basically... it's a cool suggestion, i'd imagine it could in theory make things easier to find. but... who is going to categorize the millions of questions we already have, in addition to the 12k we get every day? we can't even close off-topic questions effectively.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Indeed, it is a lot of work to categorize the millions of questions, which already do have tags, but... there is more to do.  And the answer is (in my suggestion) to find ways to leverage the community to do that.  E.g. suggest tags, vote on tags.

Comment: Reposted and expanded on as a question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/301917

Answer (score -4):

If moving the content of the Documentation project breaks links on the Internet, this can easily be fixed in the server's .htaccess file with permanent redirect directives.  They are entered in the form

RedirectPermanent /old-file.html http://www.domain.com/new-file.html

Each URL will take one line in the .htaccess file.

A bonus of this approach is that search engines should re-index the pages, so eventually the URLs returned by search engines will be the new URL, not the old, broken URL.

Comment: That only works if we are _moving_ content. Unfortunately, we are _removing_ it. There's no new URL to point to.

Comment: @JonEricson The wayback machine might be a good place to direct users to.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Yeah. I'm making sure the topics pages are archived on archive.org. (I wrote [a script](https://github.com/jericson/so-docs-tools)!) But I don't think that's a good solution in the general case. Stuff goes out of date and it's better to have it on the site where people can edit.

Comment: @JonEricson — First you say you're _removing_ the content, then you say you're going to _move_ it to archive.org.  Which is it?  If the latter is true, my answer above is perfectly applicable.

Comment: Andrew and @TinyGiant: I've been playing around with Wayback Machine and it seems they don't support `%23` in URLs. That's a shame since it means they aren't archiving any C# topics.

Comment: @JonEricson Well I guess that idea is a non-starter.

Answer (score -5):

I have invested a considerable amount of work and care in the documentation. I've wrote on two topics in which I'm expert on. A lot of other developers like me did the same. I don't have a coding blog to move my content to, so my work will go down the drain.

I think it's a huge waste to just remove *all* the content from the web.
The documentation, with all its faults, can still be beneficial to many users.

It is possible to just mark all the content with "Closed - Obsolete community documentation" or such. Voting and commenting can be disabled.

Benefit of a closed/obsolete resource:

- No broken links, all content will stay where it is
- Among the documentation there are many very good resources. Those ranked with high vote - can be safely considered good resource for their date.
- Documentation for topics that are not sufficiently documented outside SO  will still be discoverable with Google (or in SO search) - and it will greatly help developers that can't find better information.
- Even old or even inaccurate content can help developers research obscure problems, give ideas for solutions and provide references or at least keywords to extend the research.
- When you're researching something rare, even crappy search result is better than no result at all. It still provides leads.

Comment: exactly. *all of documentation* IMO should be converted into community-wiki self-answered questions by Community. each example and remarks sections for each topic automatically converted apiece with some auto-generated title. this will preserve the content a.o.t. destroying it (and letting users on data-dump content chase ***is*** just the same as destroying it). as for becoming obsolete, many older Q&A entries are (becoming) obsolete anyway, and we don't see a mass crusade to eradicate them ahead of time, so why should Documentation content be erased! It shouldn't!

Comment: good entries will with time get up-voted more, bad ones will get downvoted, flagged into low-quality queue and deleted, with time. valuable content will be preserved, bad one deleted. a win-win.

Comment: I don't think a closed resource is a good thing. In these times, things change like very often. What is a really good approach today couldn't be the best way tomorrow and if the possibility of updating is not there I think the best is that the docs aren't there in the first place. It could confuse more than help.

Comment: archive.is seem a better alternative than scraping manually :)
I understand that the downvote has a different semantics here.  But the only thing that I wrote is that a static Documentation *can still* be beneficial to users, so logically a downvoter thinks that it cannot help people. I'll make my argument clearer

Comment: in most cases, there aren't "no documentation," we're just losing SO documentation, not all the official documentation that the SO documentation is duplicating. We aren't really losing much.

Comment: @KevinB I wrote original documentation and useful tricks I've invented and wanted to share. For what it's worth - SO is throwing away this as well. I didn't expect SO will delete it, I wouldn't have invested so much

Comment: @KevinB you can only form an *informed* opinion on tags that you frequent / have expertise on. **not** the others. Even if just 5% of the whole of Doc is good original content, it would be **exactly** like throwing the proverbial baby out with the dirty bath water.

Comment: it's not rocket science to pick out a sample number of examples and then check official docs.

Comment: @KevinB Some of my original contributions are not documented anywhere else. I'm not sure what's more insulting, SO throwing my work or all the down voters here that can't care less.

Comment: It would be nice of StackExchange to provide users with a way to easily export their own contributions, at least in markdown and HTML format. Then you could easily transfer them to Wikibooks, for instance. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354416/1333493

Comment: "I don't have a coding blog to move my content to, so my work will go down the drain." Depends a bit also on you. Move it to Q&A (self answered Qs), create a blog, put in into a wikibook (new or existing one), ... Your work can be preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Trilarion. My contributions are not enough material to open a blog or a wiki book for. Self answered Qs may be suitable, but seem a bit out of context. I'll probably just keep my backup offline for now.

Comment: I lost my backup of my contribution. If anyone has a link to some mirror, I'll appreciate it

Answer (score -5):

I have not been a big proponent of Stack Overflow Documentation.

I did think it had possibilities. But I created my account to write answers that I would own and get credit for as long as I could curate them. So I didn't contribute much to Documentation.

The linkage to reputation on Stack Overflow seems to encourage gaming behavior and what I considered to be poor edits.

I have also come to view it as diluting the value of my reputation score with an additional questionable source of reputation.

I do remain optimistic. The problems with documentation could be worked out. Perhaps we need more of a Wikipedia-style approach to it. Maybe we need more hierarchical views, and perhaps we should give some editors more control of the strategic direction and overall shape of topics and subtopics.

However, I don't think it makes sense to tie our accounts together.

### Proposal

I propose that you spin off documentation as a separate Stack Exchange site/product. Separate reputation - make it like it never happened on Stack Overflow - maybe show it on Stack Overflow like any other SE account. On Documentation.SE, start off with shadow reputation from Stack Overflow for the first years so that the *right* people have the most privileges and greatest influence in shaping the direction of it.

The site could even make use of Stack Overflow's answers' Creative Commons licenses, and take the best from the answers on Stack Overflow to create a mega wiki/compendium of documentation.

I don't think this is a panacea. I do think it could help address *some* problems and avoid throwing the baby out with the bath water.

For myself, in regards to Python, I'm still thinking I'm more likely to continue to contribute to CPython documentation (as I've begun to do) than contribute to Documentation.SE - but for other topics, like Haskell or Unix, I could easily see myself contributing edits here and there, e.g. on code/command samples.

### What does Stack Overflow and its community bring to the table?

I've already alluded to these things, but to list them:

- Platform - it's built. Perhaps it won't get much love from developers. But it's there.
- Site Reputation - Stack Overflow is the number one site for developers. Should I trust some other arbitrary site owners with this?
- Users - the community has a great reputation as well.
- User reputations - this can influence decision making with regards to structure.
- Community - I'm more likely to contribute to a linked site.

There's not much to stop others from reposting content from Stack Overflow, but they don't have reputation or credibility. Any new unaffiliated site will have to earn a new reputation - probably from scratch.

Comment: There is no reason someone else could not make your proposal happen just as well as we could. What would Stack Overflow (the company and the community) bring to the table?

Comment: well, the part where reputation from docs doesn't inflate SO rep, but otherwise nothing.

Comment: @KevinB Literally anyone can create a version of Docs that doesn't inflate SO rep...SO are the only people that can create a version of docs that *does* inflate SO rep.

Comment: @Servy i meant, this suggestion would remove the bonus rep that so docs has added, where as any other tool taking this over wouldn't.

Comment: @KevinB Even if SO *did* make a new Docs site (say Docs 2.0) that didn't share rep with SO, they've made it pretty clear that they wouldn't remove the rep from the beta even then.  If they're not going to remove it now, even after acknowledging that it wasn't useful content (on the whole), then there isn't much room for change.

Comment: @JonEricson I think that this's a decent idea. When Docs was in private beta, it [was on a separate site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330259/what-is-docs-beta-stackexchange-com) - docs-beta.stackexchange.com. I really liked that, especially that the rep's separated from SO and users won't be motivated solely by rep. At the same time, those with good content can contribute to share their knowledge. Since the whole platform's built for almost 2 years, I really hope that this idea can be considered!

Answer (score -8):

I really loved this "Documentation BETA" project, I thought that it will be a great project, I can't believe that such a project will be aborted. I would love to help keeping it with all my forces. You say that you don't have enough money to realise all the projects, okey I understand that, but there is always a solution. I have a suggestion, I don't know how to realise it technically, but I'm sure that it can be done. My suggestion is: give this project to the world, propose the tasks that are done to realise this project by your engineers to volunteer engineers around the world. and I'm sure that they will embrace it. Please take my suggestion in consideration. Don't kill this project, It's like wiki of Informatics.

Comment: One of the main problems with Docs was that there already *are* other resources out there that did what it was trying to do better, so, in effect, this *already happened* before Docs even released.  It wasn't filling a void left by other sites/products/etc., some of which are volunteer based, some aren't.  Docs also didn't really do anything innovative or unique; so it's not like there's something for anyone else to need to emulate in particular.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but there is a good advantage on this particular project, it's created by the best community ever, so if you read a "normal documentation" you will have "normal information" which is good enough, but I saw things differently (or at least i dreamed that it will be so different), I thought that if a documentation is written by this community it will be a documentation + an experience of manipulation, which is the more important thing.

Comment: There are already lots of resources out there that have community contributions of information providing the same information that Documentation was trying to provide, and doing it better.  As much as you *wanted* it to provide quality content, it just didn't.  It provided lots of low quality contributions, lots of plagiarism, lots of bad information, and little good information, and much of that stemmed from major problems with how the software was fundamentally designed, as it encouraged this bad behavior and didn't incentivise good behavior.  The Docs community *was the problem*.

Comment: I understand what u say, so i think that i was just making illusion of this documentation, thanks for making things clear to me, I apreciate that =D.

Answer (score -8):

I have been reading through the answers and they have all provided very valuable feedback and ideas. Couldn't you have made an announcement a few 
months before this so you could take feedback and give the docs one more chance ?

Comment: They got lots of feedback, but they ignored most of it.

Answer (score -8):

You worked a lot on it... so many work, and now it is gone.

I am really sorry for that. I think, it should have been maybe more similar to the main site.

Admitting that it is not my concern, but I have the impression, that maybe you tend to give up things too eagerly. Don't let the many negative effects to influence you, if you have a goal.

Comment: `maybe you tend to give up things too eagerly` Wut? This project has had months and months of tryouts and feedback. SO kept pushing it for months despite knowing there was lots of issues with it. They really tried hard. They didn't give up anything, and certainly not eagerly...

Comment: I think, find informations, like very upvotes posts, can improve the documentation by giving informations. We should conserve this, reliable, informations   in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -9):

My understanding is that Stack Overflow (including Documentation) was designed with the intent that it would be the go to reference for things, which means there will exist links to that documentation both on and off the site.  Breaking those links is something of a breach of trust.

I understand the objection that the information might become out-of-date, but that's also true of most other sources out there, and most changes to the topics being discussed would be incremental rather than breaking changes (and in the cases where the changes *do* invalidate a good amount of what came before, enough people will just keep using the old version (e.g. Python 2 vs 3) that the old documentation will retain its value).  Breaking links is an extreme solution to something that usually won't even be a problem.

I propose that we just make Documentation readonly and add a big disclaimer at the top of each page that states it to be an archive of the documentation as it existed on August 8, 2017, and warns that some parts may be out of date.

Or if that isn't an option, at least throw together a script that submits each page in Documentation to the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/) (and set the old urls to redirect there).  That would make it *quite* clear that it's an old archive, but without throwing away all the information (and making it available only as a JSON archive or something is basically the same as throwing it away for most purposes; nobody is going to download and search an archive just to access a dead link).

Comment: Yeah, an archived version should be provided. A "smart" solution would be to import everything into Wikibooks (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354416/1333493) and then redirect every URL to the corresponding page ID or revision ID. Otherwise, make a big WARC file with ArchiveTeam technology and serve it with a WARC proxy.

Answer (score -9):

The lesson learned seem entirely inadequate?  As [Joel wrote](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/26/designing-for-people-who-have-better-things-to-do-with-their-lives/):

> Users don’t have the manual, and if they did, they wouldn’t read it.
>   In fact, users can’t read anything, and if they could, they wouldn’t
>   want to.

Nobody learns by reading documentation: not carpenters, not engineers, and not programmers.  The only way to learn is by doing.

Documentation is just a holy grail for groups of people brainstorming about the software world.  Hey, if we had documentation:

- we'd field fewer support calls
- we would not have to spend time making a new engineer productive
- we'd have departments aligned at the start of a project
- we'd have designed the software correctly at the start

No, no, no, no.

Comment: "The only way to learn is by doing." In that shortended form it sounds a bit paradoxical. After all you can only do what you know how to do. I guess what you (don't) propose here is that tutorials would be a cool idea instead of documentation. But then I thought the idea of Documentation was that it should be example centric. So in a way they wanted learning by doing, only it didn't work out.

Comment: @Trilarion: Alternatively worded, you learn by making mistakes. Examples are great, especially practice questions, like you get on an online learning platform like Coursera or EdX.

Comment: Joel was explaining UI design, which is not _quite_ the same thing. I don't know about the rest, but I do see evidence that [adding links to documentation reduces support tickets](http://jericson.github.io/2015/04/08/customer-support-4.html). I can also say from personal experience that much of the time learning a new programming language is dedicated to reading and especially manuals. The aerospace engineers I know consult technical manuals to avoid making very costly mistakes. The larger the project, the more time is wasted when people don't write down what they know.

Answer (score -11):

Noob here. I am sorry to hear this; Documentation has been such a help for me.

How can I download all the content from the Documentation? I read it will be kept somehow, but... just in case.

I'm interested in the Android, Python, and Java tags.
Can someone more experienced than me make a ZIP file of the HTML pages?

Comment: We'll publish a JSON archive after the 8th. It's entirely possible someone will decide to host the content. At the moment we don't have plans to archive the HTML pages, but we have considered that idea.

Answer (score -11):

**Stickers!**

Please consider sending stickers (for laptop covers, etc.) or some kind of cheap but visible souvenir swag to people who participated in Documentation. It's a good way to give us a smile, a memory, and a few obscure bragging rights.

I had high hopes for it. I participated because I hoped to make it possible for fellow programmers to look up collectively curated ways of solving nontrivial problems.  But, if it wasn't heading for a tipping point, it didn't make sense to continue doing it. That would waste Stack Exchange money and contributor time.

I hang around with some lawyers. They talk about case law -- the accumulated weight of what's been decided by judges -- and black-letter law -- the codified spelled-out regulations. I think SO is a fantastic case-law-style resource for our profession. I know we lack good black-letter-law style resources, and it's good that the SO krewe tried to create one.

But it's tremendously hard to convert case law to black letter law. In hindsight it's obvious that SO's power comes from the case-law-like Q&A format. But we wouldn't have known that if SO handn't tried the Documentation experiment.

Did I mention, Stickers!

Answer (score -14):

> discontinuing Documentation will be breaking the internet just a bit

Yes, it will indeed.

As many others are pointing out here, at least some of the content is actually very valuable because it took considerable effort to sort it out.

Not removing Documentation leads to two issues: a lot of info is not valuable/harmful and *can not be fixed anymore* and; even if the info is good, it will become outdated at some point.

These are both good points. However, it still seems a waste if the good content is removed. If only there were *other* solutions...

Wait! The *good* content can easily be filtered out because this is actually the content that gets actively linked (e.g. in Q&A-posts). Why not retain only the parts of Documentation that have the privilege of being linked to?

That only leaves the problem of the info getting outdated. This is not an issue only for Documentation. Searching the Internet for solutions often lead to (very) outdated information. This also holds for the older Q&A's on SO. I often wish that there would be some way to pre-filter a search result (be it on Google or directly on SO) on outdated-ness.

I see one solution for this issue, but it is a bold one: why not propose at W3 (and at least start using) a new HTTP response header? Let's e.g. use `207 Outdated Content`. This would be equal to `200` with the exception that it is now clear that the information has a limited life time.

Perhaps, the content could (that is, only the *linked* Documentation pages) be served with `200` for a while, but after that, automatically convert it to the new HTTP-code. Maybe e.g. one year or so after the last edit.

Stretching this idea a bit, it could also be `207 Deprecated`, suggesting that these responses SHOULD carry a `Valid-Until` header. For software, this could be a software version number, but more generally it could be a date. After this date, content can be (but does not need to be) removed and the (regular) `410 Gone` is returned instead (or `301 Moved Permanently` where applicable).

Comment: This is pretty clever, but it (especially the second half) is really beyond our means, without even thinking hard about the merits of the ideas.

Comment: I was thinking that SE might have some influence at W3 because of the size and following. However, I do realize the 'boldness' of my suggestion. I thought: better pitch it... But the first part still stands: it's a waste if all the work was gone. Filtering the good from the bad/ugly _can_ be done based on whether the content is linked to.

Comment: @MartenKoetsier Do you have any idea just how long it would take to get something like that ratified and then incorporated into browsers? :)

Comment: Yes, years. If not, more. But it would seem that standards evolve from suggestions like this. Maybe, just maybe, this starts the butterfly-effect... :)

Answer (score -16):

I'm sad to see it go. I keep hearing about how great Documentation was because of examples and tips. Well that is exactly what I tried to do but was shot down. So I stopped trying to improve Documentation because I felt I couldn't get past the gate keepers, which was very disappointing.

> Users with less Stack Overflow experience tended to be intimidated by the prospect of making even trivial edits.

That is why it failed to attract new users in my opinion. It is a compounded version of the "SO flaming" new users get now with asking "stupid" questions. I think it is better than it was, because I've seen questions get answered now that used to be flames, but it still happens.

Documentation was a great idea. It just needs more clarification about what is acceptable to post. Documentation on the web does suck, and I was hoping this was going to fix it.

Comment: Not sure you're correct here. I think it was a good idea, but poorly implemented. There's no such thing as a one-size-fits-all style.

Comment: Everything you suggested an improvement for was approved.  You suggested one entire new topic, and it was rejected for having technical inaccuracies (and the person that rejected it went into some depth on the matter with you).

Comment: Well I'm still sad to see Documenation go.

Answer (score -18):

Can't give one more shot?

I am Stack Overflow user. I come to Stack Overflow from Google search results. It is very rare that I come to Stack Overflow and search.

I think documentation is not popular because it does not come in search results.

- I have not seen documentation links in Google.
- I have not seen documentation links within Stack Overflow search results.

Is documentation is searchable? Can we make it google-able and run the documentation for few more months?

Comment: The beta was always very one sided. All about content creators and less about content consumers

Comment: things like reorganising reputation rewards were given high priority while a simple bug in the search results took many weeks

Comment: They didn't show up in many search results because the content didn't *merit* showing up in many search results.  The problem was that the actual content in there wasn't good, not that there was good content that Google was ignoring.

Comment: Okay, But why not is StackOverflow search results? Even if I search for that exact documentation title.

Comment: It was intentionally kept out of Stack Overflow and Google search results because it was in "beta". The content was not yet up to snuff, so it didn't make sense to have it available in searches.

Comment: @CodyGray If the reason for taking it down and the measurement for evaluation are the number of users, than keeping it from search results was a bit of a self defeating policy, don't you think? Other than that, sure the structure wans't perfect, but the concept is, and implementation can be improved upon over time.

Comment: The metric isn't the number of *visitors*, it's the number of *contributors*. They advertised it for virtually the entire public beta period with a giant banner on the SO homepage, so I very much doubt that prospective contributors were unaware of it.

Answer (score -19):

> ### What happens to badges?
>
> We also have a longstanding policy against revoking badges. But we've
> never had a badge set for a discontinued beta feature either. While we
> could just retire them, it seems confusing to show expired
> Documentation features on the list of badges. In addition, we'd lose a
> lot of good names for potential future badges. As a compromise, anyone
> who earned a Documentation badge other than Educated (for reading the
> tour) will be issued a newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge.
> Does this seem fair?

I wanted to specifically respond to this section since it has a fair number of comments beneath the OP that I agree with.

> How about a gold badge for users who were awarded with all
> Documentation badges? :p – [honk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2675154/honk)

> The silver badge sounds nice, but dang if it isn't replacing 3 silver
> badges and 8 bronze ones... as well as my first ever fully-achieved
> badge section. I like @honk's suggestion... a silver badge for those
> who participated and a gold badge for those who earned every single
> badge in the Docs section :-) – [TylerH](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh)

> Why not create a gold, silver and bronze documentation-beta badge, and
> award each of them once each for each documentation badge you had? So
> if you had 2 silver and 5 bronze doco badges, you'd get 2
> documentation-beta-silver and 5 documentation-beta-bronze badges.
> Solves every problem? – [Steve Bennett ㄹ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/263268/steve-bennett-%E3%84%B9)

Take these all together, I'd like to see the following.

[Bronze] Documentation - Awarded for each Bronze badge earned during Documentation Beta

[Silver] Documentation - Awarded for each Silver badge earned during Documentation Beta

[Gold] Documentation - Awarded for completing the Documentation badge set during Documentation Beta

This would preserve the badge count for everyone who participated in Documentation, and recognize each contribution made during the beta.

Comment: Gold badges are intentionally exclusive.  Bronze badges are intentionally trivial.  It makes sense to me to quality this as a silver badge, since participating in Documentation wasn't trivial, but wasn't exclusive, either.

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting so much downvoted, as this makes a perfect sense to me. You want to clean up the badge names? Fine, just unify them under something. The original badge name could be accessible in the badge review page, like the one that shows where you got your post badges (e.g. Nice Answer).

Answer (score -25):

Speaking as somebody who was always mentioning the feature to fellow developers most of whom A) Use Stack Overflow every day, and B) didn't know about it, I am disappointed. I think the tool wasn't really given a chance to flourish.

Comment: What opportunities do you think it needed to be given that it wasn't given?

Comment: What would have helped impove visibility I think is proper linking facilities. The interlinking between sections was clunky and unobvious, and linking from answers on the main site should have been better facilitated, maybe along the lines of how you are presented with similar existing questions when you post a new question.

Comment: I am not sure if any of these things were tried...but first thing might be to interface with learning institutions like colleges and code bootcamps to make it a defacto place to go for canonical and vetted documentation about some aspect of a language.  It would have been the perfect remedy to sifting through PHP.net which is often as maddening as it is helpful without real transparent vetting and discussion of code examples.

Comment: @Servy "What opportunities do you think it needed to be given that it wasn't given?" Maybe the crap that was not removed. If crap/low quality content would have been removed from consequently from first week, contributors who can contribute high quality content would not have given up in the second week. Also there should have been the discussion feature from day one of public beta. It's one year too late for that, I know.

Comment: @MikeChastain That would have been an awful idea.  The main problem with the feature was that tons of people posted tons of crap content, much of which was plagiarized, and very few people actually posted good content.  Directing lots of new programmers (particularly those that wouldn't know the difference between good content and bad content) would have been harmful.

Comment: @Trilarion Sure, but *how* do you remove the crap?  The problem is that people came in droves to contribute crap, and very few people came to clean it up.  It's not that they didn't have mechanisms to clean it up so much as the fact that they were simply so overwhelmed by the numbers, and vigor, of those submitting bad content.

Answer (score -30):

I feel that this is a big shame. The docs were the best docs I've ever come across, but I understand why the decision has been made.

I just hope it comes back.