# Where did the chat room for Documentation go?

Tags: support, documentation, chat

I remember that there's a chat room to discuss the public beta of Documentation.

The link's https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta. However, when I navigate to this link now, the room is not found.

Is the room deleted or has the link been changed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The room has been automatically frozen for inactivity, because nobody used it any more.

It was eventually deleted on July 11 with the last official message:

> Hi everyone! Given we are presently running the T-SQL experiment to iterate our way into what Documentation should look like, we are going to go ahead and delete this room by EOD today. We will get this back up when the timing is right! -- [Vasudha Swaminathan](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38050785#38050785)

Although it probably will never come back.

Comment: Considering [Documentation is being sunsetted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/), very unlikely yes.