# Remove prompt for Documentation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, sidebar

With Documentation going through [sunsetting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation?cb=1), perhaps the prompt should be removed from questions page as well. [image: documentation prompt shown under featured box]

Comment: Thanks Shamas. Yes, it's on our list of things to remove from the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That widget will be gone with the next production build.