# Is there a timeline for the sunsetting of Documentation?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, documentation

As Documentation has sunsetted on Tuesday, contributions to Docs are no longer accepted and the review queue was shut down too, which was the plan mentioned in the announcement.

> After August 8, 2017 at 1700 UTC, we’ll disable proposed changes and wait for pending changes to be reviewed. Once the review queue is cleared, it'll be removed from the review menu and page.

And I presume removing all the links to Documentation in the Q & A section will be next since they have to be removed before the Docs pages can be removed.

> Until the suggested edit process is finished, Documentation pages will remain available on the site.

**So, is there a rough estimate on when this process will start?**

---

In addition, what I understand, there are a few aspects to the sunset, as outlined in [the announcement of the closure of Docs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation):

- review queue [[done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354789/good-bye-documentation-please-remove-the-link-from-review-queue-list)]
- reputation
- badges
- links to Documentation
- questions on Meta

So, completing shutting down Documentation will take some time as there are many references to Docs scattered around Stack Overflow, but I'm just curious **when will the final plan for reputation and badges be announced** and **whether there is a timeline by the Docs team on when will Docs sunset completely**? (Maybe 1 month? 6 to 8 weeks? 3 months?)

Comment: You already said 6 to 8 weeks. Why do you need another estimate?

Comment: @rene Not quite official enough ;-)

Comment: AFAIK that is the official estimate for all the things here ...

Comment: Is that estimate kind of like @codygray's Free Beer Tomorrow?

Comment: Difference is, @SandPiper, [6 to 8 weeks is an established meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) from the early days of SO's history. My sense of humor is…original.

Comment: @Panda we will be making a post within the next day or two to outline exactly that. We'll update everyone on the final plan for all of those considerations (now that we have weighed in all your responses as well) and plan to begin the link migration work this week. Our estimate is 4-6 more weeks for the entire sunset to get wrapped up but a lot of it is dependent on how quickly we can get through the links. Details coming soon!

Comment: 4-6 weeks! That must be a real estimate... right?

Comment: @Machavity only if you have a Valve clock.

Comment: @VasudhaSwaminathan Thanks for the estimate, looking forward to the detailed outline!

Comment: The last item, which depends on reading a ton of meta posts, will likely take longer than the rest.

Comment: As promised, [the details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355115/documentation-is-read-only-what-s-next).

Comment: @VasudhaSwaminathan That's very clear and comprehensive, thanks!