# Removing Documentation: Reputation, Archive, and Links

Tags: discussion, documentation

**Update:** More details about attribution and the current status of link removal can be found in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357661/1438).

---

[Last time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355115/documentation-is-read-only-what-s-next) I promised we’d release a JSON archive, preserve reputation earned on Documentation, issue replacement badges, organize a link-cleanup posse and finalize an attribution policy. However, as [Nick Craver tweeted](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/905542844156436481):

> Stack Overflow reputation is really hard to calculate.

Adam Lear and Nick have been working through innumerable edge cases to be sure nothing will break when we remove the Documentation code. Their tests have turned up latent issues with how non-Documentation reputation is tracked. We found a few issues with the reputation history records that we use to audit reputation, so we wanted to make sure there were no *actual* reputation bugs (good news: haven't found any) before going ahead with setting Documentation reputation in stone.

### Archive

I’m pleased to announce the JSON archive for Documentation, which may be downloaded from [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). It has a README file that explains the various files and their contents. I’ve also been putting together some examples of how to use the archive over at [so_docs](https://github.com/jericson/so_docs) on GitHub. If you need help using the archive, please [ask on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=documentation,discussion,archive). Alternatively, if the question is on topic on Stack Overflow itself, ask there.

### Attribution

When using Documentation content, it’s important to credit contributors. If you are the sole author, you may use your topics and examples without adding any sort of attribution; the content belongs to you. But if any of the contributors are *not you*, please add the following notice somewhere visible on the page:

> This content was ported over from Stack Overflow Documentation, now retired. To access the source and attribution please access the [Docs archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z) and reference topic ID: ## and example ID: ##.

**For more details, please see the Attribution section of the [previous update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355115/documentation-is-read-only-what-s-next).**

### Link removal

With those pieces in place, it’s now time to start looking at removing links to Documentation from Q&A posts. (Thank you again for [encouraging us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354222/1438) to entrust this job to the community.) If you want to be a part of this project, you can jump right in by editing one of the posts listed in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dqCXFuEp9aH-vR350ZGFE0pCcT9Baf9S6a5ShIgw_v4/edit?usp=sharing).

Please keep these guidelines in mind:

- If the example or topic add little or nothing to a post’s usefulness, just remove the link. For instance, a sentence like “You can find more information . . .” can just be removed. So can a link to a topic about a general programming concept.
- If Documentation content helps answer the question, copy the relevant portion. Be sure to follow our [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and include the attribution notice above.  For your convenience, we’ve also included a link in the spreadsheet to the contributors of each topic or example. We've also included a direct link to Example Markdown:

  [image: Markdown link]
- Please consider also fixing other problems with the post while you are editing it.
- When you are done with a link, mark it as "Handled" in [the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dqCXFuEp9aH-vR350ZGFE0pCcT9Baf9S6a5ShIgw_v4/edit?usp=sharing):

  [image: Handled with care.]

  That'll also update the summary tab:

  [image: Summary tab]

  Green means all the tag's posts are handled, red means > 50 are outstanding and yellow is somewhere in between.

  Unfortunately, anonymous users have been vandalizing the spreadsheet, so we are now requiring people to request permission to edit:

  [image: Request permission]

  You'll need to be logged into Google account to edit. Be aware that other editors will have access to your Gmail address and G+ profile. Once the links are cleaned up, we'll delete the spreadsheet. Feel free to edit out links without updating the spreadsheet, if you prefer.

I’ve also created [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153924/documentation-links) for coordinating activity. It’s a good place to ask about specific examples, too.

### Code & UI element removal

As the link cleanup process commences, our developers will begin removing code and page elements related to Documentation. In particular, the topbar menu item and the search bar on Docs will be removed soon. However, we’re not going to remove the content itself until the link cleanup is completed.

Comment: With regards to cleaning up documentation links, it might be best that only users with [editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) work through the questions. As Cody Gray [said in a discussion about burninations](/a/356032/5764553): _"Philosophically, at less than 2k reputation, you are probably not sufficiently qualified to make independent judgments about how to make good edits....At <2k, all you can do is suggest edits, which just makes more work for everyone."_

Comment: @AndrewMyers: I think a lot of the edits in this case don't require much expertise. In particular, removing links that merely point to Documentation requires not much more than understanding how formatting works. Ideally all the edits would be done by people who can do them unilaterally, but I think reviewing these edits won't take too much time/effort.

Comment: @JonEricson Didn't we recently have a problem with the Suggested Edits queue being completely full, blocking edits from being submitted? Unless there's been a surge of reviewers that brings us not just back to, but above the previous queue throughput, we shouldn't be putting these in the queue.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Right at the moment, there are 141 suggested edits awaiting approval, so the queue isn't close to full. There are ~3440 links to be removed, but presumably they won't all be edited at the same time and probably not all by users who need their edits approved. We're also doing some A/B tests of review queue danger indicators that should help bring in new reviewers as needed. More details coming next week.

Comment: I also do not support encouraging users with less than 2k rep to engage in the link clean up. At best it is just busy work for the reviewers, at worst it can cause problems. Not to mention the fact that editors should not _just_ be removing links if there are other issues with the post, they should be addressing all issues with the posts when editing.

Comment: Is there a way in the sheet to track whether a particular post has already been edited by someone else?

Comment: Yeah, lets keep busy the button smashing monkeys...

Comment: @NisargShah: You can leave a comment, which will show up as a number on the tab. For smaller tags, I'd recommend leaving a comment once you are done with all the posts. We can also add a column (and enable editing) if that'll help. We're not at all sure what will work for you all.

Comment: @JonEricson Either should be fine, as long as everyone follows the same practice.

Comment: @Jon Ericson can i change the link with another one with the same goal or idea instead of remove it?

Comment: @JonEricson You might want to add your `@stackoverflow.com` email to your account so you can get credit for your commits on GitHub.

Comment: @YCF_L: Absolutely. That would be an ideal resolution.

Comment: JOn, I see that attribution still seems under discussion with answers here, but when concrete enough it may be beneficial to add this info and that on removals to some static page (say in the help pages) rather than having to search past meta posts and answers to find the most current requirements

Comment: Just delete Documentation and if people talk about it act like you don't know what they're talking about. Leave the rep because if you delete rep users have earned they (we) will come with pitchforks and torches. We know where SE lives. But all of us who remember how bad it was will help cover up the fact that Documentation ever happened. It will be our little secret.

Comment: **For all of those (like me) who are missing the content "Documentation beta" provided, [here you can find help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356673/1016343)... I didn't find the JSON archive helpful at all.**

Comment: [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46333366/6535336) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46333340/6535336) [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46333316/6535336) today, all answered using un-attributed documentation.  How are we going to keep track of this in order to get attribution correctly assigned?

Comment: "Anonymous users have been vandalizing the spreadsheet" It's really funny and naive to believe you could allow all the internet to edit a document without trolls coming along to sabotage it.

Comment: @idmean: We talked about it before opening it up to anonymous editors and decided it was worth trying. I'd say "optimistic" rather than "naive". (But I'd also accept "naively optimistic".)

Comment: To help you with **attribution,** I believe we would need a tool like a **Doc Beta offline reader.**

Comment: So the Community user is now outright removing whole paragraphs of text that includes links to documentation you no longer want to own? That's bad and has the potential to just invalidate whole answers on Stack Overflow. I understand that you no longer wants to accept new documentation entries, but please reconsider what should happen to existing links to documentation entries [from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40753152/267].

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That's not the Community user. Rolling back the change (as you have done) is fine for now, but what happens when those links break? If you want to replace them with another link, this is a good time to do it. Or, you can edit in the content, if you prefer. I think your [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40753152/1) is sufficient, but it's up to you.

Comment: Holy crap, I am too tired to see straight. My apologies entirely! :( Those links, however, should not break but that's an entirely other discussion. I'm going to have a long talk with my eyes to see the difference between the username of whoever made the change *below* and *above* the change being made.

Comment: But nevertheless, I see you are actively contributing to link rot on the internet. I cannot condone this. I will have to remove myself from contributing to Stack Overflow in the future. Your experiment failed, whoop de doo, but this does not give you the right to actively remove contributed content from the internet. Apparently you think so, so this is where we part ways. So long.

Comment: @Someone: We kinda remove contributed content all the time. We even remove entire sites from time to time. But as always, the content is archived so you (or anyone who has the motivation) can save it somewhere else. This is a good thing because there's no guarantee we will be around forever. I'm sad to see Documentation go too, but it wasn't in the cards.

Comment: 'documentation' is still a tab on my profile page (edits, reviews). is this going to be removed too?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Yes, that's on the list. It might be among the last things to go since it's a good way for people to find their content.

Answer (score 120):

### I find your lack of attribution disturbing.<sup>1</sup>

What you've suggested for attribution does not fulfill the attribution requirements imposed by [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode), under which Stack Exchange has licensed the contributions from users. *Just* linking to a data dump and saying "go find the attribution for this somewhere over there" isn't sufficient. Even if the "attribution" was a link which went directly to a page which contained the content, it would be insufficient.<sup>2</sup> In my opinion, having the only attribution being a link to an archive, where you're telling people to go dig through a non-human-readable set of data files<sup>3</sup> to find the author information, is significantly worse. You're basically saying that Stack Exchange considers it acceptable to skip including the attribution required by CC BY-SA 3.0 when it's *just inconvenient* to include the attribution.

### For attribution, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) requires that you list:<sup>4</sup>

1. The copyright notice for the work <sup>CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(c)</sup>
2. At least a link to the license URI<sup>5,</sup> <sup>CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(a)</sup>
3. The original author(s)' username(s) <sup>CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(c)(i)</sup>
4. The title of the work  <sup>CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(c)(ii)</sup>
5. A URI to the work<sup>6,</sup> <sup>CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(c)(iii)</sup> and
6. Clearly indicate any changes you've made. <sup>CC BY-SA 3.0 § 3(b) and § 4(c)(iv)</sup>

The only time these are not required is if the author has given notice, under CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(a), that they desire for their credit to be removed. In such case, you must remove the attribution.

### Stack Exchange *does not* have the right to change this retroactively

CC BY-SA 3.0 is the license under which the authors licensed their contributions to Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange is just a licensee of that content. It doesn't hold the copyright to the user content. It doesn't own the user content. It's not the author. Stack Exchange *does not* have the right to change the terms of the license retroactively.

While what you have suggested is *convenient* for Stack Exchange, changing a legal agreement retroactively is not acceptable.<sup>7</sup> Stack Exchange could have made your suggested attribution what's acceptable by making the change public *prior to the users providing their contributions*, but not after the content has been contributed.

The (non) attribution you have suggested *might* be considered sufficient if all of Stack Exchange was considered a single work. But that's not the view intended by the terms of service, the CC BY-SA 3.0 license, or how Stack Exchange has treated each individual contribution. Given that the Documentation dump is hosted by archive.org, not Stack Exchange, it makes it clear that Stack Exchange is not treating them as all the same work. Thus, such interpretation would be internally inconsistent. So far, and certainly how Documentation was set up, and Stack Exchange in general, each Documentation example, SE question, and SE answer is considered a separate work. Each is individually attributable to the users who have contributed to that individual work.

### Your suggestion to not list contributors conflicts with the data dump

The data dump *license.txt* file explicitly states (emphasis mine):

> So let us clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we *require* that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow Documentation. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the Stack Overflow Documentation archive located at archive.org.
> 3. Indicate topic and example IDs where the content came from.
> 4. **List the contributors (found in contributors.json) with a link to their profile page (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username).**

Note: As written, the above 4 points from the *license.txt* file can only be interpreted as *in addition to* the requirements spelled out in the CC BY SA 3.0 license. If they were intended to limit those requirements, then A) it would need to explicitly state that it's reducing/limiting what's required; and B) Any such limits would have had to be publicly posted *prior to* the users contributing content. When interpreted as additional requirements, these do not conflict with CC BY-SA 3.0.

### This isn't a situation where we get to just say I'd like it to be *this* way.

The contributions have already been made. The license which defines the rights and duties of the parties to the license has already been agreed to. We only get to deal with the situation as it exists, not how we might like it to exist. The only way we would be able to do that is if we got each separate author to agree to new license terms for their work.

## Suggested attribution

Attributing Documentation is complex. I would suggest something like the following text. This is for the example "[Getting started with firefox-addon - Installing unsigned add-ons](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/27244/installing-unsigned-add-ons)":

> The following content is from "Getting started with firefox-addon - Installing unsigned add-ons" from Stack Overflow Documentation ([archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170909011459/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/27244/installing-unsigned-add-ons#t=201709090114592333996)); copyright 2017 by [Makyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen) and [Martin Zhai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790154/martin-zhai); licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). An [archive of the full Stack Overflow Documentation content can be found at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z), in which this example is indexed by its topic ID: 3235, as example: 27244.

Normally, I would strongly recommend including the URL at which the person which is copying the content actually obtained it. In fact, stating where *you* found it is considered a primary criteria for referencing material in most professions.

However, given that the goal here is to remove links to Documentation, I chose to use a link to an archive.org copy of that Documentation page. I had [archive.org](https://archive.org/) create an archive of the Documentation page by going to the Documentation page and clicking on the following [bookmarklet](https://www.google.com/search?q=bookmarklet):

```
javascript:void(window.open('https://web.archive.org/save/'+location.href))
```

---

<sup>I am not a lawyer. The above is based on a basic reading of the CC BY-SA 3.0 license. It should be considered my opinion, and is not legal advice.</sup>

<sup>1. The way this statement is phrased is intended to provide some  humor into a serious subject. ([reference](https://youtu.be/m0XuKORufGk?t=23))</sup>

<sup>2. Along the same lines, just links back to questions/answers from which content was copied from Stack Exchange is insufficient for attribution. Such attribution must include the 6 things listed above. Proper attribution for code from an answer would be [something like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253618/if-i-use-so-code-on-my-website-how-should-i-give-attribution/253622#comment500920_253622):</sup>

> <sup>The following code is from the answer to "If I use SO code on my website, how should I give attribution? - Meta Stack Overflow" at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253622, copyright 2014 and 2017 by Bill the Lizard and Makyen, licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).</sup>

<sup>3. The format is a 7-zip compressed set of JSON encoded data. A human *could* read through the data. However, the significant majority of people would find it difficult to find the authors of a particular post. Admittedly, a higher percentage of Stack Overflow readers would be fine reading through it than the general population.</sup>

<sup>4. CC BY-SA 3.0 qualifies #3–6 [CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(c)(i)–(iv)] as only required when "reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing". However, I don't see that Stack Exchange would *want* to argue that its unreasonable to include them in an SE question/answer. If Stack Exchange makes that argument here, then it opens up that argument to *anyone*, *anywhere*, which isn't consistent with how Stack Exchange has been a proponent of attribution in the past. Basically, IMO, it's reasonable to include those in an SE Q/A if it's reasonable to include them *anywhere*.</sup>

<sup>5. The CC BY-SA 3.0 license is already linked from every Stack Exchange page, so this requirement is covered.</sup>

<sup>6. You don't have to provide the URI to the work if "such URI does not refer to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work". The data dump does include it, so you do need to include the URI to the data dump, if that's the source of where you obtained the information.</sup>

<sup>7. You could write an agreement, and there are ones so written, that allows one party to unilaterally change the agreement. However, what's really required for that to be enforceable is beyond both my expertise and what could be covered here.</sup>

Comment: For what it's worth, we consulted a lawyer when formulating the guidance in the previous update. This isn't something we decided on a whim. I did update the license.txt today however. The version included with the Q&A data dump was clearly not appropriate for this case. I'll double check on the wording next week.

Comment: @JonEricson, I'm glad to hear you consulted with a lawyer. I'm interested in their thinking/reasoning, because, IMO, what you've suggested for "attribution" is inconsistent with a simple reading of the requirements imposed by [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode), which is the controlling document under which all user-content was licensed to Stack Exchange. Frankly, I'm not seeing how they would get to the point of recommending what you've suggested be used.

Comment: @JonEricson, Note CC BY-SA 3.0 does qualify #3–6 above as only required when "reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing". However, I don't see that Stack Exchange would *want* to argue that an SE question/answer as the medium being used makes it unreasonable to include those. If Stack Exchange makes that argument here, then it opens up that argument to *anyone*, *anywhere*, which isn't consistent with how Stack Exchange has been a proponent of attribution in the past. Basically, IMO, it's reasonable to include those in an SE Q/A, if it's reasonable to include them *anywhere*.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with this. "Go find the attribution over there" is not attribution, any more than "Go find the answer over there" is an answer. [Attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required) has always been a big deal at Stack Overflow, and it's never acceptable to say "Go dig through the data dump, referencing post #...", so why would it be acceptable to do that for Documentation? Very concerning to me, actually, that *anyone* at Stack Overflow thought for a minute that this kind of pseudo-attribution would be okay, whether technically legal or not.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm not thrilled with this guidance, but I'm even less excited about people just taking content with no attribution at all. If people include a link to the archive with an example or topic ID, it's at least possible to reconstruct attribution. (I've even been working on [scripts](https://github.com/jericson/so-docs-tools/blob/master/examples/example2html.rb) to do just that.) Since there are examples with dozens of authors, we wanted to know what the minimum requirements of the license are. If people are willing to do more, we are very grateful.

Comment: @Makyen: The Wayback Machine doesn't work for URLs with `%23` in them. That makes [a major portion](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23) of Documentation unavailable. However, we can save the contributor page for each example and topic. As we speak, I'm running a script to [save all contributor pages](https://web.archive.org/web/*/stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/*).

Comment: @JonEricson, that issue could be resolved internal to SE by serving any affected pages at a URL which archive.org supports and providing a redirect during this process at the original URL. Archive.org could then make an archive at the new URL. You'd then need to inform the people making the edits to remove Doc URLs from Q&A that you're doing this, but once they know about the issue, it's a relatively easy thing for them to deal with.

Comment: Am rather stumped by the 1st point in the data dump license.txt file - "*[..] It doesn’t have to be **obnoxious**; a discreet text blurb is fine*"! Did they mean *conspicuous*, or was the word *obnoxious* intended?

Comment: @Abhitalks, I just copied the text from the *license.txt* file. It was probably intended to be similar to the requirement in the [SE TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal#attribution) for additional attribution, which requires mentioning SE as where you found Q/A content. In that text they use "unobtrusive". Other than that, I can't speak to their intent with respect to the wording they used there. However, it does tend to indicate that the text should be interpreted by just a plain reading.

Comment: Thanks Makyen. Just hope someone sees this. [Obnoxious](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obnoxious) has a totally different connotation. I think "*Obtrusive*" would have been intended, and it got mangled. Pinging @JonEricson.

Comment: @Abhitalks Rest assured, we are actively following the thread and comments. Looking into it!

Comment: @Abhitalks: The second meaning of "obnoxious" is intended here. The idea is you don't need to use the [<blink> tag](http://www.montulli.org/theoriginofthe%3Cblink%3Etag) or something to draw attention to the attribution. We can probably find another word, however.

Answer (score 11):

#### Deleted answers and questions containing references to Docs

Mostly as an FYI, I found at least one Docs reference was in a [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111669/how-to-send-parameters-on-awk-to-replace-a-parameter-unix-korn-shell/39112516#39112516) — an answer deleted before I looked at it.  It's not a problem to me, but anybody with less than 10k rep would not be able to see the answer as they go to edit it, which would be confusing.

JFTR, I removed the reference to Docs.  Even if the answer had not been deleted, that would (probably) have been a sensible course of action; the link provided very limited benefit to the answer.

Here is [another already deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429211/what-does-the-following-error-message-mean-error-invalid-operands-to-binary-ex/45429495#45429495) that used to contain a Docs reference — 'twas a "link-only" answer before 'twas deleted.  And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379639/memcpy-works-fine-with-strlenstr1-but-doesnt-work-with-strlenstr/45380193#45380193) is in a fully-deleted question (so the answer is deleted because the question is deleted).  I've encountered a number of others already — it could be quite a common occurrence based on my non-random sampling of two tags.

#### Comments containing references to Docs

Also, closely related, I came across a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417384/behaviour-on-setting-a-pointer-to-a-dangling-pointer/44417650#comment75838579_44417514) (which could be deleted at any time) with a reference to Docs. It was by [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) and it said:

> Well, you might like to read here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior/2775/read-value-of-pointer-that-was-freed#t=201706071809120620508

Because it was primarily a reference to a Docs entry, I flagged it with a custom reason 'No longer needed — link to Docs. Comments are ephemeral; this should simply be removed, as should any other comment referencing a Docs URL.'  I'm not sure whether comments containing docs links were discussed before.

(And now you've got a link to Docs in an MSO answer — I'll leave the resolution of that to someone else.)

#### Indicating that an entry has been processed?

I'm not clear whether we're meant to edit the spreadsheet.  I can only comment, so I've added comments to the entries on the 'awk' and 'c' sheets that I've processed.

Comment: Good catch. I'll check with Adam to see if we can remove deleted posts. We might end up generating a new spreadsheet based on the current state of links on the site. For the moment, we're hoping comments work for you all. But it won't be a problem to allow editing if that seems like a better plan. We didn't want to dictate a process, but we're happy to facilitate one. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson: is there any evidence of anyone else actually editing answers?  If so, they don't seem to be leaving comments in the spreadsheet, so people won't know in general what has been processed and what has not.

Comment: It looks like there were 105 removed over the weekend. So this is going to take awhile unless we make it easier. We're going to have an updated spreadsheet to remove deleted posts and fix whatever bug is [excluding some posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356341/1438). I think I'll open it up to editing (and include a running total) so that people can keep track of what's happened and be encouraged they aren't working in a vacuum.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My email inbox says "yes". :) But I agree with Jon - we should just open the doc up to editing. Commenting alone isn't working out too great.

Comment: What do you think of the [new spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dqCXFuEp9aH-vR350ZGFE0pCcT9Baf9S6a5ShIgw_v4/edit?usp=sharing)? (Credit goes to @AdamLear. Unless you hate it, in which case I blame Lotus 1-2-3 for popularizing spreadsheets.)

Comment: I _think_ it'll be safe to flag Docs links in comments as "no longer needed".

Comment: @JonEricson: (and Adam Lear): the new spreadsheet looks good.  I just completed a trivial tab (recursion), though the editing wasn't as simple as I'd like (because the Q&A had some issues, not because of the removal of references to Docs).  It's hard to get to the worksheets for the tail end of the alphabet; I'm not sure there's a simple way around that, though.  I do like the statistics and the fixed yes/no drop-down is good.  It's definitely a major improvement over the Mark I spreadsheet.

Comment: I'll use the simpler 'no longer needed' flag on some comments when I come across them, and see if the moderators agree.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, it's good to hear that this version is easier to deal with. I agree that navigation is a PITA... There's a sheet selector thingy that should help some: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b44TO.png.

Comment: @JonEricson: I expect you're aware of it, but just in case you've overlooked it, there is still a documentation tab at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=documentation, showing documentation privileges.

Answer (score 7):

### Missing posts in the spreadsheet

While searching for posts with Docs links on Stack Overflow, I seem to notice that some posts are missing from [the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O34K66rXWY_kAQggErIYUkJxZtGzvAj4qBJ1hW5XJJA/edit?usp=sharing).

The **spreadsheet has 3,980 posts** while a search on Stack Overflow using the keywords [`url:stackoverflow.com/documentation/*`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fdocumentation%2F*) shows that there are **4,426 posts that contain Docs links** (as of the time of this post).

Some of the posts that are missing:

- [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress): [Ajax in a wordpress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063228/ajax-in-a-wordpress-page/40064088#40064088)
- [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css): [Get all specific childs from two parents CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050572/get-all-specific-childs-from-two-parents-css/46050670#46050670)
- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php): [How to install zend framework 2 on wamp server ? Its installing 3.02 beta version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380415/how-to-install-zend-framework-2-on-wamp-server-its-installing-3-02-beta-versio/41381092#41381092)

Comment: I can confirm that two of my own posts which contained Documentation links were found with the search term suggested, but were not included in the spreadsheet. However, the search will also find URLs to archive.org archives on Documentation pages. Thus, any that have already been changed to point to a live archive (not the Documentation dump) will be included in the number found. Without some method of filtering out such false positives, this search will show inflated numbers. However, it's better to have a complete list from which we need to prune false-positives than an incomplete list.

Comment: @Makyen Actually, I don't think that the number's inflated much. Any posts with Docs links that are updated to point to the live archive after the spreadsheet's out should still be included in it since edited posts aren't struck off from the spreadsheet. So, unless the posts are edited before the spreadsheet's out, those pointing to the live archive should be included in it.

Comment: Hmm.. I think we might have miscommunicated. I was trying to say the search you've provided will be (somewhat) inflated, which is better than using the spreadsheet, which is missing some actual results. I was trying to state that, based on your reported issue with the spreadsheet, I found two additional posts of my own which were not included on the spreadsheet, which should have been there.

Comment: @Makyen Yup, that makes sense, I concur :)

Comment: Aha, looks like the automatic http->https link conversion didn't trigger a reindex on the modified posts, so there's a bunch of links that are https now but elastic still thinks are http. This is what I get for thinking "it's all https now, I may as well `url:https://stackoverflow.com`", heh. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @AdamLear No problem, thanks for the reply :)

Comment: We have a [new spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dqCXFuEp9aH-vR350ZGFE0pCcT9Baf9S6a5ShIgw_v4/edit?usp=sharing) that should fix the problem.

Comment: The new spreadsheet's great and easier to use, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 6):

All 5034 Documentation links in Q&A have been [handled by the community](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dqCXFuEp9aH-vR350ZGFE0pCcT9Baf9S6a5ShIgw_v4/edit#gid=1667215241). On behalf of the Documentation team, I'd like to thank those of you who pitched in! This worked out imaginably better than I expected. As always, the Stack Overflow community is full of delightful surprises.

Since there’s been some confusion, I’d like to remind everyone that nobody lost reputation when these links were removed from your posts. We’ll be removing Documentation content from the site very soon, so now is the time to fix those links. Rolling back edits is counterproductive.

You might also notice a new "Documentation User" badge (or [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357618/1438)) in your inbox. We're going to be [removing Documentation badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357625/1438) other than the Betas and Pioneers soon. All things (whether good or bad) must come to an end.

---

As [many of you have noticed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356304/1438), our original attribution suggestion was somewhat minimalistic. My primary concern was that some topics and examples were edited by many more people than would be reasonable to list in a Stack Overflow answer. Now that all of the links have been handled, we can see the potential impact. It turns out that none of the [20 attribution blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3aarchive.org%2fdetails%2fdocumentation-dump.7z) were for content edited by dozens of users. So I manually updated   attribution blocks to include all contributors:

[image: Sample attribution block]

I also added the title, a link to the contributor page found on archive.org and a link to the licence used to copy the contribution. For future reference, all topic and example contributor pages are currently archived on archive.org:

- https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/{example_id}
- https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/{topic_id}

While researching attribution, we found a helpful pamphlet from Creative Commons Australia called [Attributing Creative
Commons Materials](http://creativecommons.org.au/materials/attribution.pdf):

> ### Attributing in different mediums
>
> Where possible, the same information should be included regardless of how you are reusing the work. However, sometimes this is impractical or impossible. The CC licences let you change the exact placement, the language or level of detail from medium to medium, as long as your attribution is ‘reasonable to the medium’.
>
> For example, when you are using CC material in a book, it is easy to provide a long, written attribution with all the information next to the work. However, where you use a CC song in a podcast, it is trickier to provide the same amount of information so immediately.

I mention this because I don't want this to become a precedent for unreasonable attribution in posts. It's reasonable to depend on a link to a full list of contributors rather than putting them inline. In fact, on posts themselves we display just the first and last editor (if different). Full attribution can be found by following the "edited" link:

[image: Most recent editor and author of a post]

We got lucky that I was able to list Documentation contributors this time, so I just did it. If you need to [cite a paper with hundreds of authors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63534/how-to-list-a-paper-in-your-cv-when-having-1000-co-authors), it's not necessary to give credit inline. Linking to an outside list of contributors is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: _"This worked out imaginably better than I expected."_ - So it _was_ better than you expected, but still failed to blow your mind? Awww... I guess there's always next time...

Comment: @AndrewMyers: Huh. I can't imagine what I was thinking when I wrote that. Inconceivable!