# Rejected edit when cleaning the documentation links

Tags: discussion, documentation, suggested-edits

I just suggested an edit this post: [Django {%trans%} not working, despite django.po being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610962/django-trans-not-working-despite-django-po-being-generated/38611365#38611365)
to remove the link to the documentation.

The link to the documentation does not add any useful information to the answer, and I thought simply removing the reference to the URL was the action to take, as described here : [Removing Documentation: Reputation, Archive, and Links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links?cb=1)

> If the example or topic add little or nothing to a post’s usefulness, just remove the link. For instance, a sentence like “You can find more information . . .” can just be removed.

However, my edit has been rejected with

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Here is a direct [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17331483) to the suggestion.

Am I missing something?

Comment: BTW, a second one has been rejected: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17331360

Comment: There's a good reason that it's *highly* suggested that major cleanup efforts be worked on by those with 2k rep, rather than those that need to suggest edits.  Processes like these are much harder to handle via suggested edits.

Comment: if anything, maybe additional  link to the meta post in your comment instead of only *Documentation cleanup* https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17331483

Comment: Yet there's not a single word of SE suggesting that users with less than 2k can't help.

Comment: A comment from SE even says the opposite: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links?cb=1#comment512490_356294

Comment: also see: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39112000#39112000 and I pinged Jon in that chatroom

Comment: Looks like the link in the edit comment works. My suggestions are getting approved now.

Comment: @Dunatotatos No, that link *doesn't* say the opposite.  It says that it's desirable for the edit to be done by those that can do so unilaterally, which is what I said.

Comment: The second edit that you mention in comment was rejected because a reviewer clicked "reject and edit" and replaced the link with a link to official documentation. You could argue "Improve edit" might be more fair, but as for the content quality, their edit is better than yours.

Comment: @JiriTousek Actually, [as you can see in the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35940264/revisions), the user that reject-edited left the link to Documentation as it originally was (revision 9). The original poster edited the link to point to official documentation a few hours later (revision 10).

Comment: @AndrewMyers I stand corrected. My bad.

Comment: I stand by [my original comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links?cb=1#comment512497_356294): _"I also do not support encouraging users with less than 2k rep to engage in the link clean up. At best it is just busy work for the reviewers, at worst it can cause problems. Not to mention the fact that editors should not just be removing links if there are other issues with the post, they should be addressing all issues with the posts when editing."_

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I realize this is frustrating, since you were trying to do what you were asked to do, but the reviewers who rejected your edit were *correct*.

Why? Your edit *removed content* from the answer without any obvious valid reason. That's either vandalism or simply an unwanted drastic change, depending on how charitable the reviewers are.

A significant part of the problem was your edit summary:

> Documentation cleanup

That has a very non-obvious meaning. Someone has to connect the dots to realize that you're talking about Stack Overflow's "Documentation" project, which is being discontinued, and thus requires a bunch of dead links to be cleaned up. Not everyone knows about this (yes, despite it being [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)), and it's your job as an editor to make your edit summaries clear and obvious. *Why* are you cleaning this thing up? Your summary leaves the reviewers guessing. That's a sure-fire way to get an edit rejected, as well it *should* be.

Remember that it's not just the reviewers that see these comments. They appear as the edit summary in the post's revision history—forever. If you're going to be *removing content*, you need to explain clearly *why* you are removing it.

It would be more appropriate to say something like:

> Remove link(s) to Stack Overflow Documentation, since the project has been discontinued (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356294). The linked content added little to nothing of value to the post anyway.

We are programmers here. We *should* know how to write good commit messages.

Comment: I wish schools would teach people how to write good commit messages.

Comment: I wish schools would teach people how to write good. (FTFY, @Stijn)

Comment: I wish schools would teach people how to write well (@CodyGray ;)).

Comment: @Meghan: Wooosh!

Comment: @yivi aww -- I wasn't sure if it was a joke or not, so I guessed. I chose ... poorly.

Comment: @Stijn: If they taught people how to write good email subjects, that would be enough. Or even how to title papers properly. Sadly, naming is hard, and titling is basically a special case of naming.

Comment: *"We are programmers here. We should know how to write good commit messages."*. Really? Let's get real. How often have *you* seen a commit message containing (1) a link, (2) Two well-formed sentences, and (3) 25 words along with said link, capitalized and grammatically correct. It's a commit message! Sure it *could* have contained something more, but certainly not *should* have. :-)

Comment: I wish schools would teach people.

Comment: @dfd I've committed lots of code to various repositories, so...pretty often? :-) Definitely helps when you're the sole contributor, I suppose.

Comment: I followed these suggestions, and things went well for a few edits. Then 2 got rejected: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17350303 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17351460 I guess I miss something else. I give up!