# Documentation tab in Privileges Remains

Tags: discussion, documentation

Today I was casually going through random links on StackOverflow and I wondered, "Gee, what tools do I get when I hit the next milestone?" until I saw this:

[image]

I know that Documentation has been sunset and people can no longer access it - so should this tab be removed? As for myself, I don't see any reason in keeping it, as after all, the privileges for Documentation are only relevant when it was still existent. Thoughts?

Comment: As stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links?cb=1) ui elements will only be removed once the clean up is done. So it might take 6 to 8 weeks

Comment: @rene Thanks for the citation! I just want to ensure that the details get ironed out eventually. :)

Comment: @rene It's been 4 months since this was mentioned, and the links still exist. I just also realized that there is no way to bump/add a bounty to a question, so how do we get the attention of the devs (Posting another question would quickly be closed as a duplicate)?

Comment: @FrankerZ none of this has any priority except being a nuisance. That said, I pinged Jon Ericson to bring this to his attention.

Comment: @FrankerZ: Long story. Unfortunately, we haven't been able to clear out all the Documentation code. The biggest sticking point is that we need to preserve reputation, which turns out to be [easier said than done](https://twitter.com/aalear/status/954253891788595200). Once the code is ripped out, the tab (and several other vestigial items) will disappear automatically.

Comment: @JonEricson No problem, thanks for the update. Just noticed it was lingering still in my profile, and when searching meta, stumbled upon this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looked at the milestones tabs on the Privileges page - it seems that the Documentation tab is officially gone!