# Am I getting glaucoma, or is the list of privileges translucent?

Tags: discussion, privileges

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. This is really annoying to read.

[image]

Comment: It is, and it always has been. The idea there is that the privileges you've earned are faded so you can focus on the ones that you haven't yet earned (not faded), but that looks sillier and sillier the more privileges you earn.

Comment: @animuson Horrible UI. And I agree that it looks ridiculous when you've run out of ones to earn

Comment: @animuson - The "documentation" privileges don't make sense anymore.

Comment: @j08691 - the two alternatives are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Never mind that fading them out like this is horrible UI - why is it even necessary to fade them out when you have checkmarks denoting earned privileges?

Comment: So let's add a "Jon Skeet" privilege threshold, and then for most people there will always be at least one left to earn.

Comment: Maybe we're all getting glaucoma

Comment: This is by design and it tells you: "There's nothing for you to see here, move along!"

Comment: @StephenC -- that's what I was thinking.  It's too bad you can't have a website to detect glaucoma.

Comment: @StephenC Documentation links will be [removed later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356564/documentation-tab-in-privileges-remains), supposedly.

Comment: Not to be a #PhD spoilsport, but Glaucoma would affect your periphery first 8)

Answer (score 19):

This is by design.

Privileges you are yet to obtain are shown at full opacity - however ones that you have are faded slightly.

This is the same screen for me, a lowly pleb who has yet to reach 25k.

[image: Privileges screen]

As you can see, the screen makes a lot more sense when you still have something to aim for.

Comment: `a lowly pleb who has yet to reach 25k.` Given enough time and dedication, you'll get there...

Comment: Given the age of my account, I suspect it's the dedication that's lacking ;)

Comment: To fix this, clearly there needs to be a privledge at 100 million rep called Jon Skeet