# Should being awarded 'Documentation Review' privilege still be happening?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, privileges

Today I reached 100+ reputation on SO and I was awarded the Documentation Review privilege as pictured:

[image: privilege awarded]

I looked into it a found that [documentation has been 'sunsetted'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation). I also found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356564/documentation-tab-in-privileges-remains) on SOMeta, which is unanswered but has a comment saying that:

> As stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links?cb=1) ui elements will only be removed once the clean up
>   is done. So it might take 6 to 8 weeks

The question was asked 4 months ago however!

So, to avoid this duplicating that question, I'm not asking why the UI element in privilege milestones remains, but I'm curious why I am notified that I have been awarded a privilege that no longer exists, and should it / is it being removed?

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks is a [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/286709) and isn't an actual estimated time.

Comment: @YohDeadfall I couldn't less hip right now if I tried

Comment: @YohDeadfall I had no idea either :)

Comment: Good news! The main sticking point to removing Documentation code, preserving reputation, seems to have been solved this week. Next week we'll be taking out more references to Documentation including, I think, this one. Too late to avoid this spurious notification, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was removed with all of the remaining documentation code. Sorry for the bother, it won't happen again I promise :)