# How to use the documentation archive?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

Now you have removed documentation and placed a [dump file here](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). It is really not more than a dump, in JSON format. Does it include any of the bitmaps, screenshots etc? I don't think so, from a quick look into the *.7z file.

How can I access my articles, which I have contributed? I'd like to put some of this information in answers I have written, to "restore" some of the information I have provided.

The minimum I would have expected is that you provide a description how to convert the JSON files into a database, Excel etc. which is easy to use.

Currently, I am not able to do this. There is no help from Stack Overflow provided, only [this post from you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356294/1016343) which doesn't help at all. There is also no front end any more. Do you expect every one of us to re-invent the wheel and develop a frontend for the dump file? I am very disappointed about this.

I know that with SQL 2016 in T-SQL you can do something like

> SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@jsonStr, N'lax $');

to get a table from a `@jsonStr` but that will not work with megabytes of data. Where are the nice, well-formatted web pages we created? They are all gone. Or are we supposed to view all that in raw JSON format in a text or hex editor?

It is looking as nice as this:

[image]

[image: RawJSON]

Okay, we are developers, and I understand you gave us a challenge, but ...

**Please change it - for all recent beta users of documentation, and for the entire community (I am sure there are more beta users like me who would like to provide some of the lost information). Something which allows to view the JSON content as web pages - for example an *offline reader* - would be excellent. And I think you must have the source code, because you made *"Doc Beta."***

Comment: I'm planning on answering this soon. Two notes in the meantime: 1) Uploaded images are still available on i.stack.imgur.com. We don't plan to purge those images, so links to them will still work as intended. 2) We're working on ways to make the data more accessible for people who don't want to use the archive. If you happen to use SQLite, I see there's [now an extension for JSON](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141907/25092).

Comment: @JonEricson - Thank you for your efforts. I think this is really something that will be required. The JSON archive is no convenient way to access the data.

Comment: **UPDATE:** It seems that [https://stackoverflow.com/documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) still allows you to access the content. I hope this will stay and not be removed so everyone has a chance to rescue some content into PDF file(s).

Comment: Yes, it will be around for a bit more. At least until all the Q&A links are removed. I'll also be working on making it easier to access the archive, but that might not happen until after the content is removed.

Comment: @JonEricson - Just a thought: How about using a tool like WGET to crawl through the Docs pages, then ZIP the results and provide it as a real archive (i.e. static offline pages with local hyperlinks)?

Comment: There's no reason someone couldn't do that, but I expect it will be much less useful than the JSON archive which contains all the metadata. In case you didn't know, the archive does include the HTML rendering of all the content. The links might need changing, however.

Comment: @JonEricson - If that is the case, I'll wait for your answer (how to load the archive into SQL server, how to set up the HTML "render engine" locally to be able to bring up the pages). Because currently I do not see how I can use it easily. It would also be great to have some guidance how to search for content to which I have contributed.

Comment: **UPDATE2:** You can no longer access the content through the web site.  Now the link https://stackoverflow.com/documentation just allows you to download the JSON archive.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a convenient way, most of the Docs topics are archived on the [Wayback Machine (web archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20170908035416/stackoverflow.com/documentation). Except for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) since the web archive strips off `%23` (`#`).

Even though this doesn't utilise the Docs data dump, it's an easy way to refer to.

Comment: I experimented a bit with it, but it seems the links are not working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [featured meta post on the removal.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links)

There's [a link in there](https://github.com/jericson/so_docs) that gives you all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The first link I already knew. I think the 2nd link is what helps some people. But I am not using Ruby at all (hence I don't have any experience with it) - some .NET code would be really helpful. And I believe that the Stack developers owe the SO community some more assistance here.

Comment: @Matt: Why does SO "owe" the community anything? Docs has always been an experiment, and never very successful. We can't expect them to write tools like this in every single popular language out there.

Comment: Because the articles were taken away from the site, and no more instant access is possible. A web archive (static HTML pages) with index would be a way for everyone to read the articles offline. But a JSON dump is cumbersome.

Comment: That doesn't answer: _"Why does SO __"owe"__ the community anything?"_

Comment: Maybe "owe" is not the right word, I apologize for not being an English native speaker. But I think there is some responsibility connected with providing a platform - beta or not, and not just shutting it down.

Comment: As I said, it was a beta. We were given plenty of heads-up about the fact documentation was retiring.

Comment: Yes, the information about the retiring was ok, and that is not what I am criticizing. I am criticizing that there is no easy way to access the retired content.

Comment: Until someone sets up a copy of the content somewhere online, which shouldn't take too much time to happen.

Comment: I hope so. If you notice there is something hosted, please let me know.