# I can't find back the documentation archive website

Tags: discussion, documentation

Not so long ago I stumbled upon a website made by a Stack Overflow user that allowed to browse through Stack Overflow's documentation (through the archives that they have made available).

However, I could not find it back by searching the Internet.

Did anyone hear of it? I am looking for the name of this website.

*I am not looking to access the documentation archive*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the documentation archive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356673/how-to-use-the-documentation-archive)

Comment: @RobertLongson This is not a duplicate, I was looking for the documentation website that was launched after SO docs closed.

Comment: Did you read the first sentence in that question?

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't look at the link. However it wasn't the point of his question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a review on the Internet Archive [details page for Documentation data dump](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z) that indicates the site RIP Tutorial:

> A website from this dump has been created: http://www.riptutorial.com/
>
> It’s current read-only, but I plan to make a wiki from it to allow people to edit example and make embedded live examples using some fiddle such as .NET Fiddle, SQL Fiddle, JS Fiddle which I believe was highly missing to be an “example first” documentation.

Comment: What a cool website! I didn't know that Microsoft invented C and C++! `/s`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto hahahaha

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: "*I didn't know that Microsoft invented C and C++!*" Well, at least the archive is keeping up the standards of accuracy that made Docs.SO the success it is today ;)