# Are we removing all links to the documentation?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

One of my answers which has link to the documentation was changed by a high-rank user at SO, where the change was only to remove the link do the documentation.

It wasn't a new user (so it wasn't in order to score points for edits).
I know that the documentation project is over, however I didn't notice any post regarding removing all links to the documentation from current answers.

If relevant, here is the link to the post:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41332934/revisions

Thanks!

Comment: The post is featured on meta: [Removing Documentation: Reputation, Archive, and Links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links)

Comment: Ack. That edit was wrong because **it removed attribution**. The code sample appearing in your answer was lifted from the linked Documentation article, so removing that link means you're using other people's work without giving them credit. It needs to be edited to provide explicit attribution to the authors of the Documentation, as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/).

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the answer. It seems like that edit already approved by other users. How can I revert it? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to revert it. Just edit and fix it.