# I like badges, but only when earned

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just found that I received a "Documentation User" badge. Huh? Here's the extent of my interaction with the (now frozen) Documentation section:

- I checked out the various *Swift Language* topic. Maybe - maybe - drilled into a few.
- I participated in a SO interview that (I believe) dealt with how the Documentation section was used.

That's it.

Okay, one more thing - I've read a few (probably not all) MSO posts about the "sunsetting" of this part of SO.

For this I get a Silver badge? I'm thinking this is a mistake. Could someone enlighten me? Maybe check the scripts dealing with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

So good news! We're going to take your [Peer Review badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5854/peer-review?userid=7014451) away soon:

[image: Reverse idol swap]

The truth is we really appreciate all the contributions we got on Documentation and want to acknowledge Documentation users who earned any badges at all. Most people will end up with fewer badges and nobody will get more than they started with. For more information, please see the "What happens to badges?" section of [this announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation).

Comment: Strictly speaking, folks who *only* had Docs Beta or Pioneer badges will end up with an extra. That's \*squints at the query\* two people out of the 43,370 "Documentation User" grants, both with the Pioneer badge.