# Disappearing badges?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

Earlier today, I could've sworn I had at least 5 badges more on the main site than I have now.

Bronze: 81 -> 77
Silver: 41 -> 40 (I think)

Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you lost some reputation point as well?

Comment: @NabihIbrahimBawazir Not today, but I don't believe that has anything to do with this.

Comment: Is this related? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357624/i-like-badges-but-only-when-earned/357625#357625

Comment: @Pang Maybe... could that be awarded more than once? I cannot recall.

Comment: yes I lost two bronze badges on main site also

Comment: @Pang Ah, I see now, I've lost every single documentation badge I ever earned.

Comment: Seems to be the docs badges. I just looked and there are only 3 now and they're all silver

Comment: Sorry about the surprise there... In hindsight, I should've planned better for announcing this. I'll post a more detailed answer soon, but in the meantime... Magisch is right in identifying the cause, and I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @AdamLear No problem, thank you for clarifying that. It would be helpful if you could do a roll call of recalled badges as well, so we know exactly what's gone away.

Comment: Disappointed in the drop, but delighted to ditch the documentation decorations.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is equal parts [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and [status-mybad](/questions/tagged/status-mybad). I'm sorry about the surprise factor. We've explained our plans for badges in the previous posts about sunsetting Documentation (quoted in Magisch's answer), but in hindsight, I should've announced some sort of timeline as well.

Here's the list of badges that were removed:

- Backer: First example up vote
- Bluebook: First citation of a topic or example you've edited
- Creditor: First citation by you of a topic or example you haven't edited in an answer you posted that receives an upvote
- Educated: Read the documentation tour
- Incrementalist: First proposed change to be approved by others
- Knowledgeable: First proposed change to be approved by others that handles others' improvement requests
- Peer Review: First review of someone else's proposed change
- Primer: First topic request to either be upvoted by others or to have a topic created from it
- Renovator: First improvement request

All bronze except for Knowledgeable, which was silver.

Comment: Actually in "sunsetting Documentation" you (well, Jon) never directly said the badges will be revoked. It's implied to those reading carefully, but from first reading one don't understand the badges will be gone.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, that's fair. It was more explicit in some of the other posts, but we should've been clearer in the initial announcement and the subsequent official updates.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The paragraph seems pretty clear to me: "We also have a longstanding policy against revoking badges. . . " Oh. Yeah, that's not so clear, is it. :-/

Comment: @JonEricson The "But" that comes after that sentence should've been _very_ big. :-)

Comment: @JonEricson you got it. :)

Comment: I still maintain that there should have been an additional gold or silver badge for those who earned every Doc badge while it was still ongoing... rather than a silver badge for anyone who earned *any single* badge

Answer (score 27):

They retired the documentation badges.

Instead there are now 3 silver badges related to documentation that have been awarded to people active in various stages of the project:

[image]

All the other documentation badges, among them all the bronze ones for minor feature use, seem to have gone away.

---

[Relevant excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/4909087):

> ### What happens to badges?
>
> We also have a [longstanding
>   policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/23/generalist-badge-implemented/)
>   against revoking badges. But we've never had a badge set for a
>   discontinued beta feature either. While we could just [retire
>   them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq),
>   it seems confusing to show expired Documentation features on the [list
>   of badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). In addition, we'd
>   lose a lot of good names for potential future badges. As a compromise,
>   anyone who earned a Documentation badge other than
>   [Educated](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5870/educated) (for
>   reading the tour) will be issued a newly minted silver Documentation
>   Beta badge. Does this seem fair?

Comment: Yep, just found this out. Was about to post an answer, but yours includes a picture! How about a freehand circle to go with that...