# Removing documentation links from the tags

Tags: discussion, documentation, tag-wiki

I've noticed that there are tags (like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) and many more) that still have links to SO's documentation. I suggest that the moderators (or anyone who can do it) will create some script to remove them automatically.

Comment: An automatic removal script would not be appropriate. See [Removing Documentation: Reputation, Archive, and Links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links); the same thing should be done for tag wikis as was done for other posts. You're right, it does seem that they were overlooked. How sad. Nobody ever remembers the tag wikis. :-(

Answer (score 8):

If there's a problem with the wikis, just go edit them. You have that privilege. They'll need approval from the review queue