# Documentation icon on links incorrectly used

Tags: bug, documentation, hyperlinks

I just read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359933/4284627) which mentions the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag. But I noticed something strange in the question:

[image]

It seems like the system thinks that the link goes to Stack Overflow documentation, even though the link's URL is the tag info page of the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag
(https://stackoverflow.com/tags/documentation/info, nothing to do with Stack Overflow documentation). I suppose it's because it sees `documentation` in the URL and thinks that any Stack Overflow URL containing `documentation` is a Stack Overflow documentation page (even though this one isn't). Seeing this in the beginning of that Meta question gives the impression that the question is about Stack Overflow documentation, when it actually is a burninate request that has nothing to do with documentation (except the name of the tag it wants to burninate).

Since [documentation is gone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/4284627), I suggest simply removing the documentation icon from all links. But even if it would be useful to keep it for some reason, I don't think it's intended that it should be used in this specific case.

Comment: Yeah, there's no need for the icon anymore. We'll remove it. (Not sure about timing right now, but should be soonish.)

Comment: @JonEricson Soonish like 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @JonEricson “should be soonish” — Did you mean “6–8 weeks”?

Comment: @JonEricson Is "soonish" longer or shorter than 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: Each time that joke is attempted adds `rand(8)` weeks to the estimate.

Comment: @JonEricson So, was it done like 6-8 weeks ago? (Does that mean `rand(8)` weeks will be *subtracted* from the estimate instead?)