# Clean up the [documentation] tag

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Related: [It is safe to burn all of our [documentation]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359933/it-is-safe-to-burn-all-of-our-documentation)

Since the burnination request system is somewhat backed up right now, I would like to propose that we start with a widespread cleanup effort.

This tag is currently hosting a large number of terrible, off-topic questions (many of which have link-only answers). In particular, a lot of the questions are of the form "Where do I find documentation for *X*?" or "what's a good tool to help me with documentation of [some special case]?" And if I see another answer there recommending Doxygen, I think I'm going to lose it.

Can we have a widespread cleanup effort? Per the usual process, this would *not* involve widespread retagging (that's the purview of [the official burnination request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359933/it-is-safe-to-burn-all-of-our-documentation), which hasn't been featured yet), just closing (and possibly deleting) poor questions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this can't wait to the official burninate request? I know they're pretty backed up, but cleaning up a tag that should be burninated, and then leaving it hanging around to collect new trash seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth , the way I'm understanding the OP's question, he's not asking people to retag the questions, he wants people to flag/close/delete the off topic questions frequently found under the `[documentation]` tag, so it's a distinct procedure from the burnination request. Burninating the tag [just means to remove that tag from the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag), not remove all questions that have that tag.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but we need to do that anyway when we're burninating the tag. My question is: why do we need to do this now, rather than wait till we're going to burninate the tag (there is a burninate request with more than 50 votes for this tag, so it should be featured). Cleaning up before burnination seems weird to me, since we need to do another pass cleaning it up when we burninate it, which will happen, and in the meantime new questions will still be added. It seems to me like this is an attempt to expedite the burninate request, and should be asked as such.

Comment: @DavyM and burninating on SO, like described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7296893), does not _just_ mean removing the tag from the system. In step 4, we clean up the tag, and close any questions that should be closed.  You can see it in process with the [tag:wheel] tag, which currently has 53 closed questions, of which 9 were closed today.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth My preference would be to just feature the burninate request so we could burninate it outright. I'm not sure when it's going to happen, though.

Comment: Well, that's what I guessed. And you can probably ask that, and provide arguments why this one should take priority over the other ones in the [queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bburninate-request%5d%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d%20score%3a20%20is%3aq). Currently, this feels like a question with a hidden agenda.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNaW8WW3FMI

Comment: @Erik one reason could be that the tag is gathering new off-topic posts at least daily. The longer we wait, the more questions we will have to deal with.