# Should we close all meta questions tagged with Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues, vote-to-close, meta

I see a large number of questions in the Close Vote review queue on Meta Stack Overflow that have the [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) tag. They are flagged as off topic with the "can no longer be reproduced" reason.

I know that the Documentation feature has been terminated, so I see the logic in the "can no longer be reproduced" reason. Has a decision been made to delete all Meta questions about the Documentation feature? I wasn't able to find a Meta question seeking consensus on this.

Comment: It is probably related to the burninate request https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359933/it-is-safe-to-burn-all-of-our-documentation

Comment: @SurajRao Possibly. I saw that post but it seems to relate to a Documentation tag on the main site. It ends with the following: This has nothing to do with the deprecated [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links) platform or its associated Meta tag [meta-tag:documentation].

Comment: Ah.. you are talking about the _meta stackoverflow_ close vote reviews.. You might want to specify it in your question. It looked like you mixed up documentation tag in SO and the deprecated documentation feature.

Comment: @SurajRao Good point. I have updated the question.

Comment: At least [one moderator](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=40682472#40682472) disagrees with closing those questions.

Comment: I had a brief discussion with Jon Ericson the other day when I noticed this as I wasn't sure about it either and wanted to know if there was an official stance on it. It seems there was a plan at *some point* to go through and status tag or close things. However, that being the case, it seems a bit of a waste of time for the community to vote to close and then review the entire tag if the staff can automate the Community user to do it and save everyone time. So while you're free to go ahead and do it, you might want to hold off just in case.

Comment: Does that cover this one as you tagged it with `documentation`???

Comment: @MartinBarker Someone else added the documentation tag, but I assume that if we nuke all questions in that tag, this one can go as well.

Comment: This question is not off-topic, as it is not about Documentation per se, but about questions related to it, which still exist here on Meta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Jon Ericson writes in the [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/4751173) post:

> ### What about all the questions on Meta?
>
> I’m going to be going through the [~1,500 unaddressed meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=documentation+-%5Bstatus-*%5D+closed%3Ano) and either close or put a status tag on them. Our community produced many great conversations and suggestions, so I don’t plan to delete anything. I could probably slap [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) on everything, but I’d rather take the opportunity to make sure we have the feedback incorporated in our retrospective.

That means we, the community, don't *need* to go through them and close them all. Personally, when I see one in the review queue, I close it, because the questions shouldn't be getting new answer. In any case, these questions **won't** be deleted (except for a few [Roomba](/help/roomba) candidates).