# Should [documentation] meta questions follow Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, meta, vote-to-delete, clean-up

Since [SO Documentation is no more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation), all [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) Meta questions about it are now useless (at the very least, they are off topic now).

Even though they don't take up (much) physical space at SO HQ or anything, they are still getting in the way by e.g. popping up in unrelated search results ([a recent example that incited me to write this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=obsolete)) -- "documentation" is quite a common word in IT, after all.

One can argue that they might have historical value or something. But MSO is not a museum, which means preservation is good and all, but must not get in the way of the site's primary purpose. Maybe only retain a few "key" ones? Those will provide all the information an archaeologist may ever need on the topic: what that was, why it was created and why it was deleted (so they don't suggest it anew and don't repeat the same mistakes).

A related question, [Should we close all meta questions tagged with Documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361843/should-we-close-all-meta-questions-tagged-with-documentation), has nothing to do with the current issue: the Documentation questions getting in the way.

So, should those questions be deleted?

Comment: Not sure what's up with the downvotes, but an obvious complication is that there are probably many [tag:documentation] questions which are not about the now-defunct SO Documentation sub-site. You seem to bo implying that the tag should be romoved but that's almost certainly misdirected. Could you update your proposal with an estimate of how many questions in this tag are actually affected - however informal - and clarify whether or not you are psoposing a burnination of the entire tag?

Comment: I don't know what the search link is supposed to demonstrate. None of the results I see (top 15, sorted by "relevance") on the first page of results seem to be about SO Documentation.

Comment: (Sorry about those embarrassing typos; I'm on mobile.)

Comment: @tripleee the question is about the [meta-tag:documentation] tag on meta, not on the main site. On the link, the 2nd result and 2 more are tagged [meta-tag:documentation] just on the 1st page.

Comment: Yes, that much is clear; but within the 15 results I reviewed in the search results, none seemed to be relevant for this discussion (the ones I noticed were about some other aspect of [tag:documentation], such as how something is explained in the documentation in the help section on SO), so perhaps you could elaborate on what you wanted to demonstrate, or provide a better search? Notice that search results will differ between users depending on how they configured their search perferences.

Comment: @tripleee: He is talking about the documentation tag **on Meta Stack Overflow**, not on the main site. If you press the link to the tag in his post, every single one of them is about Docs.SO.

Comment: If you have the tag view preference set to show the newest questions (which probably most of us do) that is obviously true, because there were many questions related to the Documentation purge; but they mostly seem relevant to keep, the older questions *probably* dominantly are not about Documentation, and his "obsolete" search link fails to support the claim that there is a problem. I'm simply asking for the question to be clarified to better persuade us that there is a problem, if indeed there is one.

Comment: @tripleee: "*his "obsolete" search link fails to support the claim that there is a problem.*" If you set the sort order to "relevance", then the second question on the "obsolete" search is a Docs.SO question. And there are two other questions in the first 30 about Docs.SO.

Comment: This question should not be closed as "can no longer be reproduced". It's about the fate of the still-extant Meta questions *about* the late Documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we close all meta questions tagged with Documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361843/should-we-close-all-meta-questions-tagged-with-documentation)

Comment: Ba-dum Crash! Closed as off-topic for "No longer can be reproduced".

Answer (score 8):

Deletion of content isn't reserved for *old* content.  It's reserved for content which is **actively harmful** to the site.

The old information about the Documentation beta is still relevant and pertinent, since while the efforts have died out, should they resurrect themselves, we (the community) have a reference frame point to illustrate exactly what they got wrong in the first place.

All of this predicates on this assertion:

> One can argue that they might have historical value or something. But MSO is not a museum, which means preservation is good and all, but must not get in the way of the site's primary purpose.

Meta Stack Overflow *is* a museum of sorts.  The primary purpose of the site is to discuss Stack Overflow and its policies.  Documentation was a part of Stack Overflow, so it has its home here on MSO.

Again, just because a topic is old doesn't mean it should be deleted.  Seeing an irrelevant search entry speaks more to the fact that search is broken and less to the fact that old Documentation questions are still floating around.

Comment: I showed how Documentation questions are actively harmful.

Comment: Search is not broken. It gives results relevant to the keywords typed. I've no idea how you could possibly "fix" that :)

Comment: It works in that if you search for "documentation", you will find "documentation".  This is sort of how Alta Vista worked before Google came around and demonstrated that it's possible to produce actually useful and relevant search results.

Comment: There was recently a flood of Documentation questions in the Close Vote review queue of  Meta Stack Overflow. It appeared that someone was flagging large numbers of questions about Documentation as Off Topic. Am I right in thinking that we should **not** be throwing these flags? If so, should we vote to close when we see them on the review queue?

Comment: @Blackwood I noticed the same today, and the first few I accepted. When I saw the pattern I thought to look into this, stumbling onto this post. Obviously the "concensus" is that these type of questions should stay. However the "no longer reproducaable" close reason is a very valid on in this case. Seeing that loads of questions have plenty upvotes they most likely wont fall prey to roomba, but still, is this something we should be doing?