# Meta close vote queue

Tags: discussion, support, meta

I just saw a nice red dot showing there are some reviews that need to be done. When I went there I saw some old posts in the close vote queue about documentation or having tags like [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

What is the point of closing these questions?

Comment: This might be related to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373201/how-should-we-handle-the-ongoing-mass-editing-on-meta#373214). That same user cast the fist CV's there...

Comment: That takes us to.. the 4th of the 10 plagues of Meta? Or where are we exactly?

Comment: Not much of a point, really. Very little harm as well, considering the review queues are quite out of the way.

Comment: Related : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361843/should-we-close-all-meta-questions-tagged-with-documentation , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373085/is-there-an-intent-to-delete-the-closed-documentation-questions

Comment: Thanks for those links @RobertColumbia. I think I will use them in my question later today. They give an answer to half my question about the documentation questions :)

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: Oh, that wasn't entirely intentional. I just copied the address without really looking.