# Request to undelete question: "Where is Sphinx search REST API documented"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

The question [Where is Sphinx search REST API documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284555/where-is-sphinx-search-rest-api-documented) was deleted because it allegedly asks to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource*.

At first glance, the criticism seems to be correct, but when taking a closer look, the corresponding user is actually asking a reasonable question about the meaning of the URL parameters of the search function of the [Sphinx documentation tool](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/). To my knowledge as a co-maintainer of Sphinx, these parameters are not explained anywhere else. This explains why my answer to this question was up-voted six times.

Could someone undelete the question?

I *do* agree that the wording of the question should be improved.

Comment: This question has likely been deleted during the [documentation cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361707/7296893).

Comment: The question has been undeleted. Please suggest an edit to make the question less misleading.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: I clarified the question.

Comment: I find it funny when the meta for a question gets more upvotes than the subject question and answer *combined*.

Comment: meta votes are _cheap_

Comment: Shouldn't parameters of a documentation tool be documented in some official location?

Comment: Another reason why editing titles is important. The title asked a completely different question than the body.