# What about having Documentation on Github?

Tags: discussion, documentation, archive

### Backstory

I've saved some [Stack Overflow Documentation links as reference for a CSS training](https://github.com/adrifmonte/css-training) that I have, and, knowing that those links would be broken in near future (and, having that it's just simple markup), I've taken a copy of the markup content of those links to [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/adrifmonte/css-training/tree/master/stack-overflow-documentation), including the recommended attributions.

### Suggestion

I think it would be nice if we could keep Documentation as a whole in GitHub, instead of just letting it go to archive.

What do you think? Any comment or idea? Maybe create an archive parser? Maybe Stack Overflow itself have an easier way to do that?

We could possibly continue contributing to Documentation there.

Or, just archive it there.

### Related links

- [Some GitHub attempts to keep Documentation alive](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=stack+overflow+documentation&type=)
- [Stack Overflow Documentation Home](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)
- [Removing Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links)

Comment: The Docs project failed because it generated a lot of bad documentation.  You'll have a hard time convincing anybody that replicating bad docs is a good idea.  And be careful, using a link in a post to your repository is okay, but the post still needs to be informative enough without that link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the big reasons that Documentation wasn't a huge success was the barrier to entry, as well as what qualified as "good" documentation.  By opening it up to anyone that wants to submit a PR, you run into two nightmares:

- Everyone will submit that damn Java arrays documentation again.  No one will actually write *meaningful* documentation when they can rattle off something from a book or website.
- Being able to filter out the noise from the signal becomes exponentially harder, given that there are more people out there that know the basics and are more than willing to share them, as opposed to the people that know the harder stuff.

Comment: What barrier to entry? 

Comment: "How do I write good documentation?"  "What qualifies as good documentation?"  There are other points besides those [enumerated in the discussion leading up to its sunsetting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349410/1079354) as well.

Comment: Oh that. I thought you were referring to some sort of site privilege.

Comment: I recall there being some miniscule amount of gating - that is, there likely was a minimum reputation involved - but those aren't significant barriers in the face of not knowing how to actually author good docs.

Comment: ugh... java arrays...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier:  Yes.  It has left an indelible mark on us all in some way.  Let us record it in every history book available so that we will make that mistake *Never Again*.

Answer (score 6):

Part of what made Stack Overflow docs great was that it was high profile—we're one of the most visited programming sites on the internet, so putting that link in the topbar can earn *tons* of views.

Putting it on GitHub just wouldn't get that kind of attention, and it's very possible that it would just sit there slowly going out of date.