# What is the proper procedure to citing a Stack Overflow post in my code?

Tags: discussion, licensing, attribution

***The Question (TL;DR):***

I'm making a PyQt program both for fun with my friends, and to put on GitHub to show programming experience for employers/recruiters. I wanted to make the text of a couple of QLabels in my program have text outlines, and found a class written by someone on Stack Overflow that achieves that effect. Is it enough to write a docstring at the top of that file (and as part of my program and repo README's) citing that classes' author, link for the code post, and a clear statement saying that they were the author of this specific class in my code? Or do I need to get in touch with that author/do more to cite that class? Should I just avoid this QLabel visual effect all together regardless of citation since I couldn't figure out how to do it on my own?

***The Context***

So I recently graduated from uni and my main career goal is to officially develop, release, and sell a game I've been working on since high school. In the meantime, I wanted to test out if some of the concepts/mechanics were sound, and I'm a [Dungeon Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_Master) for my friends for [D&D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons), so I homebrewed a custom version of D&D with the characters, mechanics, and story beats as a form of play testing (they are aware of this, and have been very supportive!).

I wanted to make a digital and automated character sheet using PyQt in place of our printed one. While all the logic, concepts, layouts, etc. have all been made entirely by myself using the PyQt library, I wanted to make the text for a couple Qlabels have text outlines (not label border, but character outlines). When I was looking up what PyQt tool(s) I could use to achieve that effect, I found the exact same question I was asking here on Stack Overflow and someone had given a great answer in the form of a class they wrote. I'm still totally new to PyQt and wherever I looked, the approach to getting that same appearance basically had to be custom made using more or less the same steps/concepts as this class.

***The Full Question:***

Since I obviously didn't write this one QLabel-related class, I put it in its own file and wrote a docstring at the top stating that this class in specific was not written by me, but by user XXX on Stack Overflow, and I also included a link to the specific post where they offered their class. I also included this class's citation in my program's README file. Based on this context, is my citation of author and link sufficient or is there additional attribution I would have to give or direct permission I should get?

I have no plans of monetizing this character sheet program or that kind of stuff. It's just to have fun with my friends and make it public on GitHub, so employers can see that I have some experience with Python. Also, does using this one class to make my labels look nicer reflect poorly on my own coding ability in the eyes of potential employers/turn them away even with the proper citation?

Comment: See [What is the license for content I post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Comment: I wrote an [answer to: "Removing Documentation: Reputation, Archive, and Links"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356304/3773011), which goes into reasonable depth of what I, personally, believe are the actual requirements for attribution with the CC BY-SA license, including some examples. While the examples in that answer are for the archived SO Documentation project, there requirements of the license are consistent. However, I'd need to re-read the CC BY-SA 4.0 license to reference it in detail (i.e. get section numbers). However, I am not a lawyer and my opinion is not legal advice.

Comment: Thanks for the links and help y'all! I see I posted in the wrong place originally, sorry about that! 

From what it looks like, it might just be best to not use that class at all and not have that visual effect. Since I could only find the username and post link, and am missing info like their real name or title (it was a text reply to a forum post instead of a full program/file/separate post) my citation likely won't suffice. The last thing I want is to plagiarize someone else or be plagiarized (accident or not).

Thank you for bearing with me, and I'll do my best to be more aware!

Comment: @Naybur In your question you say that you're wanting to know what the attribution requirements are for code that you found on Stack Overflow, but now in comments you're saying that you're really getting the code from a "text reply to a forum post". If you're not getting the code from Stack Overflow, then we really can't help you (off-topic, too complex, and too many unknowns). As to you thinking you need the user's real legal name: you don't need that for code which you've gotten from Stack Overflow. For such code, you'd use their username.

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right, forum was not the right term, I should have clarified it was from SO. It was from Stack Overflow, but the class was provided as a reply/answer to someone's question. So someone asked a question and the person who answered it relayed it through text as opposed to uploading a file or linking to a repository, which is why I wasn't sure what the title would be or how I could properly meet all of the bullet points to correctly attribute. Sorry for the mix up!

Comment: For SO, I don't think "real name" attribution is required. I think a link to the actual answer would satisfy all CC licence requirements.