# Documentation badge awarded twice?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, badges

I guess sunsetting documentation is going into the final stretch, as I was just awarded the Documentation badge for "Earned at least one badge for contributing to Stack Overflow Documentation", as per [Documentation is read-only. What’s next?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355115/2422776).

Strangely enough, I seem to have two of them (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7358/documentation-user?userid=2422776)).
I'm guessing this is a bug?

Comment: I also just received 2 badges. It says "at least" so I guess 1+ is ok?

Comment: This is a bug that we are working on fixing. One of the badges will be removed shortly. Sorry.

Comment: I'm okay with having two badges. Everyone knows two shinies are better than one.

Comment: Jon giveth, and Jon taketh away.

Comment: I'll have you note that Adam taketh away, @TinyGiant. ;-)

Comment: Hey now, Adam giveth in the first place too.

Comment: I'm going on a limb here and state just about everyone got it twice. It's probably fixed for the same amount of users by now as well.

Comment: @JonEricson isn't there a rule that badges are never revoked unless they were obtained by egregious cheating?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Doesn't get much more egregious than "without realizing it, telepathically convince the developer to make a mistake".

Comment: @AdamLear It was an accident, I swear. Please don't ban me!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, fun fact: prod, unlike dev, has a scheduled badge task. :) So I kicked off a grant *and* the normal scheduled task ran at the same time.

Everything should be just about cleaned up now, sorry about that. The good news, as was pointed out to me, is that the next time we decide to shut down Documentation, I should know better.

Comment: So you've documented it now?

Comment: @Machavity And make it easy for others to learn from *my* hard-earned mistakes? They wish.

Comment: I see the change reflected in my badges, and now only got 1 Doc Badge. However, my user [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3908170/graycygnus?tab=profile) still counts the phantom badge (should be 9 instead of 10 silver badges in my case). Caching maybe?

Comment: @GrayCygnus Yeah, probably. Flairs are pretty heavily cached, but I'll check tomorrow and see if it's something else instead. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: *"`the next time we decide to shut down Documentation, I should know better.`"* Hahaha!

Comment: Btw, the [description of the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7358/documentation-user) includes a link to the Docs page. (`Earned at least one badge for contributing to **Stack Overflow Documentation**.`) But shouldn't the hyperlink be removed since it'll eventually be pointing to a broken page?

Comment: @Panda Click it. :)

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for your reply! Initially I thought that the page would be removed *eventually*, but then I realised that the [/teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) page still accessible too ;-)