# I got the Documentation User badge but have no idea how

Tags: support, badges

today I received the Documentation User badge for contributing to Stack Overflow Documentation, however, I have no idea how I helped. Can someone give any pointers? Also shouldn't Stack Overflow make this badge more detailed?

Edit: Since more people have the same question. Did we get this badge because:

1. We contributed in some way to the Documentation without being aware
   of it?
2. Part of our answers was implemented in the Documentation?
3. Our questions helped to form the Documentation?
4. Some other reason?

Comment: I still don't see how this is a duplicate of either of the two provided 'duplicates'. When you get a badge, you should know for what contribution you got it for, right? :/

Comment: I got it too. And i have no idea, why, too... I would be interested, why, too... (sorry, if that is bad grammar/english...)

Comment: When looking who else earned this badge, we see that 43370 users got awarded with this badge, all at the same time (10 hours ago, at the time of writing this).

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann Even so, why 'just' 43370 and not everyone?

Comment: @scooterlord That's the interesting question...

Comment: @scooterlord this badge was introduced to replace all the old documentation badges. (since most of documentation is going the way of the dinosaurs).
I received this badge too 11 hours ago, and i have no idea why. i don't think I've consciously contributed to any documentation pages. I'm not complaining, but it would be nice to know what i did to get that badge.

Comment: The basic premise was supposed to be that if you had *any* of the old documentation related badges, they would go away, and you would get this one in return. thing is, i don't remember having any of those.

Comment: @TimothyGroote yep, I don't remember having any of those either, that's why I was confused. And exactly as you said, I don't remember consciously contributing. In any case, having a pointer to the notification would be nice.

Comment: I got this badge twice yesterday - without any action (or without any action I remember ..). I suspect a bug or something + within same hour of OP

Comment: Yes, [there was a bug yesterday that caused it to be awarded twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357616/documentation-badge-awarded-twice/357618#357618). That bug has since been corrected, @Arount.

Comment: I'm puzzled about getting one too.  I'm 99% sure I never did anything than look at it passively and never created/edited any content.  Was there a bronze level "I read the faq" type badge for it?

Comment: **tl-dr**: `As a compromise, anyone who earned a Documentation badge other than Educated (for reading the tour) will be issued a newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge` and you had a [peer review badge Awarded Apr 6 at 23:33](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5854/peer-review?userid=2261073) when you reviewed your first "Documentation proposal". If it took over 15 minutes to figure out for myself (I forgot about it as I probably confused it with the plain Custodian badge when I got it), it's worth a comment over here.

Comment: LOL, I answered your updated/edited question (in comment above) 5 minutes before you updated/edited it... ffin awesome

Comment: I actually read your answer before I posted - I still don't see the connection between the too.

Comment: ? your updated question asks for further clarification why you (and others) got the badge, while giving 4 (of which 1 open ended) options. So (as can all be read in my comment above), for you it is option 1: you contributed on Apr 6 to documentation by reviewing a documentation proposal, for which you received a bronze 'peer review' badge, akin to 'custodian' badges for each first in regular review queues. A 'peer review' badge belongs to the Documentation project, and is not an 'educated' badge. I feel I'm spelling it out here.. Seems a clear connection between my comment and your updated Q

Comment: @GitaarLAB thanks for the clarification. It would be crystal clear, if we could also make the connection of the 'Peer review' to the Documentation. Other than that it makes sense.

Comment: NP, you are welcome (perhaps give the other original comment an uptick as well for others). PS for @swe it's: [Backer Badge Awarded Sep 15 '16 at 10:32](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5849/backer?userid=3169021)

Comment: @TimothyGroote: [Backer Badge Awarded Jul 25 '16 at 7:14](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5849/backer?userid=694736)

Comment: @GitaarLAB ha, how about that. thanks.