# Documentation proposals still work

Tags: bug, documentation

Since the decision was made to [phase out Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation), almost everything related to it (such as the review queue) has been removed or made read-only. The proposals however, still remain:

[image]

And yes, they are still functional:

[image]

--A proud backer of [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override)

Comment: It isn't like articles can be submitted for those topics, though, so this isn't as major a bug IMO.