# Educated badge still being awarded for reading the Docs tour

Tags: bug, documentation, badges

Not a pressing issue, but I'd just like to point out that the [Educated](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5870/educated) badge is still currently being awarded even though [Docs has sunsetted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation?cb=1).

At the time of this post, it seems that close to 300 Educated badges were awarded after 1700 UTC, August 8, the time Docs was disabled.

---

Just to add on, all Docs badges will be retired, so it doesn't really matter if it's still awarded for the time being.

> ### What happens to badges?
>
> We also have a longstanding policy against revoking badges. But we've never had a badge set for a discontinued beta feature either. While we could just retire them, it seems confusing to show expired Documentation features on the list of badges. In addition, we'd lose a lot of good names for potential future badges. As a compromise, anyone who earned a Documentation badge other than Educated (for reading the tour) will be issued a newly minted silver Documentation Beta badge. Does this seem fair?

Comment: Well, now it's 301.

Comment: @George When I wrote this post, it was 294 to be exact. ;-)

Comment: I'll be honest, I went to see if I had it so I could add it to my collection... (and I didn't, so thanks for the extra badge!)

Comment: @Albzi Actually, all Docs badges will be retired, I've added it to my post ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. In sorta good news, the 'educated' badge, as mentioned in our original [sunset post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation?cb=1), will not be carried forward. None of the other badges can be earned any more, so we should be 'safe'. Regardless, we will turn off the ability asap. More details on all the elements coming today!

Comment: And here are the [details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355115/documentation-is-read-only-what-s-next).

Comment: *Quick... get it while you can*

Comment: Doesn't matter had badge @Panda ;)