# Disable the 'Insert Link to Documentation' popup

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

[Documentation has sunsetted last Tuesday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation?cb=1). However, the hyperlink tab to insert a Docs link into a Q & A post continues to display on both Stack Overflow and Meta.SO ...

[image]

... even though links to Docs can no longer be posted.

[image]

Comment: I thought we were actively blocking the submission of links to Documentation. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @CodyGray Oh yea, just tried it, I've updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: We're focusing on the "big picture" items at the moment (rep preservation, link cleanup, data dump, etc). I'm getting to smaller things like this as I have time, but they're all on the giant list of things to clean out before we're done. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear Yea, just wanted to point it out; it's a minor problem. Also, thanks to the Docs team for all the work!