# Obsolete information in help center

Tags: bug, documentation, reputation, help-center

Here's [the page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) I'm talking about.

> **You gain reputation when:**
>
> - example you contributed to is voted up: +5
> - proposed change is approved: +2
> - first time an answer that cites documentation you contributed to is upvoted: +5

Since [Documentation was retired](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/5958455) on August 8, these content might as well be removed from the help center so as not to confuse users.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign] in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: I hope this will be [meta-tag:status-completed].