# Questions that supersede others

Tags: discussion

***Introduction***

A lot of questions are about very specific problems, for example "how to resolve this exact error?" with some error log.

Let's call these bug-questions.

But what if I want to share my knowledge of debugging a **whole category** of these issues? Should I just post a question about that, and answer my own question? Doesn't it become a duplicate of all existing bug-questions about these errors?

Once a generic answer exists, shouldn't we close all existing bug-questions? Also, I don't think 'duplicate' would be accurate in this case. Maybe we should have a 'superseded by [...]' reason?

At least personally, as a SO user, I am way more interested in finding an answer that describes the *way* to debug an issue than the solution to a lot of very restricted problems.

---

***Example***

I have, of course, a very specific example in mind. Look at this question:
[Qt 5.1.1: Application failed to start because platform plugin "windows" is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495620/qt-5-1-1-application-failed-to-start-because-platform-plugin-windows-is-missi).

Inside the question, a lot of other questions are referenced, and the OP says "my question is not the same as these questions, because the answers there do not solve my problem!". But the OP has a very similar error log to the other questions. It just so happens that his problem has a different root cause than the other questions had.

I know how to debug such an error log.

---

***The actual question***

How should we handle questions that supersede existing questions?

Comment: Mark them as duplicates, as they are pretty much duplicates just with a little variation on data, your example is different as it's not a duplicate because they have specified _However, in my case the problem still persists._ and _It just so happens that his problem has a different root cause than the other questions had_ means it's a different question and is worth keeping. As for _Should I just post a question about that, and answer my own question_ I'd say no, as that seems too much like the documentation section which is now removed.

Comment: A better example for my reasoning as marking as duplicates is the amount of [_return data after ajax call questions_ in the JavaScript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5316697/2315360) which are always marked as duplicates to a single question, sure the data might be a little different but if they take the time to read the answer they should understand how to fix their problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you would like to do does not fit the Q&A format of Stack Overflow.

You may instead want to write a tutorial or blog post about how one can debug certain types of errors, or how to read error logs. That information is very *valuable*, it unfortunately doesn't fit here though.

Given the above, it is not possible for questions to supersede other questions in the sense that you mean. It is therefore not desirable to have a special close reason, or special handling of questions.

---

I personally find this a real shame: people will have a very specific issue, search for it on Stack Overflow and expect a ready-to-go solution. Ideally, it's just a matter of copy 'n pasting something. This means that even if you would write the types of questions that you would like to write, they would likely not be received very positively. People certainly wouldn't appreciate to be steered from copy 'n paste to "let me explain to you the intrinsic details of the system, so you can understand what causes your problem and will eventually lead to you deriving the solution yourself". If only.

Possibly related to your question, in a way an attempt to address it, is the [now-stopped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217) experimental [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) feature on Stack Overflow. It suffered from various issues, but you may find that its [intent](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/21/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/) was very similar to yours.