# Obsolete privilege "Documentation review" at reputation 100?

Tags: bug, documentation, badges

I just reached a reputation of 100 and ...`earned the "documentation review" privilege! Learn more about it in the help center` which leads to the following [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-reviewing).

According to [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) it seems obsolete, or am I missing something? If so, it would be helpful to remove this confusing notification.

Thanks for clarification!

Comment: No it's 100% obsolete.  Good bug report here.