# How can I get the Documentation user Badge?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

There is a silver badge called Documentation user badge which can earn at least one badge for contributing to Stack Overflow Documentation. I visited to the Stack Overflow Documentation page, but it said **We have shut down
Stack Overflow Documentation**. How can I get this badge?

Thank You!

Comment: You can't. Not anymore.

Comment: Time machine. Invent a time machine.

Comment: And I want the [Precognitive badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive)! Because in hindsight I would probably have joined SO then, so I think I deserve it as well. I'd even be the only one to have one!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I get this badge?

You can't. [Documentation has been discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation), it is no longer possible to get into the beta or obtain this badge.