# Expand the profile with a personal blog for stack overflow (code dev part)

Tags: feature-request, blog

Sometimes I want to share knowledge that I recently gained about something.

But just thinking about manage a blog in someplace makes me give up. (yes i'm lazy)

Imagine kinda a medium (that don't keep harassing me to sign-in every second) inside my profile.

So I can craft a very long and detailed post with the tools that i'm already familiar.

It will not be lost on the endless questions on stack overflow.

And I think that this 'blog' should be very collaborative, so people can post stuff to make that post even better.

It will make easier to separate content from question.

Because if I want to make a long post with very detailed explanations about something I believe that a 'question' is not the best place, and why go to medium if we already are here.

Just a suggestion =D

Comment: Already tried, [not a success](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow).

Comment: well, that sucks ... that avengers meme, "I'm X years to late", gonna have to set up a medium then

Comment: Another alternative was also tried - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation

Comment: Or, why not start your own blog? It's really not that hard. Alternatively, if you still don't want to manage a blog yourself, you could always team up with someone, or guest write on an existing blog. Some blogs do look for writers guest or permanent writers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do not need this as a separate feature.

If you want to share programming knowledge, you can do so directly on Stack Overflow by asking and answering your own question. The key is just figuring out how to phrase the question so that you insights become relevant as an answer. The answer can be as long and descriptive as it needs to be, allowing you to include your "very detailed explanations". Furthermore, our Q&A engine is inherently collaborative, allowing others to edit your answer and/or post answers of their own.

If you want to talk about yourself or about matters unrelated to specific programming tasks, then you really need to do that off-site. Start your own blog, use Medium, etc.